# É correto dar maior preferência a composição do que herança?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, herança, composição

Eu já li em vários artigos e livros de *Designer Patterns* a expressão `Prefira composição em vez de herança`. Acredito que é um tema bastante polêmico devido aos pontos de vista discutidos.

A meu ver, composição e herança são usadas para resolver problemas diferentes, certo?

```
class Carro {  
    private Motor motor;      
}
```

O exemplo acima é bem coerente pois um carro deve ter um motor. Entretanto se substituirmos a herança por composição em alguns casos a estrutura fica um pouco estranha, por exemplo.

```
class Carro {
    private Veiculo veiculo;
}
```

É estranho pensar que Veiculo virá um atributo de Carro. Nesse contexto, Veiculo serve apenas para a reutilização de código pois não segue uma hierarquia e não agrega polimorfismo.

Desculpem minha ignorância mas as classes herdadas mantém o acoplamento que é necessário entre elas (a herança em si), certo?

Quais as vantagens de se usar composição em vez de herança? É possível especificar um momento certo de usá-las? Seguindo a opinião do título, a melhor combinação seria composição + interface?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

> **TL;DR** - Somente use herança se o subtipo puder **perfeitamente** substituir o tipo base. Além disso, **reduza as responsabilidades** de suas classes. Use composição para juntar várias responsabilidades isoladas em um objeto só (i.e. **agregue funcionalidades**).
>
> O restante da resposta é baseada em exemplos práticos. Para uma resposta mais conceitual (e mais curta), incluindo o embasamento teórico, veja [a resposta do utluiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11430/215). E [a resposta do carlosrafaelgn](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21891/215) apresenta um contraponto bastante interessante.

### Quando não usar herança?

A decisão entre usar ou não herança deve se guiar no [Princípio da Substituição de Liskov](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_substitui%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Liskov), que diz: "onde um objeto da classe base pode ser usado um objeto da subclasse deve também poder ser usado". Manter esse princípio se torna complicado em relações de herança complexas, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
class Animal { }
class Cachorro extends Animal { }
class Gato extends Animal { }

class AbrigoAnimais {
    Animal obterAnimal() { }
    void adicionarAnimal(Animal a) { }
}
class AbrigoCachorros extends AbrigoAnimais {
    Cachorro obterAnimal() { } // OK
    void adicionarAnimal(Cachorro c) { } // É overload, não overrride
}

AbrigoAnimais canil = new AbrigoCachorros();
canil.adicionarAnimal(new Gato()); // Deveria ser válido, pelo princípio da substituição
```

O mesmo se observa em casos onde a subclasse é mais restrita que a superclasse:

```
class Retangulo {
    void atribuirLados(int altura, int largura) { }
}
class Quadrado extends Retangulo { }

new Quadrado().atribuirLados(10, 20); // Deveria ser válido, pelo princípio da substituição
```

Além disso - não relacionado a esse princípio, mas também relevante - há o problema do que fazer na presença de herança múltipla:

```
interface Voador { }

class Veiculo { }

class Aviao extends Veiculo implements Voador { }
class Passaro extends Animal implements Voador { }

// Como reaproveitar a funcionalidade de Voador?
```

Ou em casos onde a interface é conflitante:

```
interface Foo {
    String metodo();
}
interface Bar {
    int metodo();
}

class Baz implements Foo, Bar {
    // Não é possivel, pois o que "metodo" vai retornar?
}
```

Se seu modelo não possui nenhum desses problemas, então vai em frente e use herança! Mas na maioria das vezes (pela minha experiência) pelo menos um desses problemas está presente. Além disso, a motivação do programador com frequência é simplesmente "reutilizar código" - ele não tem uma taxonomia clara onde a relação de herança se justifique, ele só a usa porque acha que tem que usar. É nesses casos que a composição se torna uma alternativa preferível.

### Como resolver usando composição?

No primeiro caso, pode-se fazer isso colocando no tipo base somente os métodos que atendem ao princípio da substituição:

```
interface AbrigoAnimais {
    Animal obterAnimal();
}
class ImplAbrigoAnimais<T extends Animal> implements AbrigoAnimais {
    T obterAnimal() { } // OK, tipo de retorno covariante
    void adicionarAnimal(T animal) { } // Não está presente na interface
}
class AbrigoCachorros implements AbrigoAnimais {
    ImplAbrigoAnimais<Cachorro> abrigo = new ImplAbrigoAnimais<Cachorro>();

    Cachorro obterAnimal() { return abrigo.obterAnimal() }
    void adicionarAnimal(Cachorro cachorro) { abrigo.adicionarAnimal(cachorro); }
}

AbrigoAnimais canil = new AbrigoCachorros();
canil.obterAnimal(); // OK
```

Mesma coisa no segundo (note que é possível suportar tanto leitura quanto escrita):

```
interface Retangular {
    void atribuirLargura(int largura);
    void atribuirAltura(int altura);
}
class Retangulo implements Retangular {
    void atribuirLargura(int largura) { }
    void atribuirAltura(int altura) { }
    void atribuirLados(int largura, int altura) { } // Não está na interface
}
class Quadrado implements Retangular {
    Retangulo quadrado = new Retangulo();
    void atribuirLargura(int largura) { 
        atribuirLados(largura);
    }
    void atribuirAltura(int altura) { 
        atribuirLados(altura);
    }
    void atribuirLados(int valor) {  // Não está na interface
        quadrado.atribuirLargura(valor);
        quadrado.atribuirAltura(valor);
    }
}
```

### Separação de Responsabilidades

Por fim, vou demonstrar como a separação de responsabilidades pode ajudar muito a modelar um conjunto complexo de entidades:

```
interface ObjetoPosicionado { }
interface Animal extends ObjetoPosicionado { }
interface Veiculo extends ObjetoPosicionado { }

class ImplObjetoPosicionado implements ObjetoPosicionado {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
}
class ImplAnimal implements Animal {
    ObjetoPosicionado impl;
    int fome;
}
class ImplVeiculo implements Veiculo {
    ObjetoPosicionado impl;
    List<Pessoa> passageiros;
}
```

Aqui cada classe cuida de um aspecto específico: uma controla onde o objeto está no espaço, outra controla os atributos específicos do animal **fazendo uso** do objeto anterior (pois um `Animal` é um `ObjetoPosicionado`), e outra controla os atributos específicos do veículo (idem). Com as responsabilidades isoladas, pode-se reutilizá-las numa classe particular aproveitando-se apenas o que é necessário, e não desperdiçando espaço:

```
class Cavalo implements Animal, Veiculo {
    ImplAnimal ia;
    ImplVeiculo iv;

    public Cavalo() {
        ObjetoPosicionado op = new ObjetoPosicionado(); // Uma única cópia...
        ia = new ImplAnimal(op);  // ...é utilizada aqui...
        iv = new ImplVeiculo(op); // ...e aqui.
    }

    // Realiza a interface de ObjetoPosicionado
    void deslocar(int x, int y, int z) {
        ia.deslocar(x,y,z); // Ou iv - dá no mesmo, pois ambos têm a mesma "impl"
    }

    // Realiza a interface de Animal
    void comer() {
        ia.comer();
    }

    // Realiza a interface de Veiculo
    void adicionarPassageiro(Pessoa p) {
        iv.adicionarPassageiro(p);
    }
}
```

### Mas não é muito código pra escrever?

Sim! Se a sintaxe da linguagem não ajuda, você teria que fazer uma baita ginástica para criar modelos desse tipo, anda que o esforço "se pague" depois (uma API limpa e um código eficiente). E qual seria a solução? Deixar a "pureza" de lado e **acabar com a herança de uma vez**:

```
class Cavalo {
    Animal comoAnimal() { return ia; }
    Veiculo comoVeiculo() { return iv; }
}

Cavalo c = new Cavalo();

//Animal a = c;
Animal a = c.comoAnimal();
```

Ou seja: volta a "estranheza" da pergunta original, mas ganha-se todos os benefícios do uso de composição menos o *overhead* do código extra para tornar isso possível. No fim das contas, ainda é herança que você está fazendo - mas sem usar a sintaxe/semântica dela, e sim a da composição.

### É o ideal?

Não. O ideal seria que o computador tratasse bem da "confusão" que é a maneira que o cérebro humano categoriza as coisas ("Aves voam. Avestruzes são aves, só que não voam. Aviões também voam, mas não batem as asas. Foguetes voam, e nem têm asas! Patos são aves, e também nadam. Barcos não nadam, mas é quase isso... Aviões, foguetes e barcos são veículos. Mísseis parecem foguetes, mas não transportam passageiros.").

Na ausência disso, só resta criar modelos com características desejáveis, como a **segurança de tipos**. Ela visa garantir que entidades "parecidas" possam ser tratadas como um tipo só - através da substituição segundo o princípio citado no começo da resposta. Se você não tem essa segurança, de que adianta ter um objeto que **pode ou não** cumprir o contrato da classe?

No fim das contas, o que interessa ao programador é que determinado objeto possua certa funcionalidade desejável. Ou seja, conceitualmente `um carro é um veículo`, mas pragmaticamente `um objeto carro possui a funcionalidade de um objeto veículo`.

Comment: Nota: minha resposta foi bem prolixa, mas não consigo explicar isso usando menos palavras... Se alguém tiver uma resposta mais sucinta - e talvez até mais completa, pois o que escrevi foi somente fruto da minha experiência pessoal - ela será muito bem vinda!

Comment: resposta muito bem explicativa, agora faz mais sentido com os exemplos reais do mau uso da herança, em relação a "estranheza" de usar composição no lugar de herança acho que vale por todos os benefícios que consigo e com o proveito de usar "Generics" como no seu exemplo fica melhor ainda, muito boa explicação! amanha vou dar mais 50pts pela resposta.

Answer (score 36):

Sei que posso entrar na esfera da opinião, mas ainda assim, muito curiosa a colocação

> prefira composição em vez de herança

Durante minhas aulas do mestrado, eu ouvia exatamente o contrário. Inclusive, dentre todos os tipos de herança que existem, os que respeitam o [princípio da substituição](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_substitui%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Liskov) eram "*verdinhos*" e os que não respeitam, eram "*vermelhinhos*".

Em poucas palavras, o princípio da substituição me foi passado da seguinte forma:

- Sejam as classes `A` e `B`, `B` subclasse de `A`
- É possível substituir uma instância `iA` da classe `A` por uma instância `iB` da classe `B` em qualquer situação, com nenhum efeito observável

A partir daí, definiu-se o conceito de subclasse e subtipo:

- Um subclasse é uma estrutura construída usando herança, satisfazendo ou não o princípio da substituição
- Um subtipo é uma classe que satisfaz o princípio da substituição

Logo, nem todas as subclasses são subtipos, e (em algumas linguagens bastante específicas) é possível ter um subtipo que não seja uma subclasse.

Com isso definido, é possível separar quais formas de herança podem ou não respeitar o princípio da substituição.

Algumas que podem respeitar o princípio:

- Especialização
- Especificação
- Extensão
- Combinação (ou Herança Múltipla)

Enquanto algumas outras nem sempre respeitam (e devem ser evitadas, se possível):

- Construção: Uma superclasse é usada apenas pelo seu comportamento, e não tem relacionamento real com a superclasse. Por exemplo, criar uma classe `Pilha`, que é uma subclasse de `Vetor`, apenas porque alguns dos métodos necessários já estão lá prontinhos na classe `Vetor`.
- Generalização: Uma subclasse estende o comportamento da superclasse por criar uma tipo mais geral de objeto, generalizando ou estendendo a superclasse por fornecer mais funcionalidades.
- Limitação: A subclasse limita alguma parte do comportamento da superclasse, sobrepondo métodos indesejáveis (por exemplo, fazendo com que um método funcional da superclasse passe a gerar uma exceção como `InvalidOperationException`).
- Variação: Duas ou mais classes parecem ser relacionadas, mas não é claro quem deveria ser superclasse e quem deveria ser subclasse. Ocorre normalmente quando se constrói classes partindo de outras classes já existentes. Por exemplo, entre as classes `Mouse`, `TouchPad` e `Joystick`, fica difícil, ou até impossível, determinar quem deveria ser superclasse de quem em teoria. Mas na prática, o desenvolvedor simplesmente decide que `Mouse` é um caso particular de `Joystick`, e pronto!

Com isso dito, é possível partir efetivamente para a ideia de composição.

Claramente, no exemplo da "Herança por Construção", onde `Pilha` é uma subclasse de `Vetor`, o uso da sentença **Pilha é-um Vetor** soa muito mal. Nesse caso, a composição deveria ter sido utilizada, uma vez que a sentença **Pilha tem-um Vetor** soa muito melhor (considerando que a pessoa ouvindo sabe o que é uma pilha e o que é um vetor).

Por outro lado, ao utilizar composição em casos onde herança poderia ser utilizada, o desenvolvedor perde diversas possibilidades. Por exemplo, se um método `m1()` espera uma classe `A`, e você criou uma classe `B` (que, apesar de logicamente **ser-uma** classe `A` e se comportar como tal, foi criada por composição e não por herança), você não poderá passar uma instância `iB` para `m1()`, e precisará criar outro método `m2()` para trabalhar com instâncias da classe `B`. Ou seja, você perdeu uma oportunidade de reutilizar código, e acabou "duplicando" código.

Reúso de código e reúso de comportamento trazem diversos benefícios e seguranças:

- Alavanca a criação de novos componentes de software a partir de componentes de software existentes
- Produtividade (menor tempo gasto para desenvolver novos componentes)
- Consistência (um determinado comportamento se mentém igual/consistente ao longo do sistema)
- Confiabilidade (reutilizar um código já testado e validado fornece uma segurança extra para o desenvolvedor)

Tanto a composição como a herança reutilizam código e/ou comportamento, e ambas têm seus cenários de uso específicos. Depois de tudo pelo que passei ao longo do mestrado, e da minha vida profissional, não diria que um é melhor que o outro, pois os cenários de uso de cada um são diferentes.

Uma "regra do dedão" para esse caso: se a sentença **A é-um B** "soa bem", então você deveria utilizar herança, para aproveitar tudo que ela oferece. Caso contrário, tanto se **A é-um B** não "soa bem", mas deseja-se reaproveitar o comportamento de `B` em `A`, como se **A tem-um B** "soa bem", então você deveria utilizar composição.

Comment: Não vejo nada de opinião aqui. Vejo uma visão diferente com fatos e argumentos. Mas entendo sua preocupação, tem gente que tem muita opinião (usando o mesmo critério que elas adotam) sobre o que é opinião :)

Comment: Uma espécie de "meta opinião" :)

Answer (score 26):

[*Resposta menos prolixa*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11378/prefira-composicao-em-vez-de-heranca/11430#comment19626_11380) ;)

**Muitos usam a herança incorretamente para reaproveitar ou organizar código**.

### Herança

Estenda uma classe apenas quando for necessário substituir a classe original pela subclasse, de forma a estender as funcionalidades originais.

Isto envolve o [Princípio da Substituição de Liskov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) e o [Princípio Aberto/Fechado](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) do conceito de *design* [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

Basicamente, o **Princípio da Substituição** diz que uma subclasse deve substituir a superclasse sem alteração no código existente.

O **Princípio Fechado/Aberto** diz que uma classe deve ser fechada para alteração e aberta para extensão, o que significa que ela deve permitir novas funcionalidades sem alteração do código existente.

### Composição e delegação

Use composição e delegação para distribuir as responsabilidades adequadamente entre as classes. Uma classe pode referenciar outras classes e então delegar a execução de métodos que não são de sua responsabilidade para elas.

Isso tem a ver com o [Princípio da Responsabilidade Única](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

### Polimorfismo

Para permitir polimorfismo, use **interfaces** e aplique o [Princípio da Segregação de Interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). Isto significa que nenhuma classe deve ser forçada a depender de métodos que ela não usa.

As interfaces não devem simplesmente conter os métodos que achamos intuitivos num dado momento, pois esse conceito é diferente em cada contexto (como bem explicado na resposta do Marcelo). Antes, uma interface deve conter apenas os métodos interessantes para quem a usa. Se ela é usada em duas situações diferentes, divida em duas.