# É errado usar herança de classes para agrupar comportamentos e atributos comuns?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, herança

## O que nos ensinam sobre Herança

A esmagadora maioria* dos materiais que tratam sobre Herança de Classes a exemplificam como um mero mecanismo de agrupamento de atributos ou ações comuns. No máximo, como um meio de representar uma hierarquia análoga a algo que observamos na vida real. Como amostra**, veja [esta apostila da Unicamp](http://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/cursos/POOCPP/node15.html) e [esta outra da Caelum](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/heranca-reescrita-e-polimorfismo/).

O mesmo se aplica às aulas que assisti sobre o assunto. Ainda lembro quando aprendi que a "orientação a objetos possibilita representarmos o que vemos na vida real". A herança é comumente definida como um relacionamento do tipo "é um". Exemplos clássicos como `Cachorro` e `Gato` estendem `Animal` ilustram isso.

O problema é que, quando aprendemos dessa forma, a nossa preocupação recai em classificar os "objetos da vida real" para agrupar em hierarquias e então procurar atributos e ações comuns para colocarmos na superclasse.

Posso dizer que passei muito tempo usando herança como forma de agrupar coisas parecidas e evitar repetição de código, não considerando pontos importantes como acoplamento e coesão.

## Herança na prática

Contudo, parece que na prática isso simplesmente não funciona tão bem como na teoria, como exemplificado na questão "[Prefira composição em vez de herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/227)". A [excelente resposta aceita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11380/227) diz:

> Somente use herança se o subtipo puder perfeitamente substituir o tipo base.

Essa afirmação, que considero correta, nos leva à consequência lógica que de que o exemplo dos bichos não representa adequadamente o modo como devemos encarar a herança. `Gato` é um `Animal`, mas cada `Animal` exibe um comportamento muito distinto dos demais. `Gato` não é exatamente uma especialização de `Animal`, ou seja, um `Animal` que tem alguma coisa a mais, ele é um tipo único de `Animal` que dificilmente pode ser substituído por outro sem impacto.

Como foi explicado na resposta citada, usar a herança simplesmente para exibir um comportamento comum ou reaproveitar código não é, em geral, uma solução adequada. Para isso existem interfaces e delegação.

## Conclusão

Enfim, minha dúvida é: **existem situações onde seria apropriado usar a herança simplesmente para agrupar objetos com comportamentos e atributos comuns? Ou ainda para criar hierarquias de objetos que representam a "vida real"?** (se possível, dê um exemplo)

Pergunta bônus: será que vale a pena começar a utilizar outros exemplos para herança e não deixar que as pessoas descubram por si mesmas que "na prática a coisa não é bem assim"?

---

**Atualização:** considere "apropriado" ou "certo" o uso da herança que beneficie o sistema a longo prazo, isto é, evite problemas de manutenção e evolução do produto. Por exemplo, usar herança para uma hierarquia pode causar um grande problema se os filhos dessa hierarquia passarem a ter características diferentes dos pais e o código polimórfico começar a "quebrar" ou ficar com vários `if`s para tratar casos específicos.

---

<sup>* Por "esmagadora maioria" quero dizer quase todos os livros, apostilas e aulas que conheço.</sup>

<sup>** Note que não estou dizendo que elas estão totalmente erradas, mas que transmitem um aspecto de forma equivocada.</sup>

<sub>Observação: eu entendo que muitos podem considerar esta questão baseada em opiniões. Se acharem que ela não é adequada ao formato do site, comentem que eu ajustarei ou excluirei conforme o caso.</sub>

Comment: Usar herança indiscriminadamente é coisa dos anos 1990 :) O Cocoa (do OSX e iOS) é considerado um dos melhores frameworks e usa muita pouca herança, a hierarquia é bem "chata"

Comment: Ao utilizar interface não estou a reaproveitar código e sim um modelo que deve ser seguido, se não utilizar herança para reaproveitar código, qual seria o outro objectivo para uma herança? (não é uma pergunta para criticar e sim para complementar, acho que faltou essa explicação no seu texto, o que você pensa sobre o que seria ideal)

Comment: @Filipe Talvez não tenha ficado claro, mas eu defendo que o correto é usar herança para estender um tipo e então  substitui-lo no código existente. Enfim, eu estou concordando com a resposta que citei e discordando da forma como OO é ensinada. De qualquer forma, editei a pergunta pra esclarecer isso. Pelo menos eu espero que tenha esclarecido.

Comment: Acho a pergunta muito pertinente, eu mesmo já criei exemplos de Cachorro e Gato herdando de Animal aqui no SOPT (será que eu sou culpado então?), mas eu fui completamente no impulso, pois como citado na pergunta aqui TODOS os exemplos fazem isso! (eu prefiro dizer todos do que esmagadora maioria, pois 80% pra mim já é "Todos"). Não sei onde pode continuar esse assunto, mas acho imprescindível que ele ocorra. Talvez mais tarde eu releia e tente dar uma mãozinha.

Comment: @utluiz, para ser muito sincero, criei um visão mais pragmática sobre o Princípio da substituição de Liskov. Linguagens modernas como Scala introduziram noções no meio termo como `traits` e `mixing` (composição com cara de herança). Mas sinceramente? Estamos entrando em um nível de academicismo típico de fóruns de Haskell (com todo o respeito ao pessoal). Chega uma hora em que temos que sacrificar pureza por praticidade. Esse tipo de decisão é visceral, não técnica. *Overengering* é um problema muito mais grave na prática do que deturpação de princípios acadêmicos.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Muito interessante. Certamente seu comentário acrescentou bastante. Realmente as `traits` e `mixins` são uma ótima solução prática para o reaproveitamento de código sem o alto acoplamento que a herança traz. Eu também concordo que *overengineering* é um problema, mas o meu objetivo aqui não é apenas gastar muito tempo com um detalhe, mas alcançar uma certa pureza de pensamento para, na prática, conseguir tomar decisões com mais segurança e rapidez. Um dos motivos, na minha opinião, pelo qual as pessoas gastam tempo demais para decidir algo é porque elas estão cheias de dúvidas.

Comment: Tem uma longa disscussão, [Prefira composição ao invés de herança](http://www.guj.com.br/java/304124-prefira-composicao-ao-inves-de-heranca)

Comment: Contribuindo com meus 2 centavos, só ressaltando a seguinte fala do autor: _[...]ele é um tipo único de Animal que dificilmente pode ser substituído por outro sem impacto._. Aqui você se confundiu um pouco no que diz o LSP. A ideia não é que você possa substituir um `Gato` por um `Cachorro`, mas que em **todo lugar que houver um** `Animal` seja possível substituí-lo por um `Gato`. Não há garantia de nenhuma relação entre as classes derivadas de uma mesma terceira classe.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Meu argumento não é que deveria ser possível usar um `Cachorro` no lugar de um `Gato`. O problema é que a herança não é adequada para esse exemplo porque, embora ambos sejam animais, possuam 4 patas, dois olhos e assim por diante, eles raramente apresentam comportamentos em comum. De que adianta um gato que não pega ratos ou um cachorro que não enterra ossos? Meu argumento é que usar herança não é apropriado porque cada um possui características únicas. Se eu quisesse um animal genérico, não precisaria de herança, apenas de atributos como `voz`, `patas`, `peso`, `cor`...

Comment: @utluiz, sim, concordo, apenas deixei claro que o LSP não diz respeito a isso que você colocou como exemplo =]

Comment: @utluiz Está melhor agora, sim. E um comentário sobre a "polêmica" do `Animal`: não vejo problema numa subclasse ser radicalmente diferente da superclasse, desde que - no que diz respeito ao uso comum e agregado - ela seja compatível com o tipo base. Se todo animal tem `comer`, `dormir`, `fazerNecessidades` e `etc`, mas `Gato` implementa `etc` como "pegar ratos" e `Cachorro` implementa `etc` como "enterrar ossos", você ainda pode ter uma coleção de `Animal` que mistura cachorros e gatos e que chama seus métodos polimorficamente. A principal função de `etc` seria então seus efeitos colaterais.

Comment: Esta pergunta está em [discussão no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1174/esta-pergunta-deve-ser-fechada-como-subjetiva).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Bom, vamos partir de definições acadêmicas do padrão de desenvolvimento [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), e em especial do [Princípio de Substituição de Liskov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) ilustrado pelo [mgibsonbr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/215/mgibsonbr) na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11378/prefira-composicao-em-vez-de-heranca/11380#11380) que deu origem à essa pergunta.

## Por que usar composição e não herança?

Se eu tivesse que resumir em uma linha seria: "Para separar comportamento de hierarquia". Muitas vezes queremos apenas agrupar comportamento e características. O problema é que o mesmo comportamento pode ser observado em diferentes hierarquias: Exemplo `Passáros` e `Aviões` voam, na verdade o que queremos reaproveitar entre eles é o comportamento (`Voador`), bem como atributos comuns pertinentes à esse comportamento. Sempre penso em comportamentos como interfaces (exemplos do Java: `Runnable`, `Closeable`, etc).

Comportamento comum não necessariamente define uma relação de herança, muitas vezes é melhor abstrair o comportamento em sua própria unidade. Para isso algumas linguagens possuem mecanismos como [Traits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_(computer_programming)) e [Mixin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin). O Java 8 introduziu [Default Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) para facilitar a reutilização.

## Então por que usar herança?

Pois muitas vezes você realmente quer estabelecer uma hierarquia de classes, sua relação é naturalmente mais forte, e os atributos e comportamentos são específicos para essa cadeia. Os diversos objetos de uma cadeia compartilham "identidade existencial" (`IS-A`), não apenas comportamento comum.

## Mas e [o exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11378/prefira-composicao-em-vez-de-heranca/11380#11380) do `Animal`?

Veja que no exemplo em questão o problema não é com o `Animal` e sim com o `AbrigoAnimais`, em especial com a operação `void adicionarAnimal()` que é uma operação para modificar o estado do abrigo. Assumindo que a relação entre `AbrigoAnimais` e `AbrigoCachorros` seja forte, podemos resolver o problema do `overload` sem composição:

```
abstract class AbrigoAnimais<T extends Animal> {
    abstract T obterAnimal();
    void adicionarAnimal(T a) { }
}
class AbrigoCachorros extends AbrigoAnimais<Cachorro> {
    Cachorro obterAnimal() { return new Cachorro(); } 
    @Override
    void adicionarAnimal(Cachorro c) { } // É override
}

AbrigoAnimais<Cachorro> canil = new AbrigoCachorros();
canil.adicionarAnimal(new Cachorro());
// inválido
canil.adicionarAnimal(new Gato());
```

## Mas e o exemplo do Retângulo?

Mais uma vez o problema é com um método para modificar dimensões (`atribuirLados`), nesse caso as pós-condições do método são conflitantes com uma invariante da subclasse. Eliminando mutabilidade eliminamos esse problema [(Fonte: Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle#A_typical_violation).

## Guidelines

Um guia de perguntas para direcionar uso de interfaces / composição vs herança.

No Universo do seu problema:

- Determinada classe sempre "é" uma instância da superclasse ou apenas pode se comportar como tal? No primeiro caso favoreça herança, no segundo composição.
- Na hierarquia atual existem classes que naturalmente pertencem a outras cadeias hierárquicas com o mesmo comportamento e grupo de atributos (veja que existe é mais forte do que "poderão existir")? Se sim favoreça composição.
- O comportamento em questão é intercambiável? Ou seja, você precisa que determinadas instâncias de uma classe tenham comportamento `X` e outras  comportamento `Y`? Você precisa mudar o comportamento de uma instância dinamicamente? Se sim favoreça composição.
- O funcionamento da sua classe como um todo depende de atributos e métodos do parente? Ou esse comportamento apenas demonstra uma "faceta" da sua classe? No primeiro caso favoreça herança, no segundo composição.

**Conclusão:** Existem diversas ocasiões em que o uso de herança é perfeitamente aceitável, é possível agrupar comportamentos e atributos de maneiras que não ferem o princípio de Liskov, ou ainda refatorar esses objetos para eliminar problemas sem introduzir composição. Quando determinado comportamento e conjunto de atributos é exclusivo de uma cadeia, não há mal nenhum em mantê-lo nessa cadeia.

## SOLID / Liskov e *Overengering*

**Atenção: Texto Opinativo**

Existe uma pergunta implícita na pergunta no @utluiz: "Ferir o princípio de Liskov é aceitável?".

Eu já fui muito mais "purista", sempre tinha uma receita de bolo com *design patterns* (encontrava sempre ocasiões para aplicar padrões como [Visitor](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_Pattern)), criava vários *wrappers* desnecessários para obedecer a [Lei de Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), carregava meu modelo de *genéricos*, *lower bounds*, *upper bounds*, etc pois tudo havia de ser corretamente tipado, genérico e extensível. Depois vivi uma fase da pureza funcional, imutabilidade, mônadas, tipos existenciais e assim por diante. Com o tempo percebi que as linguagens introduziram novos construtores que redefiniram o uso e a aplicabilidade de boa parte dos *design patterns* que eu pregava; também aprendi que é perfeitamente aceitável (e desejável) mutabilidade por aqui e por ali, e hoje não tenho reservas em relação a um `cast` explícito e ou um `typeof` bem encapsulado se isso me poupar várias linhas de "acrobacias" com o sistema de tipos.

Obedecer ao princípio de Liskov (bem como aos outros princípios SOLID) é, com certeza, benéfico. Em especial o princípio de Liskov elimina todo um conjunto de possíveis defeitos em que a API é utilizada ou estendida de maneiras que não foram pensadas pelo desenvolvedor. Garantir que subtipos não possuam pré-condições mais fortes do que as do tipo herdado, garantir que subtipos não possuam pós-condições mais fracas que as dos seus supertipos, preservar invariantes e o histórico de modificações, essas são todas características desejáveis em um sistema robusto. Como é razoavelmente simples quebrar essas regras podemos chegar a extremos, um deles é a linha de pensamento "sempre use composição para evitar ter que refatorar o código no futuro".

Dito isso, na prática precisamos pesar o fator complexidade da API. É importante pensar em quem vai dar manutenção e em quem vai consumir o código. Antes de refatorar um código simples em outro mais complexo para satisfazer determinada diretriz é sempre bom pensar:

- **O que é melhor para quem dará manutenção nesse sistema?**
- **Quais as chances do mantenedor ter problemas com o código como ele está *vs* após o *refactoring*?**

Muitas vezes tornamos o sistema muito mais complicado do que ele precisa ser assumindo que determinada API "poderá" ser utilizada ou estendida de maneira errada... Ou ainda fazemos isso para satisfazer *cornes cases* que simplesmente não acontecem na prática.

Hoje eu prefiro simplicidade à pureza. As vezes um comentário é uma solução bem melhor do que *refactoring* :D.

Existem situações em que herança se encaixa melhor do que composição e vice-versa. Minha escolha é sempre pelo modelo mais natural para representar determinada situação. Se a herança ferir o princípio de Liskov mas ainda for a técnica de abstração mais natural, produzindo comportamento "sensato" (e.g., Para a classe `Quadrado` o método `atribuirLados` poderia lançar uma exceção quando a altura for diferente da largura, isso seria comportamento "sensato" que fere o princípio de Liskov) eu não vejo motivo para introduzir mais complexidade na API. Por outro lado se eu me encontrar "brigando" com a modelagem em várias ocasiões (e.g, necessidade de estados mutáveis e problemas do tipo *[circle-ellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem)* em linguagens de programação sem mecanismos adequados para representar o modelo) está na hora de repensar a modelagem e parar de brigar com o código.

É claro que um programador não aprende a diferenciar "exceções à regra" que causam problemas sozinho. A melhor maneira para isso, além de escrever muito código, é estudar APIs complexas e perceber em que situações o uso indevido de herança causou problemas e foi refatorado ao longo do tempo. APIs de Toolkits, Frameworks, coleções, bibliotecas de testes unitários, etc são todos excelentes candidatos a estudo (classe, interfaces e métodos *deprecated* são seus amigos). Com o tempo fica claro o que pode ser utilizado em cada situação e os *trade-offs* de cada modelo.

Comment: "prefiro simplicidade à pureza." Disse tudo. Simples é mais fácil de entender e estender, mudar e remodelar, usar e abusar. Entretanto, simplicidade é diferente de ser simplista. Noto que programadores iniciantes não conseguem escrever código simples. Parece que só depois de estudo, de reinventar a roda várias vezes, de quebrar a cara outras tantas é que finalmente a ficha cai e começam a aparecer soluções belas e simples. Na verdade foi isso que eu quis dizer no meu comentário sobre "pureza mental". Bem, de qualquer forma, foi uma ótima resposta.

Comment: @utluiz obrigado :). Eu atualizei (a já "prolixa") resposta com um pouco mais de conteúdo sobre decisões de *design*. Também entendi sua colocação sobre "pureza mental"! Só ressaltei a característica dogmática devido à minha própria evolução como programador e por saber que esse público entusiasta do Stack Overflow com QI estratosférico pode cair nas mesmas armadilhas. Acho que nossa área precisa de um fluxo contínuo de "Uncle Bob"s contestando, recapitulando, reinterpretando, refinando e reformulando as melhores práticas.

Comment: Excelente resposta! Só gostaria de dar um esclarecimento (já que minha resposta na outra pergunta está sendo tão citada): o meu exemplo do `AbrigoAnimais` não usa genéricos de propósito, justamente para ser um [mau] exemplo de herança e não um "não-exemplo". Da mesma forma que `List<Object> x = new ArrayList<String>()` é inválido (ainda que `Object x = new String()` seja válido), ao parametrizar `AbrigoAnimais` você resolveu o problema em questão mas também criou outro: como criar um método generalizado para lidar com `AbrigoAnimais`? Agora, só usando *wildcards*...

Comment: Obrigado @mgisonbr. Desculpe por me apropriar da sua (excelente) resposta. Você fez um ótimo trabalho cobrindo [exemplos clássicos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Inheritance_in_object_oriented_languages) de problemas com variância e covariância (não quis entrar nesse mérito para não deixar a resposta ainda maior). E sim, concordo com você, em linguagens que suportam variança de tipo  `adicionarAnimal` seria um típico caso de covariança em posição contravariante. Em Scala teríamos que relaxar o tipo para conformar com Liskov (matando a restrição).

Comment: Em Eiffel poderíamos manter o parâmetro mais restrito no subtipo as custas de confiar que ninguém usará um `AbrigoAnimais` para colocar um gato em um canil. Em Common Lisp poderíamos adicionalmente atualizar dinamicamente o tipo do objeto `canil` para `AbrigoAnimais` na presença de um gato. Ou seja, em diferentes linguagens lidamos com diferentes restrições técnicas e acabamos adotando diferentes padrões de solução como bem ilustrado na sua resposta.

Answer (score 21):

Respondendo à sua pergunta principal:

> existem situações onde seria apropriado usar a herança simplesmente para agrupar objetos com comportamentos e atributos comuns?

- Antes um comentário: "ter comportamento e atributos comuns" não significa nada a menos que implementem uma interface comum. Se dois objetos/classes têm 99% dos campos em comum, mas jamais são processados por uma mesma subrotina, não faz sentido agrupá-los de qualquer maneira que for. O restante da resposta assume que *não só* esses objetos têm características comuns mas que essa parte comum realiza uma mesma interface/cumpre um mesmo contrato.

A [resposta do Anthony Accioly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11713/215) já responde muito bem, mas gostaria de reforçar um ponto importante: nem sempre a ferramenta certa para determinada tarefa está prontamente disponível, e temos que nos virar com o que temos. Se sua linguagem não dá suporte a traits nem mixings (nem tipos dinâmicos, nem *duck typing*, nem tipos de dados algébricos...), e a herança é a maneira mais direta de se reutilizar um código comum, então eu diria que é sim apropriado fazê-lo.

Citando [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11380/215) à pergunta relacionada, um dos grandes problemas de se reutilizar código via composição sob uma linguagem estaticamente tipada é que não existe um meio fácil de delegar a realização de uma interface a outro objeto: ou você já tem um objeto que implementa aquela interface, ou você tem que criar um que o faça - criando cada método e "redirecionando-o" para o objeto apropriado.

Python é dinamicamente tipado, mas vamos supor por um instante que não o seja. Há uma classe (não me lembro qual, e não consigo encontrá-la numa busca) destinada a ajudar na criação de comparadores. Basicamente, ela dá uma implementação padrão aos comparadores `=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=` e `!=` de modo que o programador só precise implementar duas delas - e a biblioteca faz o resto (ex.: `a == b` sse `not(a < b or a > b)`, `a > b` sse `not(a == b or a < b)` e `a < b` sse `not(a == b or a > b)`). Como isso poderia ser feito sem usar herança?

1. Obrigando o programador a definir todos os demais métodos, só redirecionando-os para o objeto utilitário (muito código pra escrever, não?); ou:
2. Criando uma interface para "implementa maior e menor", outra pra "implementa maior e igual", outra pra "implementa menor-igual e diferente", etc...

Cada comparador será totalmente diferente um do outro (ou não seria necessário criá-lo), tudo o que eles têm é um comportamento comum (deduzir os métodos faltantes a partir dos existentes). É perfeitamente possível *não usar* herança e implementar a interface diretamente, mas perde-se toda a conveniência. Trata-se um caso incomum, mas ainda assim é um caso...

> Ou ainda para criar hierarquias de objetos que representam a "vida real"?

O maior erro que vejo quando alguém tenta modelar a "vida real" é achar que só porque duas coisas são diferentes elas devem ser modeladas de forma diferente. Por exemplo, se as classes `Cachorro` e `Gato` não tiverem nenhum comportamento diferente da classe `Animal` - apenas parâmetros distintos - então elas não deveriam sequer existir! Cada cachorro e cada gato deveria ser um objeto da classe `Animal` com um parâmetro `tipo = "cachorro"` (o que inclusive facilita a inclusão/remoção/alteração de outros animais sem alteração no código).

Ninguém modela a vida real. O que modelamos são os **aspectos** da vida real que são **relevantes** para os nossos sistemas.

(Há situações em que - por razões de economia de memória - é bom mover tudo o que é comum em uma "classe da vida real" para uma classe ou objeto distinto que, por coincidência, acaba correlacionando-se à taxonomia da vida real; mas isso já é assunto para uma postagem inteira...)

Comment: +1 Destaque: O que modelamos são os aspectos da vida real que são relevantes para os nossos sistemas.

Comment: @utluiz Se formos ainda além, sequer modelamos em uma classe os aspectos do objeto real que sejam relevantes para o nosso sistema; nós modelamos uma classe com apenas **alguns** aspectos do objeto real, dentre todos os aspectos que sejam relevantes no sistema. Estes alguns aspectos são selecionados em conjunto porque resolvem uma área do problema, e outros aspectos do objeto real serão modelados em outra classe que resolverá uma outra área do problema. Assim, um produto em uma loja teria uma classe que o representa no estoque e outra classe que o representa no e-commerce (DDD-Bounded Context).