# O que fazer se cliente pode ser tanto PF quanto PJ?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, modelagem, engenharia-de-software, regra-de-negócio

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema com orientação a objetos. que precisa manter um cadastro de clientes. Ocorre que esses clientes podem ser tanto pessoas físicas quanto jurídicas. Se os clientes fossem só pessoas jurídicas seria fácil: eu criaria uma classe abstrata `PessoaJuridica` e a classe cliente herdaria dela e implementaria outros membros específicos. Se os clientes fossem só pessoas físicas seria análogo, herdando de uma classe `PessoaFisica`.

Se um cliente, porém, pode ser qualquer um deles fica complicado. Minha primeira ideia foi ter duas classes `ClienteFisico` e `ClienteJuridico` cada uma herdando respectivamente de `PessoaFisica` e `PessoaJuridica`. Mas isso não me pareceu uma boa ideia.

Então pensei em uma segunda opção: definir `Cliente` como pessoa física *sempre* e então criar uma classe `Empresa`, sendo que um cliente pode possuir nenhuma ou várias empresas. Dessa forma, se não há empresas, os únicos dados relevantes são os dados de pessoa física do cliente. Se há empresas, então temos os dados de pessoa física do responsável por ela e junto uma lista com as informações das empresas.

O que eu gostaria de saber é: essa segunda abordagem que eu tomei é uma abordagem padrão? Digo isso no sentido de ser uma abordagem comum para resolver esse tipo de situação. Existem formas melhores para se modelar conceitos como esse em orietnação a objetos?

Comment: Talvez uma leitura [desta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11713/74) te ajude.

Comment: hmm... talvez `PessoaFisica` e `PessoaJuridica` herdem de `Pessoa`, e `Cliente` **tem uma** `Pessoa`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Primeiro: por que precisa ser orientado a objeto? Haverá algum ganho desta forma?

## PJ e PF são entidades separadas

**A segunda abordagem está completamente equivocada** já que se o cliente é uma pessoa jurídica ele não pode ser confundido com uma pessoa física que possui empresas.

Até poderia ser em um modelo fictício ou em um caso muito específico em que o cliente de fato realmente é a pessoa física e o relacionamento se dá com as empresas dele, mas no mundo real não costuma ser o caso.

## O papel das pessoas na organização não define uma nova entidade externa

Talvez você esteja mais distante do que imagina de uma solução. Eu lhe faço uma outra pergunta: se o cliente também é fornecedor, e/ou é um banco que você opera, e/ou é um representante, e/ou é uma transportadora. Como você organiza isso?

Aí você começa se **questionar se um cliente é uma entidade externa**. Talvez cliente seja apenas uma característica, uma propriedade, um atributo, um [papel (role)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/313990/101) de um parceiro de negócios que pode ser uma pessoa física ou uma pessoa jurídica. E essa característica tenha vários detalhes.

Se é para usar orientação a objeto então tem que modelar corretamente. E já aviso que nem sempre é fácil fazer isso em aplicações reais. Por essa razão é comum as pessoas não procurarem pureza de paradigma.

## Não dá para tratar PJ e PF como uma entidade única para facilitar?

Talvez você já tenha começado imaginar que **pessoa jurídica e pessoa física são coisas tão distintas** que você não pode tentar, mantendo um modelo correto, fazer delas uma única entidade que tenha as duas características. Já imagina que realmente exista uma classe, e por consequência que vão existir objetos, que são pessoas físicas e exista uma **outra** classe que define o que é uma pessoa jurídica.

Começa entender que `PessoaFísica` e `PessoaJurídica` são conceitos concretos respaldados inclusive por legislação. E que essas pessoas podem ter uma relação comercial específica em determinado momento (que pode ser permanente também), classificada como de clientela, de fornecimento, de representação, etc.

Existem características comuns entre uma pessoa física e uma jurídica. Então uma classe abstrata pode ser interessante. Esta classe seria `Pessoa`. Pessoa pura e simplesmente é algo que não existe concretamente. Note que neste exemplo não estou falando de pessoa como um ser humano. Neste caso `Pessoa` é apenas a base de características para as classes derivadas dela. Podendo até mesmo não estar limitada a pessoa física e jurídica. Já vi caso de pessoa estrangeira ser usada também, mas não funciona em qualquer situação.

## Modelagem correta

Não posso lhe responder se a abordagem é a padrão porque não tenho dados para isso, e duvido que alguém tenha. E também não sei se é relevante.

Se a intenção é fazer o modelo correto, procurar o padrão, não garante o objetivo. Minha experiência é que o padrão do que as pessoas fazem frequentemente não é o correto a se fazer.

Eu mesmo cometo erros em tudo o que não tenho experiência. E em vários casos o correto complicaria o *design* da aplicação sem necessidade.

## Fundamentando um pouco mais

Veja como um banco (organização financeira que você tem conta corrente) funciona. Ele possui cadastros e contratos completamente distintos para pessoa física e jurídica. Por que isso ocorre? Porque bancos contam com departamentos ou consultorias de Organização e Métodos que definem entidades e processos de forma correta. Eles não se baseiam na opinião leiga de programadores ou dos donos da empresa, como costuma ocorrer na imensa maioria dos casos.

É bem mais difícil do que parece definir corretamente o que cada entidade é e quais suas características, comportamentos, relações, etc. E não existe modelo padrão. O que funciona bem em uma situação não funciona ou complica outra.

E estou falando do modelo conceitual considerando apenas as regras de negócios. Nem incluí aí mecanismos de funcionamento da aplicação quando está lidando com uma pessoa jurídica. Até porque você está falando em termos gerais, não deu nenhum parâmetro de como a aplicação funciona.

## Composição

É possível criar uma classe em que você tenha as características de pessoa física e de pessoa jurídica. A forma mais comum de se fazer isso é através de composição. Ou seja, você terá dados gerais que funcionam bem, não importa se a pessoa é física ou jurídica, e terá algum objeto interno que guardará, externamente, de forma concomitante ou não, os dados específicos da pessoa física ou da pessoa jurídica.

Mas essa é uma abordagem que renega a principal característica da orientação a objeto (o que pode ser uma boa). Embora eu ache que você começa a criar classes *franksteins* nesse caso. Uma classe que tem penduricalhos dependendo da uma propriedade? Não vejo com bons olhos até que eu encontre um motivo plausível para isso existir, mas existem casos para isso.

O [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11713/74) postado pelo bfvaretto é muito interessante para dar uma ideia melhor sobre o assunto.

E a resposta do utluiz mostra alguns exemplos de classes que podem ser usadas para fazer a composição.

## User eXperience

É possível que você não possa ou não queira deixar essa divisão de entidade exposta na tela de cadastro (e outros locais do sistema, mas vou falar só da tela de cadastro para simplificar).

É compreensível que esse modelo de abstração criado no sistema não seja do interesse do usuário, que ele não deseje ou não deva entender como isso é organizado.

Mas uma coisa não impede a outra, a solução do modelo é uma e a solução da UI é outra.

Você pode pedir para fazer a tela do cadastro como se fosse algo único para os dois tipos de pessoa. Um dos primeiros campos pode ser a seleção do tipo de pessoa, que provavelmente vai modificar uma parte da tela (possivelmente uma aba) para adaptar-se aos dados de pessoa física ou jurídica, de acordo com a seleção. Este é um caso interessante para usar composição.

Internamente, no seu modelo de regras de negócio, estará usando uma classe `PessoaFísica` OU `PessoaJurídica` mas o usuário não está vendo isto.

Da mesma forma que pode pedir para ele cadastrar um cliente em uma tela, um fornecedor em outra, etc. Ele acha que está fazendo cadastros separados para no fundo, internamente, ser um cadastro unificado. Quando o usuário acessa uma tela, ela está pré-selecionando um dos atributos da classe. Por exemplo, se entra no cadastro de clientes, a propriedade `ÉCliente` está *setada* como `true`. Se depois ele for tentar cadastrar a mesma empresa como um fornecedor, o sistema avisará que já existe cadastro e apenas perguntará se deve ativar o parceiro para ser um fornecedor, marcando na classe a propriedade `ÉFornecedor` como `true`.

Claro que em um modelo organizado desta forma, você pode ter atributos que só um cliente deve sustentar, ou outros atributos que só um funcionário tem (que pode ser parceiro de negócio também, um vendedor por exemplo). Mas isso é outro problema :) Mas se você prestou atenção, leu a resposta relacionada, já deve imaginar como resolver.

---

Você não perguntou, mas se quiser saber o que eu acho do modelo adotado por praticamente todos os sistemas que existem no mercado, inclusive os grandes e famosos sistemas (um dos quais até fiz parte do desenvolvimento desde seu início), digo: amadores! (claro que isso é uma simplificação, existem motivos "plausíveis" para "cometerem esse erro").

E existe uma outra questão. Com o advento de microsserviços a modelagem passou ser outra. Em geral cada microsserviço passa ter todas as características necessárias para o objeto. Parece lindo, mas é uma das coisas mais difíceis de fazer certo. Um dos motivos que eu digo para fugir dessa arquitetura o quanto pode. E quase todo mundo pode, literalmente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Qual seria o "modelo adotado por praticamente todos os sistemas que existem no mercado"?

Comment: É esse modelo confuso em que pessoa física e jurídica é a mesma entidade, mas um cliente é algo totalmente distinto de um fornecedor. É um modelo criado nos anos 60 porque o mecanismo era mais importante, os computadores não podiam ficar lidando com abstrações além dos sistemas serem muito simples e porque as pessoas eram ingênuas e não entendiam os problema também. Infelizmente ele foi perpetuado. E até hoje ele continua presente e ensinam as pessoas modelarem errado.

Answer (score 25):

Não há uma resposta absoluta. Dependendo do escopo da aplicação, do domínio de negócios e dos requisitos, conceitos de `Cliente` e `Pessoa` podem variar enormemente.

O primeiro passo para resolver sua questão é definir os conceitos dessas entidades, seus atributos e usos. Por exemplo, no seu sistema, qual á diferença de um cliente PJ ou PF? Os dois tipos de cliente serão usados nas mesmas funcionalidades?

Se no seu sistema PF e PJ tem praticamente os mesmos atributos, variando que um possui CPF e o outro CNPJ, então uma abordagem é usar um atributo genérico `numeroDocumento` e diferenciar CPF de CNPJ pelo tamanho do conteúdo ou por um campo auxiliar `tipoPessoa`. Neste caso, você tem apenas uma entidade `Pessoa` variando apenas um atributo.

Se PF e PJ são usados em funcionalidades distintas, isto é, não são intercambiáveis, e não possuem vários atributos ou relacionamentos distintos, crie duas entidades separadas. Não perca tempo buscando semelhanças e hierarquias onde simplesmente não é necessário.

Por outro lado, se PF e PJ podem ser usados numa mesma funcionalidades, porém esta somente precisa de acesso a alguns atributos em comum, então você pode usar uma *interface* para resolver o problema. Vamos supor que há um método que recebe uma `Pessoa` e acessa o nome e o telefone dela. Não é necessário criar uma classe abstrata e usar herança para usar polimorfismo neste caso. Crie uma interface `Pessoa` e faça PF e PJ implementarem essa interface, que pode conter os atributos em comum apenas.

Agora, indo um pouco no sentido do que o `@Maniero` colocou na sua ótima resposta, para o caso de um cadastro mais geral que envolve vários tipos de pessoas, infelizmente a maioria dos sistemas atuais está longe de servir como parâmetro para boas práticas. Os diferentes tipos de pessoas podem ser agentes em diferentes sistemas, ou seja, uma pessoa física ou jurídica pode ser um vendedor, comprador, cliente, fornecedor, garantidor (que fornece uma garantia), segurador (que fornece seguro) e assim por diante.

Nesse contexto mais geral, particularmente, eu modelaria um banco de dados da seguinte forma:

- Tabela `Pessoa` com `id` próprio independente do tipo ou documento e `tipoPessoa`
- Tabela `PessoaJuridica` com atributos de PJ, chave CNPJ e FK para `Pessoa`
- Tabela `PessoaFisica` com atributos de PF, chave RG ou CPF e FK para `Pessoa`
- Tabela `Fornecedor`  com atributos de fornecedor, código e FK para `Pessoa`
- Tabela `Garantidor`  com atributos de garantidor, código e FK para `Pessoa`
- Tabela `Cliente`  com atributos de cliente, código e FK para `Pessoa`
- E assim por diante, para cada "forma" que uma `Pessoa` possa assumir no meu domínio

Mapear isso para uma linguagem orientada a objetos irá depender do uso e dos relacionamentos com outras entidades, mas uma bordagem genérica seria ter uma classe `Pessoa` sem relacionamentos e então `PessoaJuridica`, `PessoaFisica`, `Fornecedor`, `Cliente` e as demais com um atributo do tipo `Pessoa` (composição). Todas essas classes poderiam implementar uma interface com o método `getPessoa()` para então poderem ser usadas polimorficamente em chamadas de métodos.

**Nota:** não estou dizendo que esta é a melhor abordagem, nem que é uma boa abordagem. São apenas algumas ideias, mas que nunca cheguei a testar na prática porque não desenvolvi um sistema do zero com esses conceitos.

Comment: Certamente é uma boa abordagem. Se é para a situação dele é que é mais difícil de afirmar :)