# Pode ser considerada uma má prática de modelagem armazenar todas as pessoas (clientes, funcionários, fornecedores) em uma mesma tabela?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, projeto-de-software, normalização

Estou tentando projetar uma base de dados para um pequeno projeto mas estou tendo dificuldades com relação a normalização das tabelas de pessoas (físicas e jurídicas):

- Cliente
- Fornecedor
- Profissional

Pensei em tentar criar uma única tabela "Pessoa" para agregar campos comuns a todas essas pessoas e criar tabelas adicionais para os campos específicos de cada tipo de pessoa.

Fácil para Cliente e Profissional (ambos sempre pessoas físicas), mas quando o Fornecedor é adicionado na equação a quantidade de campos especializados na tabela "Pessoa" aumenta muito.

[image: Pessoas normalizadas]

Esse tipo de normalização é uma má prática? Poderia me trazer problemas mais adiante que talvez eu não esteja percebendo no momento?

Comment: Vou deixar alguém com mais experiência responder, mas na minha opinião você está no caminho certo - inclusive no detalhe de fazer o `id` das tabelas especializadas ser também uma chave estrangeira pra tabela de pessoas. Você está de fato implementado uma herança entre `pessoa` e `cliente`/`profissional`/`fornecedor`! E se um fornecedor pode ser pessoa física ou jurídica, por não repetir a estratégia? Crie uma tabela só com os campos comuns a cada fornecedor, e outra que represente `fornecedor_pessoa_fisica`, com chaves estrangeiras tanto para `fornecedor` quanto `pessoa`.

Comment: Eu gostaria de oferecer uma resposta à sua pergunta. Pode dar uma breve descrição conceitual de "Profissional" nesta modelagem?

Comment: @Caffé Esse ferramenta que estou criando é destinada a clínicas médicas. Então "Profissional" irá armazenar pessoas que trabalham na empresa. Secretárias, médicos, técnicos, almoxarifado e etc. Também irei alterar o nome da tabela "Cliente" para "Paciente" a fim de ficar mais claro. Chegando em casa edito o post com estes esclarecimentos.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Introdução

Pelo contrário. A ideia de separar as atividades das entidades que possuem relação de negócios com a organização é antiga e era usada porque ninguém tinha pensado direito na questão. Isso foi inventando há décadas quando os recursos computacionais eram extremamente escassos e não havia experiência do que funcionava ou não. Infelizmente há quem continue fazendo assim.

Não vou falar em boas práticas porque elas não costumam ajudar ninguém no caso real prático, entender e resolver o problema é que é importante. Um manual dizendo o que você deve ou não fazer, não resolve o problema. Claro que só a experiência vai permitir entender de fato o problema. Mas vejo que esses manuais de boas práticas causam mais mal do que bem porque quase sempre as pessoas entendem eles como o certo a fazer e não como ideias gerais que podem ou não ser aplicadas no caso específico.

Você pode ter uma necessidade muito específica e o que vou apresentar pode não se aplicar integralmente. Mas no geral você deve modelar os dados como eles realmente são. O problema é que nem sempre é fácil enxergá-los assim. Por exemplo, se você acha que um documento é exatamente como as tabelas devem ser modeladas, cai no erro que era cometido no passado que é separar por atividades.

Em geral a [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101) correta é o caminho mais tranquilo a seguir. Se ela for feita da forma correta fica mais fácil dar manutenção. Entre outros motivos, a normalização foi criada para facilitar que o sistema mude sem muitos traumas. Não normalizar só deve ser escolhido nos raros casos onde a performance se mostrou ruim e está afetando o funcionamento de forma significativa. Então nem pense em fazer super tabelas com tudo o que puder porque em teoria juntar tudo pode facilitar o acesso.

Uma das coisas chaves é não pensar tanto nos requisitos atuais e sim nos requisitos que possam vir acontecer. Não estou dizendo para implementar os requisitos hipotéticos futuros, digo para facilitar que eles sejam implementados. E isto vai de encontro à outras necessidades da modelagem.

## Seu modelo específico

Você diz que cliente só pode ser pessoa física. Tem certeza? Se aparecer um cliente e disser que só pode trabalhar se for tratado como pessoa jurídica - mesmo que pessoas sejam atendidas de fato - por questões tributárias ou outra razão, ele não poderá ser atendido porque o sistema não deixa?

Tem uma coisa muito certa no seu modelo que é separar os dados especializados em tabelas relacionadas. Tratar todos como entidades é a modelagem do mundo real correta. Entidades podem ser relações de negócios de naturezas diferentes. Porque um cliente não pode ser um fornecedor? Nos sistemas antigos não podiam, acabava tendo a mesma entidade cadastrada duas ou mais vezes se ela tivesse relações de negócios diferentes.

#### PJ X PF

Sua modelagem tem dados que não estão normalizados. Pessoa jurídica e física possuem dados que não se relacionam e não devem estar na mesma tabela (geralmente). Então você "deveria" ter uma tabela de `Pessoa` ou mesmo `Entidade` com os dados gerais. E tabelas relacionadas de `PessoaFisica` e `PessoaJuridica` com os dados específicos de cada tipo de pessoa. Na verdade talvez essas duas tabelas possam ser a base e não ter uma tabela `Pessoa` que unifique esses dois tipos, afinal o uso delas são mutuamente exclusivos. É impossível para a mesma entidade ter dados adicionais em ambas. Talvez fosse o caso de pensar em `Pessoa` como uma entidade abstrata que não possui tabela física, eu gosto mais assim. Não quer dizer que uma tabela não possa ser usada, mas tem que pensar bem.

Eu já falei sobre isso em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14852/101). Note que lá não falo de banco de dados relacionais. Então falar em classe abstrata lá faz sentido, aqui não, estou só fazendo uma analogia. A tabela teria que ser concreta e ter uma relação de composição e não de herança, o que pode não ser ideal. E ao contrário da crença popular, nenhum banco de dados relacional *mainstream* possui herança nativa funcional. O fato de **um** banco de dados ter iniciado uma implementação deste recurso há 20 anos e depois abandonado não o torna capaz de lidar com herança de forma apropriada.

#### Dados especializados

Então o maior problema do exemplo demonstrado é a falta de normalização do tipo de pessoa. Mas tem algo estranho quando você tem dados repetidos em `Pessoa` e em `Fornecedor`. Mesmo alguns que só estão em `Fornecedor` parecem estranhos porque são dados que não são exclusivos de um fornecedor. As tabelas relacionadas que guardam informações específicas do tipo de relação de negócio só devem ter dados que só existem na relação. Se o dado é útil às demais relações de negócios, então eles devem estar em uma tabela "superior".

> quando o fornecedor é adicionado na equação a quantidade de campos especializados na tabela "Pessoa" aumenta muito

Aí parece haver um entendimento errado. Adicionar fornecedor não deve colocar campos especializados na tabela de pessoa. Mas por outro lado não há campos especializados em fornecedor, segundo o exemplo. Até entendo que o modelo ainda não está pronto mas no que foi demostrado ainda não há necessidade de uma tabela secundária para cliente e fornecedor. É óbvio que terão dados específicos, só quero deixar claro que os campos demonstrados não são especializados, pelo menos não deveriam ser. Pode até ser que alguém disse que é, mas aí é outro problema. Uma coisa é o requisito que o usuário diz, outra coisa é o requisito real que o usuário não entende. Com os avanços da tecnologia de banco de dados eu acho até que isso possa ser feito de forma diferente, mas precisa de cuidado.

#### Profissional

Uma dúvida de menor importância: eu não sei bem o que é este `Profissional`. Ele realmente é alguém que tem relação de negócios com a organização? Com certeza nunca poderá haver uma mudança, até por força de legislação, que ele possa ser pessoa jurídica? Pergunto porque ele está parecendo um tipo especializado de fornecedor. Pode não ser. Se for acho que precisa de um tratamento apropriado.

#### Cardinalidade

Não sei se entendi o desenho desse diagrama mas provavelmente a relação entre as tabelas deve ser [1:1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253550/101) com cada tabela secundária. Não é possível uma pessoa ter dois dados diferentes de fornecedor, por exemplo. Até consigo enxergar um cenário onde isto é possível mas provavelmente não seria a forma correta de implementar e não seria fácil manter isto. Como a necessidade é rara, acho melhor não pensar nela.

## Conclusão

O que traz problema no futuro é não entender corretamente o modelo, e isto é comum, Mas não tem o que fazer, tem que tentar pensar em tudo, perguntar para quem tem mais experiência, experimentar.

Se tiver dúvidas, ter tudo junto é sempre mais difícil de resolver depois que manter tudo separado. Mas o que torna mais difícil mesmo de resolver é quando falta informações. Imagine o banco ter milhares de entidades cadastradas e para consertar um problema tem que revisar todos os cadastros manualmente.

Ter mais relações complica a manipulação do banco de dados? Sim, sem dúvida, mas só em sistemas muito simples e que provavelmente não irão mudar é que a simplificação deve ser escolhida.

Se você resolver não seguir nada disto e usar uma tabela "linguição", vai ter muitos problemas no futuro? Provavelmente não, mudanças nunca são fáceis, tem como facilitar, mas elas são sempre imprevisíveis na sua totalidade.

O que causa mais problema é redundância de dado. Se um dia tiver que conciliar esses dados pode ser uma enorme tormenta e quase inviável. E no diagrama mostrado, isto pode estar havendo.

Separando os [papéis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326641/101) das pessoas permite que no futuro você tenha mais facilmente além de clientes, fornecedores, profissionais, também vendedores, governos, bancos, transportadores, etc. E você não vai se preocupar se campos estão sendo criados para ficarem sem nada. O segredo é seguir a normalização. Raramente deve haver campos sem dados.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: excelente abordagem, acho que não poderia acrescentar nada alem de opiniões. por exemplo, acredito que aqui caiba uma tabela de dominio para informar o tipo da Pessoa (cliente, profissional, fornecedor, etc) e remover a tabela de cliente (por não ter dados especializados).

Comment: @TobyMosque Eu imagino que não tem nada porque ainda está no meio do processo de modelagem, ele vai colocar alguma coisa ali. De fato seria bem útil indicar **quais** papeis aquele pessoa exerce na organização. Eu acredito que o ideal seria ter colunas indicando isto. Pode ser uma coluna única com *flags* (acho uma otimização exagerada) ou colunas - provavelmente booleanas - para cada papel. Partindo do princípio que a chave primária nos papéis realmente é o próprio `id` da pessoa. Isto pode complicar um pouco (mas é fácil resolver) se tiver tabelas separadas p/ PF e PJ. Mas é o mais correto.

Comment: Quanto ao uso de colunas com flags ou uma coluna de especialização, acredito que isto vai depender do número de tabelas de especialização e a possibilidade de inserir novas especializações com o tempo. Se forem apenas 3 especializações, flags é realmente melhor. Outro ponto é que talvez o endereço é contatos possam ser uma tabela separada com cardinalidade 1:N

Comment: Acho que *flags* em banco de dados raramente são interessantes, pelo menos em cadastros "normais", mas não sei se não é o oposto, quanto mais campos, mais a coluna de *flag* é interessante, ela é só ajuda economizar espaço, pelo menso neste caso, o que é desnecessário. Eu pensei em falar da normalização do endereço mas não sei se ele tem essa necessidade e aí poderia abrir para outros assuntos que não é o foco da pergunta. Inclusive a coisa pode ser mais complicada porque o endereço não precisa estar necessariamente vinculado a uma pessoa. Viu como o assunto dá pano pra manga?

Comment: Em primeiro lugar agradeço pelo interesse na questão. @bigown Realmente como o modelo está em construção existem algumas coisas ali que preciso esclarecer. A ferramenta que estou projetando é para trabalhar com clínicas médicas, nesse caso a nomenclatura da tabela "Cliente" ficou inadequada (imagino que o ideal seria "Paciente" mesmo). Então os pacientes sempre serão pessoa física de acordo com minha pesquisa. Com relação aos dados repetidos em "Pessoa" e "Fornecedor" foi distração minha. Eu havia acabado de colocar "Fornecedor" vinculada a "Pessoa" e esqueci de excluir estes campos do modelo.

Comment: Chegando em casa vou analisar novamente sua pergunta com meu modelo lado a lado e esclarecer qualquer outra questão.

Comment: Faça isto. Só dando uma dica, é provável que não seja o caso:  sabe que cliente e paciente são coisas diferentes? Não digo que você precise fazer esta diferenciação mas em sistemas mais complexos de clínicas isto deveria ser tratado de forma diferente. Na maioria dos casos ambos podem ser o mesmo mas não necessariamente. O cliente **pode** ser um parente, **pode** ser a seguradora, que provavelmente seria uma outra entidade também onde há relação de negócios. E pode ter agentes de convênios também que pode ser diferente da seguradora, e aí vai abrindo possibilidades.

Answer (score 9):

Tratando-se da questão de boas práticas você está no caminho certo, o ponto chave da questão é:

> Esse tipo de normalização é uma má prática? Poderia me trazer
>   problemas mais adiante que talvez eu não esteja percebendo no momento?

"Trazer problemas" é uma questão muito relativa, tratando-se em termos de programação a abordagem está correta, você está aplicando um conceito de herança no qual geralmente todas as linguagens de programação oferecem recursos como `ORM` que fornecem suporte ao esse tipo de abordagem.

Tratando-se em termos de projeto, ai que mora a questão do problema, considerando que você realizou esse esboço/projeto baseado ou em um estudo de caso de algum software ou segundo um levantamento de requisitos de algum cliente, esses requisitos podem mudar e tornar o sua modelagem incorreta ou insuficiente.

Vamos considerar um estudo de impacto breve aqui, primeiramente tratando-se de sua modelagem:

- **Vantagens:** melhor detalhamento dos diversos níveis de informações por exemplo: pessoa -> pessoa física/jurídica -> etc. Alguns `SGBD's` como `PostgreSQL` fornecem suporte a herança nativamente. As linguagens de programação mais modernas possuem ferramentas que auxiliam no mapeamento objecto relacional dessas heranças.
- **Desvantagens**: manutenção requer maior atenção por parte da equipe já que pelo fato das informações estarem dispersas em diversos níveis é necessário maior atenção para casos em que se precisa adicionar/alteração/remover informações das mesmas. A utilização do recurso de herança provido por um `SGBD` pode causar alguns problemas caso seja necessário migrar para uma outro `SGBD` devido as particularidades de cada uma das plataformas.

Considerando agora o cenário de modelagem em que você não utiliza o conceito de herança:

- **Vantagens:** informações se apresentam de forma independente, favorecendo assim a tomada de decisão em caso de alteração. Em sistemas em que os requisitos são muito mutáveis e mudam drasticamente, devido ao isolamento das informações relacionais essa abordagem talvez seja a que resulte em menor impacto.
- **Desvantagens:** dependendo do caso pode haver uma quantidade excessiva de informações duplicadas ao longo de várias entidades.

Para resumir então, a decisão da modelagem depende da maturidade do profissional em observar o cenário de trabalho, ou seja, não existe uma verdade absoluta, pois algumas vezes as metodologias de boas práticas acabam por complicar algumas tarefas quando por exemplo nem o cliente sabe o que quer ou muda de opinião da noite para o dia.

Lembrando que nem sempre é possível construir a melhor casa do mundo em cima do lixão, ou seja, tem casos que temos que fazer o melhor possível dentro das possibilidades.