# Atributos nulos em um objeto é Ruim?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, característica-linguagem

Tenho um objeto que possui 7 atributos:

- 2 atributos estão sempre com algum valor atribuído.
- 3 valores estão sempre setados caso seja necessário fazer uma consulta com filtros (os 3 atributos são filtros).
- Os últimos 2 atributos são exclusivos (se um está setado com algum valor os outros 5 atributos são dispensados (`null`).

Então eis a minha duvida: é ruim ter um objeto com múltiplos campos com valor `null`? Todos os atributos fazem parte do escopo do objeto e o objeto em si já é especializado. Há gasto de memória mesmo que os atributos estejam como `null`?

Comment: Obs: Estou utilizando PHP

Comment: "Há gasto de memória mesmo que os atributos estejam como `null`?" Há a memória gasta pela referência em si (4 ou 8 bytes por campo, dependendo se a arquitetura é de 32 ou 64 bits). Para um único objeto, não é nada de mais, se forem muitos (muitos *mesmo*) aí começa a pesar... Pode ou não ser vantajoso usar um objeto separado, mas aí já estamos caindo no campo da micro-otimização (i.e. dificilmente valerá a pena se preocupar com isso).

Comment: @mgibsonbr Interessante, não me recordava que gastavam-se até 8 `bytes` por referencia.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Em modelagem de objetos não existe uma resposta certa para todos os casos, mas há princípios que podem ser aplicados em qualquer situação.

O cenário exposto na pergunta dá a entender que o objeto está carregando mais responsabilidades do que deveria. Vamos analisar isso com calma.

## Um cenário possível: pesquisa

O que você me descreveu parece muito com um objeto que carrega dados de uma consulta/pesquisa.

Por exemplo, um gerente de um banco pode estar fazendo a pesquisa por um contrato de um de seus clientes. Os dois campos sempre preenchidos poderiam ser `número da agência` e `código do gerente`. Os três campos opcionais poderiam ser `nome do cliente` e um intervalo de datas para delimitar os resultados. Os dois últimos exclusivos poderiam ser filtros exclusivos como `contratos com pendências` ou `contratos com atraso de pagamento`.

Dentro desse exemplo, o objeto carregaria as informações de consulta da tela. Em muitos casos isso é usado com frameworks MVC para fazer o mapeamento automático dos campos da tela para um objeto no servidor.

Nessa situação não há problema algum em ter um objeto assim, representando um formulário web.

O que eu não recomendaria é enviar um objeto desses diretamente para os métodos de pesquisa do seu model.

Seguindo com o exemplo, seria melhor ter um objeto para identificação do gerente com os dois primeiros campos e ter três métodos de pesquisa. O primeiro receberia o objeto que identifica o gerente e os três campos opcionais. O segundo faria a busca por contratos pendentes recebendo apenas a identificação do cliente. O terceiro também receberia a identificação do gerente e faria a busca por contratos com atraso.

A lógica para chamar o método adequado com os parâmetros adequados é responsabilidade do seu Controlador (*Controller*).

## Outro cenário possível: dados de domínio

Outra cenário que vejo é que esse objeto seria um objeto ou classe de domínio, representando informações importantes e fundamentais do sistema.

Por exemplo, o objeto poderia representar uma Pessoa. Os dois campos obrigatórios poderiam ser um código e o tipo de pessoa (Física e Jurídica). Os três campos opcionais poderiam ser dados como nome, endereço e telefone. Os dois campos exclusivos poderiam algum tipo de Pessoa especial que não necessita o preenchimento dos dados mencionados acima.

Dentro desse exemplo específico, já existem algumas discussões aqui no SO sobre qual é a melhor abordagem:

- [O que fazer se cliente pode ser tanto PF quanto PJ?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14839/227)
- [Pode ser considerada uma má prática de modelagem armazenar todas as pessoas (clientes, funcionários, fornecedores) em uma mesma tabela?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54177/227)

## Considerações

A lógica contida em sua entidade diz que não é uma simples questão de adotar um conjunto de campos ou outro. Existe um conjunto de regras que pode gerar complexidades futuras.

Para resolver isso, polimorfismo ou composição poderiam ser alternativas interessantes, mas a aplicação dessas técnicas varia de caso para caso.

Quanto ao desempenho ou uso de memória, dividir os dados entre diferentes objetos irá utilizar mais memória e consumir mais processamento. Entretanto, a perda ou ganho de uma abordagem é ínfimo para a grande maioria das aplicações.

Portanto, a não ser que o desempenho seja crítico para seu programa (o que é bem difícil já que PHP não está entre as linguagens mais eficientes), é melhor focar em deixar o seu código mais limpo e bem organizados do que se preocupar com esse aspecto em um nível de detalhes como este.

Comment: @utuluiz sê verdadeiro: Tinhas essa resposta em clipboard, não era? :P (fora de brincadeiras: boa resposta!)

Comment: O meu cenário é o de pesquisa: o usuario pode pesquisar livros pela letra de inicio ou pela quantidade de membros que compraram ou ainda uma pesquisa com filtros: autor, dt de lançamento, editora e pais de origem.

Comment: @MoshMage Obrigado! Na verdade foram uns 20 minutos para elaborar :D

Answer (score 6):

> Então eis a minha duvida: é ruim ter um objeto com múltiplos campos
>   com valor null? Todos os atributos fazem parte do escopo do objeto e o
>   objeto em si já é especializado.

Respondendo objetivamente, no seu caso sim. Não por motivos de desempenho mas por motivos de facilidade de compreensão do código.
Se esse objeto representa o objeto persistido no banco não é uma boa pratica que tenha atributos não relacionados ao próprio objeto, nesse caso os filtros não fazem parte do escopo do objeto persistido, e se for somente uma classe de busca não vejo necessidade de instanciar a mesma, poderia utilizar uma classe estática ou Singleton.

Perceba que o exemplo fica estranho como Objeto e mas nem tanto como classe estática.

Objeto Instanciado:

```
carro = new Carro();
carro.filtroCor = "azul";
carro.filtroMarca = "Suzuki";
carro.busca();
```

Classe Estática:

```
carro = new Carro();
PesquisaCarro.filtroCor = "azul";
PesquisaCarro.filtroMarca = "Suzuki";
PesquisaCarro.busca(carro);
```

Eu separaria o objeto persistido da classe responsavél pela busca. Independente de como vai implementar a lógica de busca.

Sugestão:

```
carro = new Carro();
carroControler = new CarroControler();
carroControler.busca(carro, "azul","Suzuki"); //Chama lógica de persistência passando parâmetros.
```

> Há gasto de memória mesmo que os atributos estejam como null?

Pelo meu ponto de vista, três ponteiros a mais na memoria a principio não vão matar ninguém.