# Modelo de relação entre cliente e fornecedor

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, modelagem, arquitetura-de-software

Há bastante tempo eu fiz uma pergunta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14839/o-que-fazer-se-cliente-pode-ser-tanto-pf-quanto-pj) sobre a modelagem de clientes utilizando orientação a objetos. O que eu tirei das respostas é que clientes, fornecedores, e etc, ao invés de serem caracterizados como entidades propriamente ditas podem ser melhor compreendidos como relações entre entidades.

Na epoca eu pensei sobre o assunto durante um tempo e realmente faz mais sentido considerar que uma empresa ser cliente de outra é na verdade um status daquela empresa. Essa abordagem tem algumas vantagens, entre elas permitir uma extensibilidade maior.

Recentemente eu peguei um sistema antigo que desenvolvi e senti a necessidade de repensar ele inteiro. Nisso vi uma oportunidade de aplicar esse tipo de modelagem, mas encontrei um problema.

No caso concreto o sistema é utilizado por uma única empresa que mantém cadastros de Clientes, Fornecedores e Transportadoras.

Na versão atual eu apliquei a abordagem tradicional. Tenho as classes `Cliente`, `Fornecedor` e `Transportadora`. Acontece que há uma quantidade enorme de código duplicado, uma vez que a maioria das propriedades são comuns a pessoas jurídicas em geral.

Eu poderia utilizar herança, mas resolvi tentar utilizar a abordagem que foi sugerida na pergunta que fiz. Criei uma única classe `Empresa` que possui todas as características de uma pessoa jurídica.

Então criei uma classe `RelacaoComercial` que modela a relação existente entre uma empresa e a empresa que usa o sistema. A partir daí criei duas classes `RelacaoClientela` e `RelacaoFornecimento` que herdam de `RelacaoComercial`.

A classe `Empresa` tem então uma propriedade `List<RelacaoComercial> RelacoesComerciais` contendo suas relações comerciais com a empresa que usa o sistema.

A diferença entre o modelo tradicional e esse é então: no modelo tradicional um cliente é uma instância de `Cliente`, enquanto que nesse modelo um cliente é uma instância de `Empresa` que possui na propriedade `RelacoesComerciais` uma instância de `RelacaoClientela`.

Há um requisito, entretanto, de marcar para cada cliente os fornecedores que ele utiliza. No modelo atual eu simplesmente estabelecia uma relação NxN entre `Cliente` e `Fornecedor`.

Mas e nesse novo modelo? Não existe uma classe `Cliente` e nem uma classe `Fornecedor` para estabelecer a relação. Minha ideia foi: na classe `RelacaoClientela` referenciar uma lista de empresas e impor a regra de negocio que só uma empresa que é um fornecedor pode ser adicionado a essa lista, mas não sei se esse é o caminho.

Usando esse tipo de modelo como posso fazer esse tipo de relacionamento?

Comment: Não sei se dá para entender todo o problema só com estas informações. Algumas coisas parecem um pouco vagas. Antes de tentar responder (se eu entender melhor o problema), Vou dizer que não entendo essa `RelacaoComercial`. Nem o seu relacionamento com `Empresa`. Dá a impressão que não está fazendo exatamente o que foi dito na outra pergunta. Eu imaginaria que os dados de `Cliente` de `Fornecedor` , etc. se relaciona direto com empresa. Outro ponto que tem na resposta àquela pergunta é que é possível abstrair o fato do modelo não diferenciar clientes, fornecedores ou manter como uma entidade só.

Comment: Lá falei sobre tela, mas poderia fazer isto no sistema como um todo. Eu disse poderia, não que seja uma necessidade. Independente disto, não consigo imaginar porque teria dificuldade em fazer a listagem dos fornecedores que um cliente fez compras. A não ser que o modelo esteja todo errado, mas não sei como está modelado. Eu acho esse requerimento estranho, mas se ele existe o relacionamento é N:M mesmo, seria assim não importa a modelagem. Cada Cliente pode ter M fornecedores. Cada fornecedor pode fornecer para N clientes.

Comment: Também não se se deveria chamar isso de "relação", eu acho que deveria ser "entidade", talvez seja porque o modelo está errado, mas novamente, desconheço isso.

Comment: Na verdade o que eu tinha entendido naquela pergunta é que temos uma classe que representa pessoas jurídicas em geral. Aqui eu chamei de `Empresa` essa classe. A partir daí, seria necessário algo para especificar se essa empresa mantém relação de clientela, fornecimento, etc. Na sugestão que você deu isso seria feito com propriedades: `ÉCliente`, `ÉFornecedor`, etc. Mas como você mesmo disse, pode ser necessário especificar atributos/métodos que só existem para clientes ou fornecedores. Esses atributos/métodos não podem ficar na classe `Empresa`, já que não existem para transportadoras.

Comment: Foi aí que eu pensei nessa solução. Eu me baseei um pouco no modelo de Claims usado para autorização. Um usuário tem várias Claims que definem sua identidade. Nesse caso pensei em fazer algo análogo: uma empresa tem várias relações comerciais estabelecidas, relação de clientela, fornecimento e etc. A partir daí para que uma empresa atue como `Cliente` bastaria adicionar na lista de relações comerciais uma instância de `RelacaoClientela`. Essa era a ideia inicial que eu tinha proposto. A classe `RelacaoComercial` estaria aí para que `Empresa` tivesse uma lista "genérica" de relações comerciais.

Comment: Ma como isso não estava dando muito certo inicialmente, resolvi seguir a outra abordagem proposta na outra pergunta. Criei uma classe `Empresa` e criei classes `Cliente`, `Fornecedor` e `Transportadora` com referência para `Empresa`. Como nesse domínio específico clientes, fornecedores e transportadoras **sempre** são pessoas jurídicas, estou pensando só se não é o caso de utilizar herança invés de composição.

Comment: Acho que entendi a classe agora. Pode ser interessante o que fez, se eu entendio certo. Se fizer herança voltará para o modelo tradicional de papeis separados. Novamente, sem mais detalhes eu não consigo responder esta pergunta específica, até porque ela já não é tão conceitual, ela é mais concreta. Talvez seu erro seja que ainda pensa nos papéis como ponto central e não na empresa como esse ponto. Composição é fazer a empresa ter os papéis (relações comerciais), não é fazer os papéis terem uma informação de `Empresa`. Isto resulta igual à herança. Veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101

Comment: Eu editei um pouco a pergunta. Na verdade, eu até poderia tentar deixar ela mais abstrata. Perceba que tudo se resume ao seguinte: se modelarmos `PessoaJuridica` com uma classe e as possíveis relações (clientela, fornecimento, etc) da forma que sugeri, quando existe relação NxN entre duas pessoas jurídicas que tem atuações diferentes (um é cliente e o outro fornecedor), como modelar essa relação? Pensei em colocar uma lista de `Empresa` na `RelacaoClientela` e impor uma regra de negócio de só poder adicionar, se a empresa for fornecedor, mas não sei se é uma boa abordagem, me parece estranho.

Comment: Eu não entendi bem qual é o problema. Talvez a modelagem esteja errada, mas não sei qual é ela. Se só acha estranho, talvez seja porque o requisito seja estranho, só isso. Talvez nem seja estranho.

Comment: Se você criar um diagrama de entidades e relacionamentos pode facilitar a obtenção da resposta.