# Tipo genérico em Java

Tags: java, genéricos, polimorfismo

Eu tenho 3 classes, `Expression`, `Operation`, `Scalar`

```
public abstract class Expression<R extends Expression> {
    public abstract R calcular();
}

public abstract class Operation<T extends Expression, R extends Expression> extends Expression {
    protected T arg;
    public Operation(T arg) {
        this.arg = arg;
    }
    public T getArgumento() {
        return arg;
    }
}
public class Scalar extends Expression {
    private double valor;

    public double getValor() { }
    public void setValor(double valor) { }
    public Scalar(double valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }
    public Scalar calcular() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

O que eu quero é criar a classe de inverter um número escalar, por exemplo:

```
 public class InversaoEscalar extends Operation{
     public InversaoEscalar(Expression<Scalar> arg){
        super(arg);
     }
     public Scalar calcular(){
         return new Scalar(Parametro);
     }
 }
```

Sendo que em `Parametro` eu gostaria de passar `1/arg.calcular().getValor()`.

Mas não entendo o porque de `arg.calcular()` não me devolve um objeto do tipo `Scalar`, e sim do tipo `Expression`, já que no meu entendimento, se eu estou passando um argumento do tipo `Expression<Scalar>`, o método `calcular` dele deveria me trazer um tipo `Scalar`, não? Como resolver este problema?

Comment: `se eu estou passando um arg do tipo Expression, o metodo calcular dele deveria me trazer um tipo Scalar` por que você acha isso? Se arg é Expression arg é Expression.

Comment: Meu metodo calcular() em Expression<R> retorna R, entao acredito que calcular em um Expression<Scalar> retornaria Scalar, não?

Comment: Você no caso apenas tem `1/arg.calcular().getValor()` no lugar onde está escrito `Parametro`?

Comment: Isso, `1/arg.calcular().getValor()` no lugar de parametro, mas como `arg.calcular()` é Expression, ele nao tem metodo `getValor()`. E o retorno é Scalar mesmo, editei ali na pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está herdando sem especificar os tipos genéricos:

```
Operation extends Expression -> R sem tipo
Scalar extends Expression -> R sem tipo
InversaoEscalar extends Operation -> T e R sem tipo
```

Quando você não declara um tipo, a implementação de genéricos usa um tipo base (no caso `R extends Expression`, logo o tipo base de `R` será `Expression`, se não houvesse um *upper bound* explícito o tipo seria `Object`).

---

## Solução pontual:

Faça `Scalar` ser uma `Expression<Scalar>` (nesse caso `calcular` retornará um `Scalar`).

```
class Scalar extends Expression<Scalar>
```

Faça `InversãoScalar` definir ao menos o tipo `Expression<Scalar>` para `T` (`arg` será desse tipo `T`), e um tipo qualquer de `Expression` para `R` que nem está sendo utilizado:

```
class InversaoEscalar extends Operation<Expression<Scalar>, Expression<?>> {

    public InversaoEscalar(Expression<Scalar> arg) {
        super(arg);
    }

    public Scalar calcular() {
        return new Scalar(1/arg.calcular().getValor());
    }
}
```

**P.S.**: sua solução está um pouco carrega de genéricos e herança (as possibilidades de combinações aí tornam o uso da API complicada; mesmo se desejar seguir por esse caminho você terá que repensar os seus *bounds* e o que deve ser parametrizável). Recomendo dar uma lida nessa pergunta: "[É errado usar herança de classes para agrupar comportamentos e atributos comuns?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11594)", bem como no código de outras bibliotecas que lidam com expressões matemáticas em Java.