# Java - pra que serve o <?> e TIPOS GENÉRICOS?

Tags: java

Não sei bem, mas suponho que a interrogação faça parte do Reflection do Java, mas queria saber pra que serve, e onde posso estudar tipos genéricos, de prefêrencia em Português, pois meu Inglês não é muito bom ;-; (estou aprendendo para melhorar nos estudos)

Comment: Isto responderia sua dúvida? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15799/tipo-gen%C3%A9rico-em-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse `<?>` é conhecido como tipo curinga (Wild Card). Ele faz parte dos tipos genéricos. Com ele você consegue receber um genérico de qualquer tipo. Por exemplo:

```
    List<?> curinga = null;
    List<String> string = Arrays.asList("Andrei", "skqo");
    List<Integer> inteiros = Arrays.asList(1, 2);

    curinga = string; // SEM PROBLEMAS
    curinga = inteiros; // SEM PROBLEMAS
```

**Respondendo a pergunta:**

Os tipos genéricos servem para flexibilizar a implementação. Pois eles aceitam um numero maior de tipos diferentes.

**Curingas delimitados:**

Agora veja um outro exemplo:

```
    List<? extends Number> numeros = null;
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Maria", "Jose");

    numeros = strings; // ERRO EM TEMPO DE COMPILAÇÃO
```

A implementação acima, não é aceita pelo compilador, pois a lista `numeros` recebe **qualquer tipo que estende de `Number`**. Logo, não é possível atribuir uma lista de strings à ela.

Mas isso é possível:

```
    List<? extends Number> numeros = null;
    List<Double> doubles = Arrays.asList(20.0, 12.1);
    List<Integer> inteiros = Arrays.asList(2,1);

    numeros = doubles; // sem problemas
    numeros = inteiros; // sem problemas
```

**Conclusão**

Os genéricos são ótimos para fazer reuso de classes e métodos pois eles podem ser parametrizados por tipo. Porém há perda de informações dos tipos durante sua execução. Por exemplo um `List<String>` é na verdade apenas um `List` quando se usa genéricos. E isso pode gerar problemas como desempenho.

Tem muitos sites na internet que tratam bem do assunto (na minha humilde opinião).
Uma forma de entender como eles funcionam é lendo sobre o assunto e fazendo testes simples iguais os exemplos que eu coloquei acima.