# Quais as vantagens e desvantagens do Duck Typing?

Tags: estilo-de-codificação

[Duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) [Typing](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) é um princípio que prega que não se deveria usar herança ou interface para definir quais métodos uma classe deve ter.

[Exemplo](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#duck-typing):

```ruby
# ruim
class Animal
  # método abstrato
  def speak
  end
end

# estendendo superclasse por herança
class Duck < Animal
  def speak
    puts "Quack! Quack"
  end
end

# estendendo superclasse por herança
class Dog < Animal
  def speak
    puts "Bau! Bau!"
  end
end

# bom
class Duck
  def speak
    puts "Quack! Quack"
  end
end

class Dog
  def speak
    puts "Bau! Bau!"
  end
end
```

Que vantagens e que problemas essa abordagem pode trazer?

Comment: Relacionado: [É errado usar herança de classes para agrupar comportamentos e atributos comuns?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11594/3117)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Como um desenvolvedor Java, não sou o fã nº1 dessa técnica. :b

Porém consigo ver alguns dos impactos que o *Duck Typing* pode ter.

### Vantagens

- **Flexibilidade**: facilita refatoração, já que não é necessário remodelar uma hierarquia de classes e interfaces quando algum tipo de comportamento muda. É um tipo de "polimorfismo barato", permitindo até usar classes já existentes em métodos genéricos sem precisar alterá-las para que implementem interfaces ou herdem classes.
- **Acoplamento mais fraco**: interfaces e classes abstratas são espécie de contratos e forçam uma ligação forte entre subclasses e superclasses. Sem isso, você não fica tão dependente dessas ligações.
- **Liberdade de modelagem**: as classes não precisam cumprir contratos pré-definidos, então o desenvolvedor pode postergar decisões de design e mudar o comportamento de métodos genéricos a qualquer momento.

### Desvantagens

- **Propensão a erros**: toda liberdade tem o seu preço. Cada método será responsável por verificar o tipo que ele recebe, já que não há um contrato para garantir o comportamento do objeto recebido. Qualquer parte do código que chama um método que acessa atributos ou métodos não declarados tem o potencial de gerar erros, já que o desenvolvedor precisa conhecer bem o código que está executando ou fazer suposições sobre isso.
- **Acoplamento forte**: não usar interfaces ou classes abstratas não garante acoplamento fraco. No fim das contas, você pode acabar chamando métodos indiscriminadamente e acabar com um acoplamento forte. E, para piorar, fica mais difícil de identificar isso.
- **Dificuldade de rastreamento**: não ter um "contrato" de uso, faz com que seja imprevisível quem vai executar o que, portanto se você precisa refatorar um código você pode passar por dificuldades para identificar quais classes precisam também de ajuste.
- **Menos legibilidade**: O desenvolvedor tem mais liberdade, só que sem disciplina um desenvolvedor inexperiente irá acabar com um código ilegível. Imagine dar manutenção num sistema onde não há tipos comuns, cada classe é diferente e o desenvolvedor chama a todo momento métodos aleatórios em objetos sem tipo definido.
- **Desempenho**: em algumas linguagens, como Java que usa reflexão, o desempenho do *Duck Typing* é inferior a uma chamada normal porque o compilador não pode otimizar a chamada. Porém, em linguagens dinâmicas (interpretadas) geralmente não há diferença. No C++, pelo que entendo, não há problemas de desempenho porque o compilador consegue identificar se as classes realmente possuem os métodos invocados dessa forma.

## Considerações

Do meu ponto de vista, usar *Duck Typing* pode ser vantajoso para projetos que tem como prioridade serem flexíveis e adaptáveis, além de terem desenvolvedores focados e experientes numa equipe pequena.

Entretanto, com pessoas mais "novatas" ou para projetos grandes e de longa duração, trabalhar com um pouco mais de "burocracia", isto é, um modelo de classes e interfaces bem definida, provavelmente traz mais benefícios e evita o caos.

Comment: Concordo com você @utluiz, e não só você, como qualquer desenvolvedor (99%) _"nascido"_ em linguagens orientadas a objetos, não estaria predisposto a esse tipo de abordagem, além disso esse tipo de "técnica" também vai contra os princípios de modelagem de projetos orientados a objetos, onde tudo fica "solto". Acredito que como você disse isso pode funcionar para projetos pequenos (não se esqueça que os projetos "pequenos" crescem). Mas quando é necessário uma melhor organização, isso não é bem vindo. (Desculpe tive que dar um pitaco de opinião, hehe)

Answer (score 13):

> **Disclaimer:** Como o [utluiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/227/utluiz), também sou Javeiro. Em especial dá escola de linguagens fortemente e estaticamente tipadas; acredito em sistemas de tipagem complexos e compiladores aptos a eliminar inconsistências cedo para evitar problemas em tempo de execução. Trocando em miúdos, sou um cara que tende bem mais para Scala do que para Python; de maneira que defender mecanismos de *Duck Typing* e *Late binding* é, no mínimo, fazer o papel de advogado do diabo.

[A resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28332/100) do [utluiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/227/utluiz) foi bastante completa no sentido de ilustrar as vantagens e desvantagens do *Duck Typing* conforme bos práticas de modelagem de sistemas, porém, gostaria de trazer a tona alguns dos problemas típicos que podem surgir com interfaces e classes abstratas, com especial foco naqueles que podem ser amenizados através de *Duck Typing*.

## Interfaces vs Duck typing

Interfaces, traits e classes / métodos abstratos são maneiras de definir contratos. Esses contratos nada mais são do que acordos sintáticos. Exemplo:

> Se você quer participar da minha corrida você tem que ter um método `void correr(Point destino)` que será disparado no começo da corrida e um método `Point getPosicao()` que me retorne a sua posição a todo momento.
>
> Dessa forma eu entrego a você uma interface `Corredor` que você deve implementar como bem entender. Você se registra na corrida como um `Corredor` e eu não estou interessado em nenhum outro aspecto seu além desses que previamente combinamos.

Veja que um acordo sintático pode ser desrespeitado semanticamente, ou seja, o método `correr`, desde que obedeça a assinatura da interface pode  fazer qualquer outra coisa além de correr. O "contrato" dá uma sensação de segurança (através de algum nível de acoplamento), mas no fundo a única coisa que ele garante é a presença de determinados métodos em determinado objeto.

O *Duck Typing* também é um acordo sintático:

> Eu espero que qualquer corredor que se registre na corrida implemente os métodos `correr` e `getPosicao`, você não precisa necessariamente assinar nenhum contrato comigo agora, porém você me promete que é capaz de fazer isso, se não as coisas ficarão complicadas na hora da corrida.

Por esse motivo *Duck Typing* é comumente associado a erros em tempo de execução, linguagens dinamicamente tipadas e *late binding*. Há maneiras elegantes de trabalhar com *Duck Typing* em linguagens estaticamente tipadas, inclusive obtendo erros em tempo de compilação (veja a parte sobre *Duck Typing* em Scala) mas esse não é o ponto aqui.

Há também uma certa desconfiança sobre a semântica dos métodos expostos pelo corredor. Como o método `correr` não segue um contrato, ele pode ter sido escrito antes do planejamento da minha corrida, será que ele faz exatamente o que eu preciso? Veja que de uma maneira ou de outra, com ambas as abordagens é possível desrespeitar semanticamente o contrato.

A diferença principal entre um mecanismo e outro é:

> Com uma interface você concorda explicitamente a priori que trabalhará conforme a minha definição do que faz um corredor; esse contrato, desse momento em diante, fará parte da sua definição essencial (e.g., `Pessoa implements Corredor`).
>
> **VS.**, Para ser um corredor você tem que agir como um corredor conforme a minha definição de corredor no momento em que estiver correndo.

## Múltiplos contratos

Interface tem as suas vantagens, mas também seus problemas. Dentre eles, possíveis explosões de complexidade.

Imagine que um atleta de Triathlon que nada, anda de bicicleta e corre precisa atender à determinado contrato. Ele não deixa de ser um corredor, nadador ou ciclista por definição, logo acaba assinando um contrato que herda de outros contratos:

```
interface Triathloner extends Corredor, Nadador, Ciclista
Pessoa implements Triathloner
```

Veja que estamos assinando um contrato um tanto quanto pesado aqui, as barreiras entre **é-um** e **se comporta como um** começaram a ficar cinzas.

Imagine agora que o mesmo atleta quer participar de outra competição ao estilo Triathlon, porém que substitui ciclismo por escalada. Ele não quer deixar de ser um atleta de Triathlon, logo, acaba implementando duas interfaces que herdam de outros contratos:

```
interface Triathloner extends Corredor, Nadador, Ciclista
interface TriathlonerII extends Corredor, Nadador, Escalador
Pessoa implements Triathloner, TriathlonerII
```

Novamente a complexidade está aumentando. As nossas interfaces estão deixando de fazer sentido.

## Operações opcionais

Imagine agora uma terceira situação, em determinado evento o atleta pode escolher entre `pedalar` ou `escalar` mas obrigatoriamente deve `correr` e `nadar`. Como modelar esse contrato? Deve o atleta implementar uma interface específica para aquele evento? Devemos carregar a interface de genéricos e construir um mecanismo com novos métodos e *late dispatching* para distinguir o atleta que sabe nadar daquele que quer nadar na competição? Deve o atleta que não sabe nadar implementar o método `nadar` com um corpo vazio (ou talvez uma exceção)?

Mas esse exemplo parece um tanto quanto forçado não? Esse é o exato caso da [a API de Listeners AWT em Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/api.html). Eis um exemplo:

> Um [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) deve implementar os métodos `mouseClicked`, `mouseEntered`, `mouseExited`, `mousePressed` e `mouseReleased`. Caso um `Listener` esteja interessado em apenas parte dos eventos ele deve herdar da classe abstrata [`MouseAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) que implementa todos os métodos de `MouseListener` (bem como de `MouseMotionListener`, `MouseWheelListener`e `EventListener`) com  corpos vazios. Isso permite ao usuário sobrescrever apenas os métodos de seu interesse.

Os problemas aqui são óbvios: Completa mistura entre "ser um" e "se comportar como", classes abstratas com todos os métodos concretos e sem corpo, bem como absoluta confusão sobre quais interfaces implementar e/ou quais *adapters* estender:

```
interface MouseListener extends EventListener
interface MouseMotionListener extends EventListener
interface MouseWheelListener extends EventListener
interface MouseInputListener extends MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
abstract class MouseMotionAdapter implements MouseMotionListener
abstract class MouseAdapter implements MouseListener, MouseWheelListener, MouseMotionListener
abstract class MouseInputAdapter extends MouseAdapter implements MouseInputListener
```

Do outro lado temos a [API de Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) do jQuery que espera um objeto qualquer (e opcional) `settings`. Todas as propriedades e métodos desse objeto são opcionais:

```
$.ajax();
```

E:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
  },
  dataType: "json",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" },
  success: function( data ){
    console.log(data);           
  }
});
```

Pense na complexidade para desenvolver uma API similar sem *Duck Typing*... A interface para *callbacks* e métodos manipuladores, os *design patterns* como *Builder* entrando em ação e assim por diante.

E olha que bacana, com *Duck Typing* dá até para reaproveitar o mesmo objeto no método [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). Ele ignorará a propriedade `type` e o método `beforeSend` e utilizará o restante das propriedades sem que você tenha que modificar o objeto de nenhuma maneira.

## Sistema de Tipos Estrutural

Existe um meio termo entre as vantagens do *Duck Typing* (contratos "locais", acoplamento mais fraco, simplicidade, etc) e a checagem de tipos em tempo de compilação?

Existe. São os chamados [tipos estruturais](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system). Eis um exemplo em Scala:

```
def registraCorredor(corredor: {def correr(destino: Point): Unit}) {
   corrida.registrar(corredor);
}
```

Nesse caso um corredor pode ser qualquer objeto que possua um método `correr`; o tipo corredor não precisa implementar nenhuma interface, porém se o método `correr` não existir no objeto `corredor` passado como parâmetro para a função `registraCorredor` o compilador acusará erro. Combine isso com outras "mágicas" de Scala como [a função apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737352/what-is-the-apply-function-in-scala) e [valores default para parâmetros](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/default-parameter-values.html) e temos o melhor dos dois mundos.