# O que é duck typing?

Tags: terminologia, tipagem, engenharia-de-software, estilo-de-codificação

Na pergunta [Quais as vantagens e desvantagens do Duck Typing?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28279/101) não existe uma definição do que é este mecanismo da programação.

Há uma definição canônica sobre ele?

Só é usado em Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se não quiser ler vou negritar o que mais importa.

O termo não é formalmente definido e há diferentes versões do que exatamente é. Algumas pessoas dizem até que [ele nem deveria existir porque já existem outros termos que indicam o que querem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/01/02/what-is-duck-typing/), dependendo de qual for a definição.

Obviamente que começamos pela frase que deu origem ao termo:

> Se anda como um pato e grasna como um pato, então deve ser um pato

Isso não explica nada sobre a programação em si, mas **quer dizer que a escolha sobre executar um método em um objeto se dá apenas pelo fato dele existir. Ou seja, o objeto precisa apenas parecer que sabe fazer aquilo, não precisa ser definido explicitamente que ele sabe fazer. Não é necessário um contrato, basta funcionar**.

[Tem uma pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/72685/101) que fala sobre o fato de ser uma forma específica de interface implícita, ou seja, um contrato que é usado por inferência e não explicitamente, ou como costuma-se dizer, é feito de acordo com a estrutura encontrada e não como o nome que diz que o objeto tem aquilo que é necessário.

E vamos pegar o que está na [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

> Com tipagem nominativa, um objeto é de um determinado tipo se for declarado como sendo (ou se a associação de um tipo com o objeto for inferida por meio de mecanismos como herança de objeto). Na tipagem de pato, um objeto é de um determinado tipo se tiver todos os métodos e propriedades exigidos por esse tipo. A tipagem de pato pode ser vista como uma equivalência estrutural baseada no uso entre um determinado objeto e os requisitos de um tipo. Consulte a [tipagem estrutural](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101) para obter mais explicações sobre a equivalência de tipo estrutural.

Pra variar o verbete foi para um lado ruim em versões anteriores, como o Eric Lippert mostra em seu artigo *linkado* acima. Lá falava sobre orientação a objeto. Isso foi retirado, mas ainda fala em herança e ainda consta OOP como uma das categorias do assunto, ou seja, alguém, limpou a sujeira da privada, baseado no que ele disse, deixando ali toda sujeira que alguém foi largando pelo caminho até chegar na privada. E isso vale para outras partes que foram editadas. Claramente houve edição para tirar tudo o que foi diretamente criticado pelo Eric, mas a sujeira continua lá. A Wikipedia tem muito disso, um monte de gente sem entendimento do assunto criando uma colcha de retalhos de palavras que deveria ser conhecimento.

Eu não gosto da [resposta aceita no SOen sobre o termo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205163/221800). Não estou dizendo que ela está claramente errada, mas é o que me parece, e por falta de uma definição canônica, eu posso estar certo e ela estar errada. Eu não acho que isso seja algo de linguagem dinâmica. [Sequer gosto do termo "linguagem dinâmica"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101), que limita o que a linguagem pode ser. Muito menos o uso de tipagem forte é bem usada ali, sem falar que é outro termo não é tão bem definido, mas que faz sentido existir. Os comentários lá tratam disto. E a [resposta seguinte com mais votos na data que eu posto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205396/221800) tem uma definição melhor, dentro do que eu estudei.

A resposta que parece mais certa dá uma boa explicação sobre a diferença entre a tipagem do pato e a tipagem estrutural, e isto é importante. O primeiro não pode ser provado antecipadamente se vai funcionar ou não, já o segundo pode ser provado mesmo não tendo sido especificado nominalmente. Como ocorre um [*late binding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding) (lá mostra várias "linguagens de tipagem estática" com o mecanismo) no primeiro, algumas pessoas confundem com tipagem dinâmica. Eu só não sei se a conclusão e exemplo dado no final estão corretos.

O termo [*late biding* também é desses que "ninguém" sabe o que é](https://ericlippert.com/2012/02/06/what-is-late-binding/).

A Wikipedia mostra que há diferença entre esses dois mecanismos, embora de forma não tão contundente.

> O pato nada, voa e anda, mas nenhum faz direito

[image: quadrinho demonstrando que o pato não liga para o que falam dele]

A crítica que se faz ao mecanismo é que, assim como o pato, ele acaba não fazendo bem nada daquilo, ou seja, pode não ser bem o que queria fazer só porque tem um método que tem o mesmo nome.

Gosto desta imagem porque ela mostra o problema de chamar um método com um nome ou [assinatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) que não faz o que você espera.

[image: Imagens de carro, caminhão e taco de golfe e uma xícara pra mostra o que encaixa ou não encaixa no objetivo]

O termo foi popularizado pelo criador do Python, o Guido Von Rossum, por isso ficou associado à Python, que usa esta "forma de tipagem", mas pode acontecer em qualquer linguagem, até mesmo em linguagens tipicamente tipadas de forma estática.

Quase todas definições do termo feito por pythonistas são ruins e enviesadas, o que reforça a ideia da linguagem ser usada principalmente por pessoas leigas que não ligam muito pra computação e ciência, mesmo que ela seja usada principalmente por pessoas que se declaram *cientistas* de dados.

Curiosamente [Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) diz "explicit is better than implicit", e *duck typing* é só mais um dos inúmeros mecanismos que violam a filosofia da linguagem.

Em muitos casos, quem não preza muito pela formalidade das cosias, em determinado momento de sua vida, cria termos sem sentido, assim como *serverless*, responsivo, NoSQL, etc.

[As discussões sobre o verbete na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Duck_typing) são mais interessantes que o verbete em si. [Também pode ser útil](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1948069/221800). E como sempre, preciso citar a [C2 como referência](https://wiki.c2.com/?DuckTyping) para entender melhor o debate.

Então seria este um termo engraçadinho que acaba sendo usado marketeiramente muitas vezes e aí todo mundo passa usar como se ele fosse necessário?

Para concluir, minha visão é que realmente *duck typing* não tem relação com *typing* e sim com *binding*. Mas entenda que não é uma definição definitiva, até agora parece que ninguém a tem. Aqui não é lugar de debate, mas estou errado?

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).