# Como reutilizar adequadamente as regras de negócio usando EJBs?

Tags: java, java-ee, arquitetura-de-software, ejb

Estou refatorando um sistema onde a maior preocupação é diminuir o acoplamento e complexidade dos vários níveis de herança, portanto os exemplos são ilustrativos.

Tenho as entidades `Contrato`, `ContratoUso` e `ContratoAdesao`. Tenho ainda um *session bean* `ContratoRepository` com as regras de negócio da entidade `Contrato`.

As regras de negócio dos contratos mais especializados tem grande parte das regras de negócio do `Contrato`.

**Qual a melhor forma de implementar isto?**

Pensei inicialmente em algumas possibilidades:

## Herança

O `ContratoUsoRepository` e os demais herdam as regras de `ContratoRepository` e implementam suas especifidades.

Exemplo usando *generics*:

```
ContratoRepository<M extends Contrato> {
  recuperarContrato(int id) {
    return M;
  }
}

ContratoUsoRepository extends ContratoRepository<ContratoUSO>() {
  //métodos específicos de ContratoUSO
}
```

## Delegação

Uso composição, tendo `ContratoRepository` injetado em `ContratoUsoRepository` e delegando para contrato o que é comum?

Exemplo com injeção de dependências:

```
ContratoUsoRepository {

  @EJB
  ContratoRepository contratoRepository;

  recuperarContrato(Int id){
     return contratoRepository.recuperarContrato(id);
  }

}
```

Exemplo :

na questão do meu problema os métodos de negócio tem o mesmo comportamento só muda a entidade especifica de retorno, 
por ex:

```
pesquisarContratoPorPeriodo(Date inicio,Date fim);
```

posso facilmente herdar esse metodo para qualquer contrato, pois o comportamento é o mesmo, só muda o tipo de contrato retornado.

**ou ainda assim é preferivel delegar ?** mesmo não fazendo nenhuma tarefa adicional.
delegar seria simplesmente:

```
contratoAdesaoService{
     @EJB contratoService
    pesquisarContratoAdesaoPorPeriodo(date inicio,Date fim){
          return contratoService.pesquisarContratoAdesaoPorPeriodo(inicio,fim);
}
```

Comment: Java não é a minha praia e não sei se entendi bem a pergunta, mas veja se estas perguntas aqui te ajudam: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11594/%C3%89-errado-usar-heran%C3%A7a-de-classes-para-agrupar-comportamentos-e-atributos-comuns, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11378/%C3%89-correto-dar-maior-prefer%C3%AAncia-a-composi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-que-heran%C3%A7a

Comment: Bruno, editei sua pergunta para tentar melhorá-la. Por favor, se algo não ficou de acordo com sua intenção original, pode editá-la novamente. Abraço.

Comment: Obrigado, é exatamente essa a dúvida.

Comment: Particularmente eu recomendo herança, por ser mais tradicional. Não possuo um argumento técnico muito forte, apenas por tradicionalismo, e por outra, é mais fácil algum dia mudarem as anotações pra injeção do que mudarem a forma como é a realizada a herança (rsrsr).

Comment: Os detalhes apresentados são insuficientes para uma boa decisão. Por padrão, eu evito a herança até que ela se prove necessária. E depois continuo evitando hehehe. Herança adiciona complexidade e compromete a abstração - geralmente vale a pena gastar um tempo a mais buscando uma solução mais simples. A propósito, por mais detalhes que se apresente, esta tende a ser uma discussão longa onde nenhuma resposta será melhor que a outra (exceto é claro algumas respostas simplórias que com certeza surgirão). Creio que esta seja uma pergunta off topic pro SOpt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente, as duas perguntas linkadas pelo @bfavaretto já responderiam sua questão no que se refere à modelagem de classes. São elas:

- [É correto dar maior preferência a composição do que herança?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)
- [É errado usar herança de classes para agrupar comportamentos e atributos comuns?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11594/227)

Porém, é possível analisar especificamente o seu caso do ponto de vista de um Caso de Uso da aplicação ou da arquitetura EJB.

## Casos de Uso

Casos de Usos de uma aplicação [podem herdar outros Casos de Uso](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagrama_de_caso_de_uso). Isso inclui a execução de determinadas determinadas regras de negócio do caso de uso herdado. Isso é comum em modelagem de sistemas.

Porém, herança em Casos de Uso não funcionam exatamente como herança em orientação a objetos. Ela consiste em inserir passos adicionais no Caso de Uso principal.

Na prática, isso não dita que você precisa necessariamente usar herança nas classes que implementam esses casos de uso. Existem várias técnicas para criar pontos de extensão no seu código.

## Enterprise Java Beans

Não recomendaria usar herança em classes EJBs. Essas classes possuem um contrato de funcionamento com o *container*. Com herança você pode acabar em situações complicadas em que é difícil saber se algum detalhe deve ou não ser herdado. Isso sem contar possíveis problemas com anotações, transações e visibilidade de acesso aos elementos.

## Delegação

Minha sugestão é que a herança de classes de regras de negócio sejam evitadas ao máximo. Usar delegação permite reusar as regras de negócio onde for necessário sem necessidade de gambiarras com hierarquia de classes.

### Evite acoplamento

De preferência, faça com que seus métodos de regras de negócio tenham baixo acoplamento para serem mais reaproveitados.

Por exemplo, ao invés de um método que assume várias coisas e acesso o banco para fazer uma validação assim:

```java
public void validarContrato(int idContrato) {
    Contrato contrato = contratoRepository.find(idContrato);
    if (contrato.hasErrors()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Contrato inválido");
    }
}
```

Você poderia receber um objeto `Contrato`:

```java
public void validarContrato(Contrato contrato) {
    if (contrato.hasErrors()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Contrato inválido");
    }
}
```

Dessa forma, você pode validar contratos antes de colocar no banco de dados. Isso é muito útil para fazer testes unitários e exibir erros para o usuário antes de cadastrar algo no banco de dados.

### Pontos de Extensão usando Interfaces

Uma das formas que considero mais produtiva para implementar pontos de extensão em casos de uso é criar uma interface que funciona como um *callback*. No Java 8 você pode usar *lambdas* para fazer isso, porém vou fazer usando o modo tradicional para ilustração.

Imagine que você tem um caso de uso da seguinte forma:

```java
public void criarContrato(Contrato c) {
    recalcularContrato(c);
    validarContrato(c);
    //algo específico aqui
    gravarContrato(c);
}
```

Caso você queira colocar algum passo ali que varie de acordo com a situação, pode adicionar um parâmetro que funciona como um ponto de extensão.

Para isso, vai precisar de uma interface como a seguinte:

```java
public interface ExtensaoContrato {
    executar(Contrato c);
}
```

Então você pode alterar o método da seguinte forma:

```java
public void criarContrato(Contrato c, ExtensaoContrato pontoExtensao) {
    recalcularContrato(c);
    validarContrato(c);
    if (pontoExtensao != null) pontoExtensao.executar(c);
    gravarContrato(c);
}
```

Isso funciona mais ou menos como o *[Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)*. A ideia é que você deixa um passo a ser provido pelo cliente que vai chamar o método, podendo haver quantas implementações forem necessárias da interface.

Então o método que chama a criação do contrato pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```java
criarContrato(contrato, new ExtensaoContrato() {
        public void executar(Contrato c) {
            //faz algo depois da validação e antes de gravar
        }
    });
```

O código acima executa o método `criarContrato` passando o contrato e também uma classe anônima que implementa `ExtensaoContrato`. O método `executar`, implementado nesta classe anônima, vai ser executado então pelo método `criarContrato`.

Assim você pode "injetar" qualquer código ali, em situações onde vocês tem um Caso de Uso geral e precisa apenas fazer algo específico em um ou mais pontos.

No caso desta pergunta, um dos cenários (dependendo de como é a implementação real) é ter uma implementação para cada tipo de contrato.

## Delegação simples

Outra opção é fazer a delegação simples, como já descrito na sua pergunta. Se não houver muitas variações e heranças é a escolha certa, pois é simples e direto.

## Considerações finais

Um dos erros mais comuns, principalmente de quem está num nível intermediário em desenvolvimento, é tentar aplicar padrões e hierarquias de classes desnecessariamente no código.

Isso não é de todo ruim. Significa que o desenvolvedor está amadurecendo. Porém, o ponto fraco de todo padrão e da herança é aumentar muito a complexidade do código. É algo difícil de medir, mas seria necessário considerar se essa complexidade adicional traz mais benefícios do que malefícios para o modelo de classes.

Comment: Muito bacana sua resposta, acrescentou bastante, irei dar uma estudada nessa questão de **Pontos de Extensão usando Interfaces** parece bem util em alguns casos, além de sofisticado.
editei minha pergunta , se possível me confirme se nesse último exemplo que dei (que é o meu contexto em algumas situações) delegar ainda seja a melhor opção. obrigado.

Comment: @BrunoSerqueira Se uma única implementação de repositório é capaz de dar conta de todos os tipos de contrato, você não precisa de herança. Pode ter uma única classe com métodos *generic*: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: eu quis dizer que os métodos em comum tem o mesmo comportamento, sem nada adicional, porém eles também tem seus comportamentos especificos.