# Quando usar Interfaces

Tags: java, interface, groovy

Eu sempre tive a seguinte dúvida: Quando realmente devo utilizar uma interface ao invés de herança e quais vantagens posso obter ?

Comment: Relacionado: [É errado usar herança de classes para agrupar comportamentos e atributos comuns?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11594/3117) e [É correto dar maior preferência a composição do que herança?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/3117)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## **Interfaces**

Uma interface é um contrato: o cara escrevendo a interface diz:

"hey, eu aceito as coisas dessa forma aqui.", e o cara usando a interface diz:

"Ok, a classe que eu escreverei será assim".

Uma interface é uma concha vazia, existem apenas as assinaturas dos métodos, o que implica que os métodos não tem um corpo. Entretanto, partir do Java 8 isso deixa de ser verdade com os default methods. A interface não pode fazer nada. É apenas um padrão.

Por exemplo (pseudo código):

```
//Eu digo todos os veículos a motor deve ser semelhante a este:

Interface MotorVehicle
{
     void run (); 
     int getFuel();
}

//Então minha equipe cumpre o "contrato" e escreve um veículo de acordo com o especificado

classe Car implements MotorVehicle
{
     int fuel;
     void run ()
     {
         print ("Wrroooooooom");
     }

     int getFuel ()
     {
         return this.fuel;
     }

}
```

## **Vantagens**

Ela separa o "contrato"  da implementação. Você tem um conjunto de métodos puros que você pode chamar sem nenhum conhecimento sobre sua implementação.

Garante que todos os métodos que a herdam possam ser chamados com segurança

É fácil implementar APIs usando interfaces, de modo que todas as implementações das interfaces fornecem os métodos previstos em cada classe.

## **Desvantagens**

Do meu ponto de vista as desvantagens de Interfaces seriam mais com relação ao seu mau uso. Por exemplo, em Java costuma-se criar interfaces para tudo, muitas vezes desnecessariamente. É como se o desenvolvedor assinasse vários contratos sem ler e depois tem o dobro de trabalho para fazer manutenção no sistema. Outro uso incorreto é colocar muitos métodos em uma única interface. Isso viola o princípio SOLID da segregação das interfaces, o que a torna praticamente inútil para reaproveitamento. E segue nessa linha.

## **Herança**

Herança incentiva o uso de classes. Você pode estender as funcionalidades de uma classe existente tanto dentro do mesmo projeto ou em outro projeto. Com a herança, você pode estender funções, features, etc. de uma classe existente para uma nova classe.

```
class Pessoa{
    String titulo;
    String nome;
    int idade;
}

classe Funcionario: Pessoa{
    int salario;
    String titulo;
}
```

O funcionário herda de Pessoa

## **Vantagens:**

Um dos principais benefícios da herança é minimizar a quantidade de código duplicado em um aplicativo,  através de compartilhamento de código comum entre várias subclasses. Mas a recomendação primordial para reuso de código é criar classes especializadas e delegar. Reaproveitar código com herança aumenta o acoplamento desnecessariamente na maioria dos casos. Onde existe código equivalente em duas classes relacionadas, a hierarquia pode geralmente ser reformulada para mover o código comum até uma superclasse. Isso também tende a resultar em uma melhor organização do código.

Herança também pode tornar o código do aplicativo mais flexível a mudanças porque as classes que herdam uma superclasse comum podem ser usados ​​alternadamente. Se o tipo de retorno de um método é superclasse

Reutilização - facilidade de usar métodos públicos de classe base sem reescrever o mesmo extensibilidade - estendendo a lógica classe base como por lógica de negócios da classe Dados derivados - base de classe pode decidir manter alguns dados privados de modo que não pode ser alterado pela classe derivada

Substituindo - Com a herança, seremos capazes de substituir os métodos da classe base, de modo que a implementação significativa do método de classe base pode ser concebida na classe derivada.

## **Desvantagens**

Uma das principais desvantagens da herança é o aumento do tempo/esforço que leva o programa para "saltar" através de todos os níveis de classes sobrecarregadas. Se uma determinada classe tem dez níveis de abstração acima dele, então ele irá essencialmente tomar dez saltos para executar através de uma função definida em cada uma dessas classes

A Principal desvantagem de usar a herança é que as duas classes (base e classe herdada) são fortemente acoplados. Isto significa que não podem ser usados independentemente umas das outras.

Além disso, com o tempo, durante a manutenção a adição de novas funcionalidaes tanto de base, bem como classes derivadas devem ser mudadas. Se a assinatura do método é alterado em ambos os casos (herança e composição)

Se um método é eliminado no "super classe" ou agregado, então vamos ter que refatora-lo em caso de utilização de métodos. As cosas podem ficar um pouco complicado no caso de herança, porque os nossos programas ainda irão compilar, mas os métodos da subclasse não irão mais sobreescrever os métodos da superclasse. Estes métodos se tornarão métodos independentes em seu próprio dominio.

Comment: Do meu ponto de vista as desvantagens de Interfaces seriam mais com relação ao seu mau uso. Por exemplo, em Java costuma-se criar interfaces para tudo, muitas vezes desnecessariamente. É como se o desenvolvedor assinasse vários contratos sem ler e depois tem o dobro de trabalho para fazer manutenção no sistema. Outro uso incorreto é colocar muitos métodos em uma única interface. Isso viola o princípio [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) da segregação das interfaces, o que a torna praticamente inútil para reaproveitamento. E segue nessa linha. Abraço!