# Bibliotecas, interface, classes e métodos

Tags: java, classes, terminologia, método, interface

Qual a diferença de bibliotecas e interfaces?

Por exemplo, na linha:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

O `util` seria a interface e `Scanner` a classe? Ou o `util` seria a biblioteca e o `Scanner` continuaria sendo a classe?

No caso dos métodos com `@Override` só faz sentido quando trabalhamos com interfaces? Em caso com herança não sei se tem tanto motivo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Os termos estão completamente errados e misturados.

Há uma relação entre classe e interface.

[Biblioteca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101) é um termo genérico que não é usado no código em si. O que você provavelmente está falando são dos pacotes (*packages*).

Então no exemplo o `java.util` é o pacote. E `Scanner` é a classe.

Em nenhum momento está usando [interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3603/101) aí. [Mais informações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35317/101). [Quando usar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/62885/101).

Veja [como usar o  `@override`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22913/101). [Mais informações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33014/101).

Comment: Os pacotes não são as pastas que separam as classes dentro de src?

Então a biblioteca está mais como dependência do que fazer parte do próprio código em si?

Comment: Sim, são. Eu diria melhor, que os pacotes agregam classes. Sua ideia está certa mas o termo está errado. Pode-se dizer que a biblioteca é um conjunto de pacotes compilados. E claro que há a dependência.