# Programar para a interface significa programar para um super-tipo, por que?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, interface

Quando programamos voltado para interface implica em programar para uma super-tipo? Qual o significado disto?

Comment: Tem um citação, um contexto de onde isto está sendo usado? A pergunta pode ser um pouco ambígua dependendo da conceituação usada.

Comment: Eu me deparei com esta citação em um slide apresentado durante minha aula de Engenharia de Software, onde estava sem apresentado um exemplo de software que utilizava o Padrão de Projeto Strategy, vou ver se consigo este trecho.

Comment: O exemplo que surgiu essa questão está no exemplo encontrado neste link: http://www2.ic.uff.br/~anselmo/cursos/TPA/apresentacoes/PadraoStrategy.pdf

Comment: Não achei esta citação mas vou tentar responder.

Comment: A citação não está nesse link, a citação está no slide de minha professora, mas não o consegui. Mas o exemplo que desencadeou essa questão é o mesmo que está no link.

Comment: @bigown, nesta pergunta já está tudo ok. Realizei o aceite da pergunta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre classes concretas, abstratas, interfaces, porque o AP já fez várias perguntas sobre isto e já recebeu respostas onde tem muito material.

Eu não posso garantir se tem uma definição formal que indique o que pode ser considerado super-tipo ou não. Na minha visão qualquer coisa que possa ser usado como base para outros tipos é um super-tipo. Incluindo interface, então a afirmação é verdadeira.

Se você vai preferir uma classe concreta, abstrata ou interface, realmente depende do caso e há material no site para ajudar a entender genericamente quando usar cada uma.

A interface é o super-tipo mais fácil de ser implementado. A [classe abstrata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87423/101) fica no meio termo porque tem partes puramente abstratas e outras concretas. A concreta é mais complicado porque só pode trocar a implementação por virtualização (ou algum mecanismo que obtenha o mesmo efeito) e isto não é algo tão simples.

A interface dá mais liberdade de implementação e é mais restrita no que faz, então ela é uma forma de programar para super-tipo, e é considerada a melhor forma.

Mas se no contexto o termo for superclasse, me parece que aí está se falando de uma classe abstrata ou concreta.

O termo "programar para interface" não pode incluir classes, que são super-tipos, que tenham implementações, pelo menos não na parte que aquilo se refere.

Java e C# não permitem herança múltipla, só uma classe pode ser herdada, então ela quase certamente implicará ter implementações, o que dificulta o princípio do "programar para interface". Para entender melhor porque, leia a pergunta *linkada* abaixo.

Então, [como diria o Ronnie Von](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ngv1FmXg040), sim, significa, mas isto não quer dizer muita coisa. Saber isto especificamente não tem implicação prática.

O que mais poderia acrescentar sobre isto já está na pergunta: [Programar voltado para interface e não para a implementação, por quê?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu não entendi uma coisa @bigown, o que você quis dizer com o termo "implementação por virtualização"?

Comment: Usar um método virtual onde você ele pode ser substituído por outro na classe filha. Se tudo for virtual até dá para dizer que a classe concreta pode funcionar como se fosse um interface. Fazer um design assim provavelmente é um erro, mas teoricamente atenderia o que o princípio do "programar para interface".

Comment: Eu também não tenho certeza, mas pelo que entendo 'super tipo' é a ideia de um tipo que pode ser instanciado sem que o objeto 'seja' desse tipo. Com herança, cachorro **é** um animal, mas um objeto que implementa uma interface `IInterface` não **é** `IInterface`

Comment: @RSinohara você está certo nisto, mas **não sei** se a interface não pode ser considerado um super-tipo. Acredito que sim, afinal ela pode ser usada no lugar do sub-tipo. Eu não sou muito acadêmico, então não vou afirmar nada, mas a não ser que alguém me mostre uma falha nesta lógica, considerarei a interface um super-tipo.

Answer (score 4):

> Interface é um recurso da orientação a objeto utilizado em Java que define ações que devem ser obrigatoriamente executadas, mas que cada classe pode executar de forma diferente.

Como exemplo:

Temos a classe abstrata `Veículo` e as classes não abstratas `Caminhao`, `Aviao` que herdam da classe `Veículo`. Concorda comigo que não tem como o caminhao voar (Não até os dias de hoje)? Portanto, os métodos serão diferentes, posso colocar na classe abstrata `Veículo` o método `abastecer()` já que é comum para todas as classes que herdam dela. Porém, enquanto o caminhão anda, o avião voa, então estes dois verbos não pertencem ao mesmo objeto e obviamente não podem ser colocados juntos na superclasse.

O que faço então?

Posso criar duas interfaces, uma com o nome `VeiculoTerrestreInterface` e a outra `VeiculoAereoInterface`, enquanto que, a interface `VeiculoTerrestreInterface` contém o método `andar()`, a interface `AviaoInterface` terá o método `voar()`.

E nas suas classes, utilizando a linguagem de programação Java, será implementada da seguinte maneira:

```
public class Aviao extends Veiculo implements VeiculoAereoInterface{

}

public class Caminhao extends Veiculo implements VeiculoTerrestreInterface{

}
```

Recapitulando, Avião e Caminhão são Veículos e possuem ações semelhantes, certo? Porém, ambas possuem suas próprias ações e que o outro pode não conseguir fazer. Para esse problema então foram criadas duas interfaces para que em cada uma delas seja definido métodos específicos, que foram voar e andar.

Futuramente posso criar também a classe `Carro` e implementar de `VeiculoTerrestreInterface` já que a mesma contém o método `andar()`.

```
public class Carro extends Veiculo implements VeiculoTerrestreInterface {

}
```

Segue uma imagem do exemplo:

[image: Classes implementando interfaces]

Comment: Eu não gosto muito deste exemplo porque ele, que é muito usado, usa OOP do jeito errado. Usa OOP querendo reproduzir coisas concretas que o mundo real faz, mas o programa é abstrato. Por isto fazer GUI, games com OOP é muito útil, mas quando tentamos reproduzir coisas concretas começamos ter problemas. Ora, o avião e o caminhão se movimentam. Então eles fazem a mesma coisa. Só a implementação é diferente. Não digo que isto está errado, mas está sendo ingênuo. Aí se um voa e o outro anda, **pode** ser um detalhe que pouco importa publicamente., que é o intuito da interface.

Comment: Relacionado: [É errado usar herança de classes para agrupar comportamentos e atributos comuns?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11594/%C3%89-errado-usar-heran%C3%A7a-de-classes-para-agrupar-comportamentos-e-atributos-comuns)

Comment: Obrigado pelos comentários, irei conferir o conteúdo do link

Answer (score 3):

Significa que você pode utilizar qualquer objeto que implemente a interface.

Usando herança e polimorfismo, você pode acessar, digamos, uma classe `cachorro` como se fosse um `animal`. Uma função pode usar a classe, só sabendo que é um `animal`.

Mas para isso, você precisa estar na hierarquia destas classes. E se o `animal` tiver uma função `mover()`, que muitos objetos têm? Se eu quiser acessar esse membro, não posso fazer isso através da classe `animal` - não para outros objetos. Claro que posso fazer com que tudo herde de `objeto`, que poderia conter esse método. Se você planejar isso no começo, vá-la. Mas se essa necessidade aparecer depois, significa mover muito código pra lá e pra cá (e talvez quebrar coisas no caminho).

Uma alternativa interessante é o uso de interfaces. Com elas, objetos nem um pouco relacionados podem compartilhar membros, que podem ser acessados por uma função que não tem ideia do que o objeto se trata, a não ser que implementa a interface.

Outra questão relevante é que a maioria das linguagens não permite herança múltipla (uma classe herdando de várias outras), enquanto permitem que uma classe implemente qualquer número de interfaces.