# Princípio de Delegação, o que é?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos

O que significa Princípio de Delegação em Programação Orientada a Objetos?

Após algumas pesquisas, encontrei uma definição sobre este princípio:

> Princípio de Delegação: maneira de tornar a composição tão poderosa para fins de reutilização como a herança.

Encontrei um exemplo de código em Java:

```
public abstract class Pato {

    public Padrao_Voaveis m_Padrao_Voaveis;

    public Pato(){

    }

    public void finalize() throws Throwable {

    }

    public void comportamento_pato(){

        m_Padrao_Voaveis.voar ();
        //(delega para a classe de comportamento)
    }

    public abstract void mostrar();

    public void nadar(){

    }
}
```

Porém, não consegui entender este princípio. Alguém possui uma maneira melhor para poder me explicar?

Comment: Polimorfismo isso?

Answer (score 8):

É um outro mecanismo para reutilização de código.
Normalmente ele é utilizado em linguagens que não
utilizam o conceitos de classes (Actor e Self). Nestas linguagens os objetos são chamados protótipos (prototypes) e cada um deles implementa um comportamento específico.

Se o objeto A não implementa uma determinada mensagem ele delega (repassa) a mensagem para o objeto B. Se o objeto B implementa aquela mensagem
então ele a executa com os dados de A, senão ele a delega para seus “delegatees”.

Em linguagens baseadas em classes este mecanismo
também pode ser obtido. Isto é feito através do
repasse da mensagem para o outro objeto. Para isso é
necessário que o objeto delegador do serviço
contenha uma referência para o objeto responsável
pela execução.

É importante indicar que a delegação difere da herança de duas maneiras importantes:

1. Com a herança, você tem apenas uma instância do objeto. Existe apenas um objeto indivisível, pois o que é herdado se torna uma parte intrínseca da nova classe.
2. A delegação geralmente fornece ao usuário apenas o que está na interface pública.
   A herança normal dá mais acesso aos detalhes internos da classe herdada.

[image: De:]

[image: Para:]

Se você olhar cuidadosamente à figura anterior, você notará que o RoboVulcao ainda possui 3 métodos relacionados ao sensor; esses são métodos que apenas chamam os métodos correspondentes do sensor. Isso é exatamente o que delegação é, apenas repassar funcionalidade às partes contidas.

Delegação vem junto com composição para oferecer soluções flexíveis e elegantes como essa que vimos anteriormente, e também respeita o princípio “separar código mutável de código estático”, mas também cobra um preço por isso: a necessidade de métodos que “embrulhem” as chamadas impõem um tempo extra de processamento por causa das chamadas a esses métodos.

Answer (score 8):

O termo pode ser usado de formas diferentes em programação. Em OOP ele basicamente é uma forma de [agregação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101) mais específica. Você deixa certos aspectos para outra classe - a delegada - realizar o que esta classe - a delegante - precisa.

A delegação ocorre tendo uma referência em algum membro para a outra classe. Ela permite a reutilização de código de forma manual.

A delegação não deixa de ocorrer de forma automática com herança e [polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25100/101), mas neste caso o termo não costuma ser usado.

Só que herança pode ser problemática em alguns casos. E olha que em estou falando da herança múltipla que é ainda mais problemática e muitas linguagens nem a implementam.

Herança costuma ser abusada e se pensa no reuso do código sem conceituar corretamente a relação entre o tipo mais geral e mais específico. Muitas vezes o reuso pode ser obtido sem a herança. Claro que isto terá que ser feito de forma mais manual. Por outro lado há mais controle e flexibilidade sobre o reuso.

De fato linguagens modernas preferiram nem ter herança. Isto pode exigir um pouco mais de código em alguns casos por exigir a delegação manual, que é o que estamos falando aqui, mas tornam a linguagem mais simples e evitam certos tipos de problemas.

## Seu exemplo

No seu exemplo mostra o que eu [comentei em pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87488/programar-para-a-interface-significa-programar-para-um-supertipo-por-que/87501#comment176418_87494). Para esta classe não interessa como o voo se dá. Não é responsabilidade dela (lembrando que as classes devem ter [responsabilidade única, serem coesas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101)). Ele cuida do pato de uma forma geral. O mecanismo específico do voo é definido em outra classe. A sua classe apenas chama este mecanismo.

Se não fosse esta delegação, além da classe estar fazendo mais do que ela precisa, ela ainda teria que reproduzir um código, que talvez você nem tenha acesso, no seu método. Para acessar o método que realmente implementa o mecanismo você precisa ter uma referência a esta classe e isto é obtido com a variável `m_Padrao_Voaveis`.

Um detalhe interessante é que o tipo **específico** desta variável não foi definido neste código e, portanto, poderá usar um sub-tipo de `Padrao_Voaveis` dando alguma flexibilidade ao que de fato será executado, dependendo de como esta variável seja inicializada, o que pode ocorrer dentro da própria classe de forma configurável ou não, ou externamente, ou seja pode ocorrer uma [injeção de dependência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21319/101).

Isto pode ser especialmente útil quando se usa interfaces. Vamos dizer que o método `comportamento_pato()` faça parte de uma interface que você deve obrigatoriamente implementar nesta classe. Dá trabalho, corre riscos escrevendo todo o código deste método. Mas você pode ter a implementação específica em outra classe. Então você cumpre o contrato definindo o método exigido pela interface mas delega a implementação do código dele para o que a outra classe já sabe fazer.

Algumas linguagens possuem facilidades que automatiza um pouco essa delegação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

> Em Programação Orientada a Objetos, segundo Angun Croll, engenheiro e
>   autor do blog JavaScript, define a Delegação como sendo uma técnica
>   que promove a reutilização do código ao permitir a invocação da função
>   de execução no contexto de uma instância específica –
>   independentemente da linha hierárquica da instância e da função. - [fonte](http://lourenzonotoroberto.blogspot.com.br/2013/04/delegacao-em-poo.html)

Segue um exemplo:

```
private static function curlExec($link, $data) {

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data, '', '&'));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $response;
}
```

E sendo chamado em outra função...

```
public function login($email, $senha) {  

    $data = array(
        'nome' => $email,
        'senha' => $senha
    );

    $link = 'http://teste.local/login';
    $response = self::curlExec($link, $data);

    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Delegação na visão de Orientação a Objetos é quando você desenvolve um Objeto que delega tarefas a outros objetos, é como se tivesse um objeto intermediário entre a SuperClass e a Classe que possui processamentos.

Neste [artigo](http://marcionorberto.blogspot.com.br/2013/04/heranca-e-delegacao.html) pode-se encontrar mais detalhes sobre este assunto;

Comment: Olá, Giovanni. Se você puder explorar um pouco mais o assunto seria ótimo.