# IList vs List , principais diferença

Tags: c#

Alguém sabe a diferença entre ele ? Quando devo usar `IList` e `List`

Segue código:

**IList:**

```
public ActionResult Upload_Photo(IList<HttpPostedFileBase> file_photo)
```

**List:**

```
public ActionResult Upload_Photo(List<HttpPostedFileBase> file_photo)
```

Alguns falam que é considerado ruim para expor a `Lista <T>`. Porque ?

Comment: Relacionada: [Programar para a interface significa programar para um super-tipo, por que?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87488/18246)

Comment: Relacionada: [Programar voltado para interface e não para a implementação, por que?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/18246)