# Como enviar atributos para classes estendidas?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, herança

```
class Veiculos
{
    protected $tipo = "carro";
}
```

Abaixo estou tentando identificar qual o tipo de veículo que a classe `Veiculos` atribuiu. Criei uma função `tipo_veiculo` que deve mostrar ao usuário qual o tipo de veículo que ele escolheu e pedir para que ele escolha uma cor na próxima etapa.

```
class Veiculo extends Veiculos
{
    public function tipo_veiculo(){
        if($tipo == "carro"){
            echo "Você selecionou carro. Escolha a cor.";
        } elseif($tipo == "moto") {
            echo "Você selecionou moto. Escolha a cor.";
        } else {
            echo "Você não selecionou nenhum carro.";
        }
    }
}
```

Como enviar o atributo `$tipo` para que a classe `Veículo` possa usá-lo? Tentei escrever alguma coisa usando o conceito de herança para que eu possa tentar obter uma resposta.

Comment: Já tentou `parent::$tipo` na classe filha?

Comment: Faz sentido o termo `parent` ... ***:)***

Comment: `parent` permite que classe que herdam de outras, possam acessar metodos e atributos marcados como protected ou public, funciona de maneira semelhante ao `super` no java.

Comment: Posso fazer com `$this` também ou por algum motivo é melhor `parent::`?

Comment: O uso de `parent::` ou `self::` fará o acesso de forma estática e isso geraria um erro do tipo `E_STRICT` em versões do PHP a partir de 5.4. No PHP 7 é gerado `fatal error`. Se a propriedade e métodos fossem estáticos não teria problema, porém, está definido como não estático. Utilize `$this->`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Entendendo herança

É difícil responder esta pergunta porque ela tem um erro conceitual. E se não entender os conceitos corretamente não vai codificar corretamente.

Quando herda uma classe a classe que deu origem a essa passa fazer parte dela, junta tudo. Ou seja, a classe filha é tudo o que a classe mãe é mais alguma coisa. Elas não são duas coisas separadas que podem se comunicar (enviar), é uma coisa só.

Já é esquisito uma classe `Veiculo` herdar de uma classe chamada `Veiculos`. Já falei em outra pergunta que tem que haver um motivo para usar uma classe e mais ainda para usar herança. Quase nada precisa de herança, herança deve ser a exceção, até os mais fanáticos por OOP sabem disto hoje em dia.

Uma das coisas mais importantes na codificação é dar bons nomes para as coisas. Uma coisa que chama `Veiculos` deve ter vários veículos dentro dele? Esta classe tem? Não parece. E se é uma coisa que tem vários veículos, por que seria parte de um veículo só? Vai pôr vários veículos dentro de um veículo? Não faz sentido.

Se essa classe é uma parte de um veículo, então deveria ter outro nome. E se é apenas uma parte deveria haver [composição e não herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11594/101) ([veja aqui também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/101)). Eu simplesmente não consigo imaginar como a herança seja adequada nesse caso.

## O problema específico

Dito tudo o que é importante para quem quiser aprender com esta pergunta, basta acessar a variável do jeito certo. Afinal `$tipo` é uma variável local (da função), já `$this->tipo` é a variável de instância da classe. O erro é diferente do que está descrito na pergunta.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/PwISge). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xscgnnsv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/Extension.php).

Comment: Então tanto faz `parent` ou `$this->`, desde que na classe que está herdando não exista o método/atributo que está sendo invocado?

Comment: É uma ótima explicação .... consegui entender que heranças são verdadeiras exceções e devem ser usadas com cautela, além disso entendi que todo o conteúdo da classe que passa para dentro da subclasse tem que ter relação com a mesma.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Não, só `this->`pode ser usado. A propriedade `$tipos` passa fazer parte da classe filha. O `parent` raramente é necessário. E nem pode ser usado para variáveis de instância. É usado quando há conflito entre implementações de método da classe filha e mãe. Se existe duas implementações de mesmo nome nas duas classes, obviamente que a preferência será pelo método da filha, aí é que entra o `parent`, é a única forma de acessar a implementação da mãe (obviamente se houver uma reimplementação do método). Também é usado para membros estáticos.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius é estranho `$tipo` estar na classe mãe. Talvez este seja um exemplo artificial. Aí ele não ajuda aprender. OOP é interessante aprender com exemplos que pelo menos simulem problemas reais. O que é certo ou não em OOP depende muito de como é o conceito real. Se o conceito é inventado, então tudo pode estar errado. Se os problemas pudessem ser modelados como queremos, OOP não seria necessário para nada. Ele ajuda modelar problemas reais. Se `Carro` herdasse de `Veiculo` faria mais sentido. Mas obviamente que depende do que tem dentro das classes, não basta o nome ser adequado.

Comment: Exemplo artificial ... estou estudando para aprender os conceitos e estou melhorando a cada dia. Obrigado.