# Quando é que eu preciso utilizar uma classe que herda de um ArrayList de um tipo? Não entendo para que serve isso

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, herança

Exemplo:

```
 public class ListaAdapterItem extends ArrayList<Item>{

 }
```

E eu tenho uma classe Item:

```
public class Item {
private int imagem;
private String nome;
private String descricao;

public Item(int imagem, String nome, String descricao){
    this.imagem = imagem;
    this.nome = nome;
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

public int getImagem() {
    return imagem;
}
public void setImagem(int imagem) {
    this.imagem = imagem;
}
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}
public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}
```

}

E na classe Main para testar esse código iria ficar algo como:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Item item = new Item(23, "nome", "descricao");

    ListaAdapterItem itens = new ListaAdapterItem();
    itens.add(item);

    }
```

É sério não consigo entender benefício algum nessa utilização alguém poderia me explicar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ótimo, em geral não tem esse benefício mesmo. Pode existir, mas é raro achar um caso assim.

Tem uma [pergunta famosa no SO do Eric Lippert que fala sobre isso](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21692193/221800). Lá mostra que o AP queria criar um lista que é um **time** e ele considerou que um time é uma lista de jogadores.

Mas na verdade um time **é** um time. Um time **possui** uma lista de jogadores. De acordo com o [princípio de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101), herança só deve ocorrer quando realmente um tipo é o mesmo que o outro tipo. Um time não pode herdar de uma lista, um time não é uma lista, mas ele é composto por uma lista de jogadores, possivelmente outras propriedades também.

Por isso que costuma-se dizer para [preferir composição no lugar de herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11594/101). Herança é supervalorizada.

Não conheço o contexto desse caso, a pergunta não fala bem o que é esse `ListAdapter`, se for só para criar uma lista especializada de `Item`, deve ser um erro.

Se for para usar com algum código legado que exige uma lista especializada e não uma lista genérica, aí tudo bem, começou errado, fazer o que? Está usando uma API ruim, faça o que tem que fazer, "suje as mãos".

Na outra resposta fala de usar quando realmente precisa estender uma lista e adicionar um comportamento. Ok, esse é um motivo que seria válido. Mas não costuma ser de fato. Se precisar manipular algo interno na lista e que tenha algo protegido, seria útil. Mas não tem nada protegido em `ArrayList`. O que é privado não pode manipular de qualquer jeito. O que é público pode ser feito com um método utilitário externo à classe. Em geral a herança não é necessária só por causa disto, até porque não espera-se usar esse método novo que seria adicionada em nenhuma API existente. E em código novo que você está criando pode usar o método utilitário. Não diga nunca, mas em geral a herança também não faz sentido nesse ponto.

Eu até dei uma pesquisada para ver onde se usa um [`ListAdapter` e descobri que o Android usa](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html). Mas note que eles fizeram certo, esse tipo herda de `Adapter`, ou seja, uma lista adaptadora é uma adaptadora, e não uma lista. Não tem nada a ver com o que foi colocado na pergunta.

Sua intuição parece estar certa. A não ser que tenha um contexto maior que indique seu uso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Massa, aprendi bastante moço.

Answer (score 1):

Serve para caso voce desejar fazer um arraylist com um comportamente próprio...
Por exemplo, se voce usa o arraylist e imaginou um método novo que voce precisaria que existisse mas não existe ainda, você cria uma classe MeuArrayList que herda de arrayList. Desse modo, você pode criar um método qualquer que voce precisa, como por exemplo "excluirPares"...Quando voce precisar, instancia esse MeuArrayList e usa o médoto excluirPares.