# Melhor maneira orientada a objetos de resolver o problema

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, lista, modelagem

Suponha que eu esteja modelando um Contracheque. Porém, cada entrada em um Contracheque eu escolhi modelar como um `ItemContracheque`. Ou seja, para representar meu Contracheque como um todo, eu posso usar uma simples lista de `ItemContracheque`.

Aí veio a dúvida, se apenas uma lista de `ItemContracheque` pode representar um Contracheque inteiro, já que ele não tem nenhum atributo a mais, eu preciso mesmo assim criar esse objeto Contracheque que teria apenas um atributo (uma lista de `ItemContracheque`)?

Qual seria a prática mais OO a se adotar aqui? Criar esse objeto Contracheque com apenas um atributo ou representar um Contracheque usando apenas uma lista de `ItemContracheque`? E o principal, porque escolher uma ao invés da outra?

Essa modelagem será usada no retorno de um dos métodos do webservice que estou fazendo.

Com códigos em Java para melhorar a questão:

```
public class Contracheque {
    private List<ItemContracheque> itensContracheque;
}
```

ou apenas usar:

```
List<ItemContracheque> itensContracheque;
```

Ou seja, isso definiria o retorno do meu método: ou um objeto `Contracheque` ou um `List<ItemContracheque>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não acho que isso tenha a ver com OOP diretamente, é apenas uma forma de modelar.

Se tem um objeto que é um contracheque então deveria ter um tipo só para indicá-lo. Conceitualmente isso é o correto. E os itens devem ser compostos dentro desse objeto ([não deve herdar nada, conforme já respondi em pergunta recente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167288/101)). É o correto por razões óbvias, porque se o conceito diz que existe esse objeto, ele deve ser criado. Não interessa o que tem dentro dele, não importa o tamanho.

Agora, dizer que só tem os itens parece ter um erro de modelagem aí. Isso é praticamente impossível. Claro, você pode definir do jeito que quiser, mas objetos não costumam ser tão simples. E até onde eu conheço um contracheque, e já trabalhei com folha de pagamento, ele é composto por vários atributos. Esse contracheque não tem número? Competência? De quem é? Valor total, entre outros valores?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Entendi! Sobre suas perguntas: sim, podem mesmo existir outros atributos, mas para suprir a necessidade do que eu preciso fazer, eles não são necessários. Então não é preciso colocá-los no objeto.

Comment: Ainda acho improvável, mas se você diz...

Comment: Hahaha Quanto ceticismo! Vou aceitar a sua como resposta, foi muito satisfatória. Obrigado pela ajuda, bigown! ;)