# Classes derivadas de herança são tabelas diferentes no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, orientação-a-objetos, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados, herança

Se eu utilizar a herança e tiver 4 classes derivadas e minha classe pai for abstrata, essas 4 classes derivadas terão cada uma delas, uma tabela diferente no banco de dados MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é tão simples transpor o modelo orientado a objeto das linguagens de programação para o relacional dos bancos de dados.

Nem mesmo em DBs que possuem herança como o PostgreSQL. Aliás, nem perca tempo com isso se for usá-lo, não é o mecanismo que as pessoas esperam.

Eu costumo dizer que OOP é bom para mecanismos, não pra regras de negócio. As pessoas ignoram isso e aí se pegam em problemas.

Há até um temo que trata disso: *impedance mismatch* entre modelo OO e relacional. É algo bem debatido e dizem que um ORM resolve isso. Até resolve, se souber o que está fazendo e se for o mais adequado, mas também traz problemas. Por isso eu falo que: ou você usa um banco de dados 100% orientado a objeto (não existem opções consagradas); ou faz o modelo relacional na sua aplicação (na parte de regra de negócio), que é o que ["todo mundo" recomenda fazer hoje em dia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11594/101) de qualquer forma (mas em geral a maioria das pessoas não entendem). Tenha em mente que quase todas heranças que as pessoas fazem em regras de negócio estão erradas.

E aí caímos no problema do contexto. Não sabemos de que herança está falando, onde ela especificamente está sendo aplicada. Cada caso pode ser uma solução, e a mais comum será eliminar a herança.

Por exemplo, se você tem uma tabela derivada chamada `Cliente` que vem de `Pessoa` provavelmente está errado. Eu [falo disso em diversas respostas aqui no SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101%20heran%C3%A7a%20cliente%20fornecedor).

Se tiver uma `PessoaJuridica` e `PessoaFisica` que deriva de `Pessoa` aí depende. Pode ser que deva ter só uma tabela `Pessoa` que acaba aceitando dados das derivadas. Conceitualmente pode não ser o ideal, mas na prática pode fazer mais sentido. Ou pode de fato ter duas tabelas os dados de cada uma totalmente separados. De fato o mais correto é sempre ter tabelas apenas para classes concretas, e todas as classes concretas devem ter uma tabela para ela.

Mas nem sempre isso funciona bem. Em alguns casos pode ser até que a herança seja o problema e deva eliminá-la. O mais correto nem sempre é o melhor a fazer.

Se toda ideia estiver errada pode ser que esteja só querendo saber como contornar o problema em vez de resolver a raiz dele.

Eu faria uma tabela para cada classe concreta, mas assim pode estar só perpetuando o problema já existente.