# Duvida com exercício de EcmaScript 6

Tags: javascript, classes, método, herança, ecmascript-6

Esse exercício de EcmaScript fala sobre a criação de duas classes, uma de usuário (onde ocorrerá a entrada de email e senha), outra de administrador (onde além de ocorrer a entrada de email e senha, fala se é o adm.

Por que o método de entrada `isAdmin()` fica na classe do usuário e não do administrador? Digo, se é para verificar que a classe se trata de um administrador, não seria melhor ficar na classe do administrador?

O código em questão é este:

```js
class Usuario{
    constructor(email, senha){
        this.email = email;
        this.senha = senha;
    }
    isAdmin(){
        return this.admin === true;
    }
}

class Admin extends Usuario{
    constructor(email, senha){
        super(email, senha);

        this.admin = true;
    }
}

const User1 = new Usuario("email@teste.com", "senha123");
const Adm1 = new Admin("email@teste.com", "senha123");

console.log(User1.isAdmin()); //retornará false
console.log(Adm1.isAdmin());  //retornará true
```

Comment: Como você testaria se um usuário comum é administrador se o método `isAdmin` só estivesse em `Admin`?

Comment: Isso é exercício de algum curso? Troca de curso, um que ensina fazer errado não é uma boa. O @LuizFelipe está certo, o erro é ter herança. E isso deveria ser claro, porque se a herança fizesse sentido não precisaria verificar se aquilo é o que diz ser.

Comment: Para complementar o comentário do @Maniero, tem uma pergunta sobre [É errado usar herança de classes para agrupar comportamentos e atributos comuns?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11594/%c3%89-errado-usar-heran%c3%a7a-de-classes-para-agrupar-comportamentos-e-atributos-comuns)

Comment: Talvez seja o caso de mostrar os problemas de uma solução antes de mostrar um jeito melhor. O único jeito de saber é vendo as próximas aulas do curso ou perguntando para quem o fez.

Answer (score -1):

É que a classe Admin, herda os métodos e atributos da classe usuário, por isso o extends. Pense que um admin é um usuário, e ele precisa checar se o usuário é um Admin, e não se um Admin é um Admin. Espero ter ajudado!