# Python - Programação Orientada a Objeto

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, funções, classes

Eu criei um módulo com duas duas classes: Quero usar as duas como se o Mouse dependesse do Computador.
Ex.: quando utilizá-los: somente quando o Computador estiver ligado o mouse tenha permissão para ser ligado(plugado)..senão apresentar uma mensagem que ele não pode plugar...

Porém não obtive êxito como mostro no código abaixo:

Alguém pode me ajudar e me dizer onde eu errei, por gentileza?

```py
from time import sleep


class Computador:
    def __init__(self, marca, ligado=False, desligado=False):
        self.marca = marca
        self.ligado = ligado
        self.desligado = desligado

    def ligar(self):
        if self.ligado:
            print(f'{self.marca}, já está ligado')
            return

        print(f'{self.marca} está ligado')
        self.ligado = True

    def desligar(self):
        if self.desligado:
            print(f'{self.marca}, já está desligado')
            return

        print(f'{self.marca} está desligado')
        self.desligado = True


class Mouse(Computador):
    def __init__(self, marca):
        super().__init__(marca)
        self.marca = marca
        self.plugado = False
        self.desplugado = False

    def plugar(self):
        if not self.desligado or not self.ligado:
            print(f'O {self.marca} não está conectando o mouse..')
            return

        print(f'{self.marca} está conectando...')
        sleep(1)
        print(f'{self.marca} plugando...')
        sleep(2)
        print('Pronto!')
        sleep(1)

    def desplugar(self):
        return
```

```py
# Essa é a Segunda Parte do Código onde estou chamando os objetos/funções:

from classes import Computador, Mouse

c1 = Computador('Dell', 'Mouse RedDragon')
m1 = Mouse('RedDragon')
print(f'Descrição: [1]{c1.marca}\n')
m1.plugar()
c1.ligar()
c1.desligar()
c1.desligar()
c1.ligar()
m1.plugar()
```

Me mostrem o que não estou fazendo de correto, por gentileza.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela edição.

Comment: Qual seria o nível deste conteúdo, já que não é Iniciante Wallace Maxters ♦, poderia me dizer para que eu edite, por gentileza??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro, elimine essa hierarquia de classes:

```
class Mouse(Computador)
```

Aqui você está dizendo que `Mouse` é uma sub-classe de `Computador`, o que não faz sentido. Um mouse **é** um computador? Não, então esta herança está errada (leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11594/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/112052) para entender melhor).

Outro ponto é que ao plugar o mouse, você deve dizer onde ele está sendo plugado. Ou seja, o método `plugar` deveria receber um computador como parâmetro, ou o contrário: o computador poderia ter um método `plugar` que recebe o periférico sendo plugado como parâmetro (no exemplo abaixo eu escolhi a segunda opção).

E o computador poderia ter uma lista dos periféricos plugados, assim você saberá o que já está lá.

No computador, não faz sentido ter 2 variáveis, uma para "ligado" e outra para "desligado". Use apenas uma com o valor `True` ou `False`. Por exemplo, poderia ter apenas `ligado`: se o valor for `True`, está ligado, se for `False`, está desligado.

Da forma que você fez, isso pode resultar em coisas bem esquisitas, já que você fez isso:

```
def __init__(self, marca, ligado=False, desligado=False):
```

Ou seja, se eu criar `Computador('marca')`, tanto `ligado` quanto `desligado` serão `False` (ou seja, o computador está ao mesmo tempo ligado e desligado).

Enfim, uma alternativa seria:

```
class Computador:
    def __init__(self, marca, ligado=False, perifericos_plugados=None):
        self.marca = marca
        self.ligado = ligado
        # lista dos periféricos plugados (usar set que não permite elementos repetidos)
        if perifericos_plugados is None:
            self.perifericos = set()
        else:
            self.perifericos = set(perifericos_plugados)

    def ligar(self):
        if self.ligado:
            print(f'{self.marca}, já está ligado')
            return

        print(f'{self.marca} está ligado')
        self.ligado = True

    def desligar(self):
        if not self.ligado:
            print(f'{self.marca}, já está desligado')
            return

        print(f'{self.marca} está desligado')
        self.ligado = False

    def plugar(self, periferico):
        if not self.ligado:
            print('Computador desligado, não pode plugar')
            return

        if periferico in self.perifericos:
            print(f'Periférico {periferico.marca} já está plugado')
            return

        print(f'Plugando {periferico.marca} em {self.marca}')
        self.perifericos.add(periferico)

    def desplugar(self, periferico):
        if not self.ligado:
            print('Computador desligado, não pode desplugar')
            return

        if periferico not in self.perifericos:
            print(f'Periférico {periferico.marca} não está plugado')
            return

        print(f'Desplugando {periferico.marca} de {self.marca}')
        self.perifericos.remove(periferico)


class Mouse:
    def __init__(self, marca):
        self.marca = marca

c1 = Computador('Dell')
m1 = Mouse('RedDragon')
print(f'Descrição: [1]{c1.marca}\n')
c1.plugar(m1)
c1.ligar()
c1.desligar()
c1.desligar()
c1.ligar()
c1.plugar(m1)
```

Repare que agora o computador recebe o periférico a ser plugado e internamente ele faz as validações necessárias (se está ligado, se o periférico já está plugado, etc).

A partir daí você pode colocar a lógica que quiser em cada caso.