# Java não possui herança múltipla?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, ruby, classes, herança

Eu havia visto em algum lugar agora não me recordo, acho que foi em um curso sobre orientação a objetos, que Ruby possui. Mas em Java eu nunca vi. Será que é por causa disso que usa-se classes abstratas? Ou isto não tem sentido?

Comment: Você fala de herança múltipla? Java não possui isso, embora uma classe possa implementar várias interfaces (uma `interface` é uma "classe puramente abstrata").

Comment: interface é uma classe abstrata?(fiquei um pouco confuso). Sim estou falando de herança múltipla.

Comment: É por aí, sim. Uma classe ser abstrata só quer dizer que ela não pode ser instanciada diretamente, é preciso se herdar dela para isso. Só que uma classe abstrata pode ter componentes concretos (i.e. campos, métodos...). A regra pra classes abstratas é igual pras outras (i.e. sem herança múltipla, no máximo **um** `extends` por classe). A interface, por outro lado, só pode ter métodos públicos e abstratos (i.e. não implementados), e mais nada. Daí o "puramente abstrata". Toda classe que implementa uma interface deve dar uma implementação concreta pros seus métodos, sem receber nada pronto.

Comment: `Java não possui múltiplos extends?` seu título está um pouco confuso. Só existe uma palavra reservada `extends` em Java, e não várias :P

Comment: Editei o titulo da questão :D

Comment: Mas a interface é uma classe?? Ou ela é simplesmente interface?

Comment: Eu diria que interface é interface, e classe é classe. Entretanto uma interface é "como se fosse uma classe 100% abstrata", ou seja, não é permitido que ela possua métodos concretos.

Comment: Não posso colocar duas respostas certas...na verdade as duas me ajudaram bastante a entender este conceito. Mas dei meu voto para as duas.

Comment: Classes e interfaces são tipos. Você pode **interpretar** a interface como se fosse uma classe "capada". E isto é bom, resolve alguns problemas como pode ver nas respostas.

Comment: Legal, capada é boa :P Interessante a questão do Problema Diamante estava lendo.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Em Java não é possível que uma classe faça herança de múltiplas classes.

O motivo disso, imagine que uma classe herda outras duas classes, entretanto essas duas classes herdadas possuem métodos com a mesma assinatura porém com implementações diferentes. Seria algo difícil de lidar, pois como a subclasse saberia qual implementação do método ela deveria usar? Por isso não é possível que uma classe estenda de mais de uma classe em Java.

Uma classe abstrata pode possuir métodos abstratos assim como métodos concretos, ou seja, métodos que já foram implementados, então o fato da classe ser abstrata não ajuda muito a resolver o problema citado anteriormente.

O que se pode fazer em Java é que uma classe implemente várias interfaces, pois interfaces são como classes 100% abstratas, ou seja, é completamente proibido qualquer tipo de implementação nela, logo, não há o menor problema se as duas interfaces tiverem um método com a mesma assinatura, pois quem vai implementar o método é a classe que implementa as interfaces.

Algo curioso é que a palavra reservada `extends` pode ser usada para as interfaces, que é quando uma interface herda outra(s) interface(s), mas nesse caso não há problema de uma interface herdar de várias outras interfaces, pois não há nenhuma implementação envolvida nesse caso. Seria um código que ficaria assim:

**Interface1:**

```
public interface Interface1 { public void teste(); }
```

**Interface2:**

```
public interface Interface2 { public void teste(); }
```

**SubInterface:**

```
public interface SubInterface extends Interface1, Interface2 { }
```

Veja que não há o menor problema em fazer isso, pois a implementação vai na primeira classe concreta que implementar a SubInterface:

```
public class MinhaClasse implements SubInterface {
    @Override
    public void teste() {
        System.out.println("sou apenas um teste");
    }
}
```

Comment: Quer dizer que em uma interface eu posso fazer extends de mais de uma??

Comment: @RogersCorrêa sim! Por isso eu usei a palavra `curioso` em meu texto :D Veja minha edição, pus código na minha resposta

Comment: Sim. entendi. Por isso questionei para ver se eu havia entendido corretamente.

Comment: Realmente funcionou com interface

Comment: Se não é possível saber qual classe usar, então pq c++ tem herança múltipla? Ela é capenga?

Comment: @FlávioGranato tive que pesquisar para responder sua pergunta, e cheguei [nesse site aqui](http://goo.gl/hdgW6b). Aparentemente é assim: `Com uma pequena convenção de assinatura, do tipo, a classe que vier declarada primeira, terá o controle de sobrescrever os membros em situação de conflito de nomes ou qualquer coisa do gênero`. Entretanto essa funcionalidade parece que dá mais dor de cabeça do que soluções, e como Java é para ser uma linguagem simples, optaram por não permitirem tal funcionalidade. Não diria que C++ é capenga, ela só não é tão alto nível como Java.

Comment: :-) entendo. Quando disse ela me referi ao Java. Sim muda somente o algoritmo de resolução das dependêcias, já citaram abaixo... com os métodos defaults para mim ficou muito evidente que poderia ter tido herança múltipla a muito tempo, foi só preguiça e uma justificativa igualmente preguiçosa. Sou programador java a 10 anos, só pq me dá mais grana que as outras linguagens, não desmerecendo elas e nem o java... por gosto mesmo iria para outro mundo... hehehehe

Comment: @FlávioGranato discordo. Veja [**nessa resposta**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11380/3117) que diz: `Somente use herança se o subtipo puder perfeitamente substituir o tipo base`, se você conseguir substituir dois tipos bases diferentes isso significa que você feriu o princípio da responsabilidade única, senão foi isso então você duplicou código pois um dos tipos bases não deveria existir. Logo, a herança múltipla sempre acabará ferindo algum dos princípios da OO, portanto em minha opinião o Java acertou em cheio nessa decisão, esse é apenas um dos motivos pelo qual eu adoro essa linguagem.

Comment: agora sim, um cara que só usa a linguagem pra ganhar dinheiro e outro que adora... o fato é que java esta se remendando muito para ter coisas que ela poderia ter tido a muito tempo, métodos default simplesmente é preguiça de implementar herança múltipla. Liskov se aplica ao momento em que estou utilizando a linguagem, não ao compilador como começamos a falar, do meu ponto de vista você esta mudando o rumo das respostas simplismente para ganhar a discussão, bem, dou-me por vencido do que ficar perdendo energia com discussão sobre o sexo dos anjos. inté mais...

Comment: @FlávioGranato não entendi bem seus argumentos, não estou tentando me impor, só disse minha opinião, talvez você esteja certo e eu que não estou enxergando algo que você está (sem ironia), eu nunca senti uma real necessidade de herança múltipla, talvez um dia eu sinta. Mas de um coisa eu concordo, acho que a conversa já deixou de ser produtiva, rs.. vamos nos dar por empatado então, já que aparentemente não ganhamos nada com isso.

Comment: Essa discussão de vocês está muito mais teórica do que prática. Aparentemente nenhum dos dois trabalharam com uma linguagem que possui herança múltipla e nunca viram bons códigos com ela. Logo, fica fácil falar que é capenga e que fere os princípios de POO. Querem um exemplo? Vejam o código do django-rest-framework e como é simples criar uma classe que possui o comportamento de outra duas por meio de herança múltipla. E Java está longe de ser uma linguagem simples...

Comment: Aliás, quando fui aprender java e descobri que não tinha como fazer herança múltipla e que para conseguir algo parecido você teria que utilizar interfaces e blablablabla, minha cabeça explodiu com tanta complexidade para fazer algo simples em outras linguagens.

Answer (score 19):

## Conceituação correta

Acho que você está procurando saber se Java permite [herança múltipla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance). Nela a classe pode herdar de várias outras classes, sejam elas concretas ou abstratas.

**Classes abstratas** são aquelas que não podem ser instanciadas, ou seja, que você não pode criar um objeto baseado nela. Elas só existem para serem herdadas mesmo. Elas devem fazer parte de outra classe. Seus métodos podem ou não ter implementações.

Um caso especial de classe abstrata é a **interface**. Nela não pode ter estado (a grosso modo, variáveis que guardam valores) e os métodos não podem ter implementação ([em Java 8 pode](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90168/101)). Tem apenas a assinatura do método definindo o comportamento mas não como o comportamento agirá. É considerada uma classe puramente abstrata por não ter estado.

Em Java você pode obter herança múltipla de interfaces através de `implements`. Ou seja, você pode herdar diversos conjuntos de comportamentos sem implementações definidas mas não pode herdar estado e <strike>implementações</strike> à vontade. Só **uma** classe concreta ou abstrata pode ser herdada. Se precisar agregar outras funcionalidades na nova classe deverá ser através de implementação específica.

Você pode usar múltiplos `implements`, ou seja pode implementar quantas interfaces forem necessárias para indicar o que aquela classe é capaz de fazer. Quando você estende, você está dizendo que a nova classe **é** uma "versão melhorada" da classe que vai ser estendida. Quando você implementa algo, você está dizendo que a classe **tem** determinadas características necessárias para seu bom funcionamento. Desta forma você e o compilador sabem se uma classe pode ser utilizado em um determinado contexto. Ou seja, se ela possui tudo o que será necessário naquele contexto.

Isso foi parcialmente minimizado com os novos [Default Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) nas interfaces.

## Usando "múltipla herança"

Não conheço bem Ruby, mas até onde sei ela também não possui herança múltipla. Ela faz isto através de *[mixins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin)*. É feito uma combinação de recursos e não exatamente uma herança de recursos. É parecido com as interfaces com *default methods*.

Então em Java 8 é possível ter algo muito próximo ao que Ruby consegue. Por ser um recurso novo ainda não entendi todas suas limitações mas está claro que não pode haver estado e não pode haver construtores como ocorre em classes concretas ou abstratas. Me parece que são limitações semelhantes às encontradas nos *mixins*.

Nota-se nos exemplos da documentação do Java sobre *default methods* que é possível adicionar comportamento completo, isto é, definição da sua assinatura mais a implementação, mas isto não é considerado herança múltipla de fato. É mais uma combinação. Claro que popularmente pode ser interpretado como sendo.

Parece ser uma tendência que todas as linguagens tenham alguma forma de combinação de métodos, ou com [*default methods*, ou com *extension methods*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121240/101) (C#) ou com *mixins* ou com [*traits* (PHP)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156913/101). Sem um recursos assim, força o programador violar o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) e copiar implementações idênticas para métodos que fazem exatamente a mesma coisa em classes diferentes.

Exemplo bem simplificado:

```
interface Teste {
    default public void teste() {
        System.out.println("teste");
    }
}

class Classe { };

class NovaClasse extends Classe implements Teste { }

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NovaClasse teste = new NovaClasse();
        teste.teste(); //vai imprimir a palavra teste conforme definido na interface
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/37YByU). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/sgbmnfat-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/MultipleInheritance.java).

## Problema da herança múltipla

[Herança múltipla é desincentivada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173198/101) por causa do [problema do diamante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) e pela dificuldade de implementação correta nas linguagens. Além disto os programadores tem dificuldade de entender o funcionamento e restrições que ela acaba impondo. Costuma haver abuso utilizando a múltipla herança como um mecanismo para facilitar a codificação quando ela deveria facilitar organização semântica da aplicação.

Poucas linguagens implementam esta funcionalidade. C++ é uma delas mas é recomendado evitar ao máximo. [Eiffel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_(programming_language)) é um caso que até incentiva mas é uma linguagem que possui outras limitações. [Smalltalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk) também permite. Algumas funcionalidades não são muito ortogonais, e não casam bem. Então é necessário fazer escolhas.

Comment: Então eu poderia fazer 1 extends em uma classe com varios implements?

Comment: Veja se a edição melhorou este entendimento.

Comment: Sim entendi melhor.