# Por que todo mundo odeia herança múltipla em C++ e qual sua diferença para mixins?

Tags: java, c++, orientação-a-objetos, ruby, herança

Sempre ouvi dizer que herança múltipla em C++ é um caos. Por que? Não seria tecnicamente a mesma coisa que utilizar *mixins* em linguagens como o Ruby?

E o que é a tal classe abstrata do Java? É um *mixin* do Java?

Comment: Relacionado: [Java não possui herança múltipla?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22718/3117). Lá também fala de classes abstratas e a resposta do @bigown fala de _mixins_.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Premissa errada

Não sei porque todo mundo odeia herança múltipla em C++. Não sei nem se isso é verdade. Conheço muita gente que não odeia. Mesmo as pessoas que apontam problemas neste recurso (o que é possível fazer virtualmente em qualquer recurso de qualquer linguagem) não costumam odiar algo que pode ser útil e tranquilo de usar se a pessoa souber o que está fazendo. Claro que estou falando de pessoas ponderadas.

## O problema da herança múltipla

#### Estado

Estado é uma das coisas que causam problema em herança múltipla, onde pode haver conflitos entre dois ou mais membros. Imagine você ter dois membros com o mesmo nome mas que tentam atender necessidades diferentes. Isto é chamado de [problema do diamante](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem).

[image: Problema diamante]

Claro que o mesmo pode ocorrer com métodos, mas é mais fácil conviver com métodos com mesmo nome indicando explicitamente qual implementação quer usar. Para estado isto é detalhe de implementação, em geral é algo privado, você não pode selecionar qual usar. Claro que pode ser resolvido privadamente sempre. Mas não dá para garantir que isto seja feito. E quando faz isto acaba complicando o suficiente para a herança começar deixar de ser vantajosa. Por isto eu disse que dá para usar, desde que você saiba muito bem o que está fazendo.

#### Construtor

Existe um outro problema que o estado causa. É comum ele exigir que tenha um construtor. Pode haver confusão na chamada destes construtores. Em que ordem eles devem ser chamados? E se na subclasse houver a necessidade de interdependência entre estes estados?

Tem solução, não é simples, não é perfeito, mas dá para resolver. Tem que saber resolver.

O problema se agrava com a existência de sobrecarga de métodos ([assinaturas diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101)).

#### Comportamento

O problema do diamante também ocorre em métodos convencionais, mas é mais fácil solucionar.

## Mixin

A conceituação exata depende de quem está falando. Não há uma definição clara, varia de linguagem para linguagem.

Normalmente é considerada uma classe que não pode ser instanciada diretamente, não possui estado e tão pouco construtores (nem faria sentido pelas características anteriores).

É possível adicionar alguma forma de estado através de campos que nada mais são que métodos de acesso ao estado.

É usado para adicionar comportamento à uma classe não para ser uma classe completa em todos os sentidos.

Isto simplifica muito a herança. Evita os problemas citados acima. Em geral resolve bem o que o programador precisa.

É mais fácil implementar *mixin* em linguagens dinâmicas já que uma das características dele é resolver esses possíveis conflitos em tempo de execução.

#### Nem tudo é perfeito

Ao contrário do que se tenta vender *mixin* não é livre de problemas. Ele pode quebrar o encapsulamento em certas linguagens como Ruby e sua característica mais dinâmica impede certas verificações em tempo de compilação. Além disto a resolução de conflitos costuma ser feito por regras de escopo automáticas podendo o compilador fazer escolhas ruins.

## Outras soluções

Diversas linguagens adotaram formas alternativas para atender necessidade de múltiplos comportamentos sem incorrer nos problemas acima.

#### Interfaces

Adotada por Java e C#, por exemplo. Interface não pode ser instanciada, não possui estado ou construtores.

É uma boa solução, mas peca por também não poder ter implementação nos métodos. Isso obriga escrever código extra ou recorrer a classes utilitárias para obter reuso de código. Uma modernização até permite ter, mas não muda o principal sobre o estado.

Uma **classe abstrata** não é uma interface porque tem estado, portanto, construtor também e os métodos **podem** ter implementação.

#### *Traits*

Grosso modo é basicamente o *mixin* sem a possibilidade dos campos.

Preferido em linguagens estáticas porque é fácil resolver tudo em tempo de compilação.

Normalmente há alguma forma explícita na linguagem para resolver conflitos. Dá um pouco mais de trabalho mas os resultados costumam ser mais adequados.

#### Extension method

É uma forma de adicionar implementação extra à uma classe. Ele não adiciona realmente um método à classe mas cria uma ilusão apenas. Ele não tem acesso ao estado interno (privado) da classe). Até hoje só vi implementado em C# e de uma certa forma em D. È mais sintático que semântico.

A combinação de interfaces com métodos de extensão pode ser considerada uma forma limitada de *trait*. Se existisse *extension properties* (que são equivalentes aos "atributos" de Ruby) se equipararia ao *mixin*.

#### *Default method*

Implementado em Java 8 para dar melhor reuso de código. É basicamente uma interface com implementação no método.

É muito parecido com um *trait*. Eu nem saberia dizer qual é a real diferença exceto pelo fato que é comum, mas não obrigatório, que a linguagem dê algum suporte específico e indique sintaticamente que aquela interface tem uma semântica diferente.

E pode até ficar parecido com *mixin* com o uso de métodos *getters* e *setters*. Não é a mesma coisa porque ele não lida com o estado diretamente. E pra falar a verdade como ainda não conheço bem esta nova funcionalidade, não sei todas limitações para fazer isto.

Isso é o mais próximo do *mixin* que o Java (8) chega.

#### Outras

Linguagens menos populares acharam outras formas de resolver os problemas da herança múltipla. No *link* sobre o problema diamante tem algumas descrições.

## Conclusão

Note que nenhuma destas formas alternativas, apesar de serem consideradas formas de obter herança múltipla, não é **a** herança múltipla como definida.

#### Abuso de herança

Herança é usada em exagero. Herança múltipla ainda mais. Ela não é tão necessária assim. Pense bem, para usar herança devemos perguntar se a classe filha **é a classe mãe** ("um carro é um veículo"). É raro uma classe ser duas coisas ao mesmo tempo. Em geral ela é uma coisa e possui determinadas características extras.

Há muita tempestade em copo d'água sobre este assunto. A maior questão aí é que raramente você precisa herança múltipla. E ficando no mesmo tipo de analogia, as pessoas olham o copo meio vazio quando deveriam olhar como meio cheio. Você pode fazer mais com este recurso disponível. Fazer mais é bom quando se sabe programar.

#### Como usar bem herança múltipla em C++

C++ poderia ter uma solução melhor para herança múltipla, poderia ser mais fácil. Mas quando ela foi criada ninguém entendia todas as implicações do que estava criando.

De qualquer forma este é um recurso muito poderoso. Tem que tomar cuidado mas dá para fazer coisas muitos fortes com ela.

É certo que C++ não facilita mas é possível usar as mesmas técnicas de interfaces, *mixins* e *traits*. Basta o programador fazer isto. É escolha dele. Ele apenas tem a escolha de não seguir esta forma. E se ele precisar uma herança de classes completas ele pode fazer também, em outras linguagens ele não pode. Faz parte da filosofia da linguagem permitir que o programador escolha o que é melhor pra ele. Não faz parte da filosofia da linguagem limitar a capacidade do programador.

Se você quer usar *mixin* em C++, faça isso. A linguagem é poderosa o suficiente para fazer desta forma. O compilador só não tem como garantir que esta técnica foi adotada corretamente (não que outras linguagens consigam algo muito melhor). Precisa de um pouco mais de disciplina mas é possível e nem dá trabalho extra.

#### Implementação de compiladores

Claro que é difícil implementar um compilador para lidar com isto, é mais difícil o programador aprender usar isto e precisa ter mais cuidado quando está usado este recurso.  Os implementadores de compiladores C++ devem reclamar mais que os usuários.

#### Recursos extras

- Conforme comentário do Math há informações relevantes [nessa outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22718/101).
- [Comparação das duas técnicas](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/123342/389).
- [Outras razões descritas no Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/218458/389).
- [Um dos melhores textos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/407928/221800) apontando os problemas do C++ sobre este assunto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Excelente resposta, foi bem mais longe do que a pergunta pedia. Não sabia que existia tantas formas de reutilizar código em classes! Obs.: Só faltou colocar o titulo "classe abastrata" ali entre interfaces e traints. =)

Comment: É que classe abstrata é uma classe comum exceto pelo fato dela não poder ser instanciada já que alguns métodos podem não ter implementação. Ou seja, ela não ajuda em nada o foco da pergunta que é a herança múltipla. Você continua só podendo ter uma classe herdada nessas linguagens, seja a classe abstrata ou concreta.

Comment: Mereço a aceitação mas não o voto? na resposta? Você sabe que pode votar também, além de aceitar? Pode votar em qualquer coisa do *site* que você ache útil. Veja o [tour]. Eu vi que você nunca votou em nada. Não perca esta oportunidade, ajuda a comunidade classificar o conteúdo e ainda ganha medalhas por isto.

Comment: "Premissa errada", concordo plenamente com isso, na verdade, as pessoas(me incluo nisso) tem a tendencia e o comodismo de reclamarem, colocar defeito e/ou odiar aquilo que ainda não entendem, não sabem pra que serve ou não conseguem usar. Eu odiava OO até aprender, eu odiava códigos com doctrine, até aprender, eu até mesmo odiava esse negocio chamado composer(melhor invensão do home depois da internet).

Answer (score 6):

Um dos problemas da herança multipla consiste em determinar a origem de métodos na classe especializada.

Por exemplo, considere as seguintes classes:

```
Class A
{
  public:
  int a;
  int b;
  private:
  void metodo(){}
}

Class B
{
  public:
  int c;
  int d;
  private:
  void metodo(){}
}

Class C: public A, public B
{
}
```

De onde vem o método que a classe C herda de A e B? De qual delas?

Classes abstratas do Java funcionam como as classes virtuais (creio que seja esse o termo) do C++, você não pode instanciar um objeto dessas classes e classes concretas que herdam das abstratas são obrigadas a implementar os métodos herdados da classe abstrata.

Um exemplo:

```
public abstract class A {
  boolean eImpar(int num) {
    //Codigo
  }

  boolean abstract ePar(int num); 
  //Nem todos os métodos em classes abstratas     
  //precisam ser abstratos, mas quando forem
  //NÂO devem ter implementação.
}

public class B extends A {
  boolean ePar(int num) {
    //Essa função PRECISA ser implementada na classe.
  }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A exemplo1 = new A(); //Erro! Classe abstrata não pode ser instanciada!
    A exemplo2 = new B(); //Possivel!
  }
}
```

Outro conceito similar a classes abstratas em Java é o de interfaces, e é através delas que você implementa a "herança multipla" do Java.

Exemplo:

```
public class A {}
public class B {}
public class C extends A, B {} //Errado!

public interface I {
  public int getNum();
}
public class A {}
public class B extends A implements I {
  public int getNum() {
    //Tem de implementar o metodo da interface!
  }
}
```

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: `Metodos em classes abstratas não precisam estar definidos, e a palavra-chave 'abstract' é opcional.` está dando muita margem para interpretação errada, que tal: `Nem todos os métodos em classes abstratas precisam ser abstratos, mas quando forem não devem ter implementação` ? Fora isso sua resposta está certa, merece um +1.

Comment: Não tenho certeza se eu entendi errado de novo ou você que está misturando os conceitos. Para fazer um método abstrato em uma classe abstrata você **deve** usar a palavra-chave `abstract`. Em interfaces a história é outra, por mais que você não use modificadores no seu método ele é implicitamente `public abstract`. Concorda?

Comment: Eu que misturei os conceitos mesmo, fiz uma classe abstrata aqui só de brincadeira num projeto, vi que precisava da `abstract` mesmo.

Comment: Sem problemas. Acho que você estava confundindo com interface. O importante é que você consertou a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Acho o uso de herança múltipla em C++ simples e funcional, embora não seja uma estrutura de programação banal.

Requer reflexão sobre a hierarquia de classes e em alguns casos raros identificar explicitamente qual atributo ou método das classes base esta acessando utilizando o operador de resolução de escopo.

Seja este caso do diamante definido na imagem acima:

```
class Object { public: int x; ...};

class Rectangle: public Object {...};

class Clickable: public Object {...};

class Button: public Rectangle, public Clickable {...}
```

O atributo x é criado por dois caminhos, é duplicado.

Para usá-lo preciso informar qual estou usando, como em:

```
void Button::Método() { std::cout << Rectangle::x; }
```

Se não queremos que x apareça duas vezes usamos herança múltipla virtual.

C++ é fácil, extremamente eficiente e poderosa. Tem um comitê ISO internacional super ativo que atualiza a linguagem a cada 3 anos. É usada em dezenas de sistemas operacionais, softwares de computação científica com alto desempenho, softwares de engenharia, softwares de uso geral, gráficos, educativos e com interfaces em modo texto ou gráfica. É um erro grosseiro taxar a linguagem de complexa por causa de suas possibilidades. Você não é obrigado a aprender todos os seus detalhes, não preciso saber decor todos os recursos descritos em https://en.cppreference.com/. É possível fazer excelentes programas em C++ sem usar herança múltipla, exceções, conversões, templates, threads, concepts, etc;

Aprenda o básico e use!
Faça diversos exemplos.

Com o tempo você vai incorporando novos conhecimentos da linguagem e evoluindo. E é aí que esta o diferencial, com C++ você vai aonde a maioria não vai.