# É correto afirmar que interface soluciona o problema de herança múltipla em Java?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança, interface

É conhecido que Java não possui suporte a **heranças múltiplas**. É correto afirmar que o conceito de interface soluciona o problema de herança múltipla em Java? Se sim, por que?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22718/java-n%C3%A3o-possui-heran%C3%A7a-m%C3%BAltipla/89274#89274

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Herança múltipla busca resolver dois problemas:

- **a)** A capacidade de um objeto polimórfico de assumir a forma de objetos de cadeias hierárquicas distintas.
- **b)** A capacidade de um objeto reutilizar código de objetos de cadeias hierárquicas distintas.

Se você aceitar a premissa de que reutilização de código é o pior dos casos de uso de herança, a capacidade **b** oferecida pela herança múltipla é dispensável.

Ora, se a capacidade **b** é dispensável e a capacidade **a** pode ser obtida com interfaces, então **interfaces resolvem sim o problema de herança múltipla**, ou pelo menos entregam uma das capacidades alvo da herança múltipla.

## Interface com implementações *default*

A última versão do Java oferece o recurso de uma interface ter implementação padrão (*default methods*).

Se você já podia ter uma classe implementando diversas interfaces, e se agora estas diversas interfaces oferecem implementações, logo, **em Java 8 as interfaces oferecem as duas capacidades propostas pela múltipla herança**.

## Conclusão

- Em **Java**, uma das duas capacidades da herança múltipla é obtida com o uso de interfaces.
- Em **Java 8**, as duas capacidades da herança múltipla são obtidas com o uso de interfaces.

É claro que os novos recursos de interfaces no Java 8 possuem algumas limitações e são bastante cavernosos, pelo menos por enquanto que ainda não estamos habituados a eles.

## Experiência e opinião

De qualquer modo, como talvez eu já tenha deixado claro, eu não vejo a reutilização de código como um bom motivo para usar herança. A capacidade de um objeto assumir várias formas, inclusive de cadeias hierárquicas distintas, me parece muito mais útil, e isso interfaces resolvem muito bem.

Usando apenas interfaces e muito pouco herança eu tenho conseguido obter designs simples, código poderoso e muita reutilização.

Comment: Tem uma outra pergunta interessante sobre o mesmo assunto, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90168/91

Answer (score 16):

A pergunta feita desta forma fica um pouco controversa. A própria herança múltipla já é controversa, já que algumas pessoas dizem que ela nem é necessária de fato, que as coisas não podem herdar de várias coisas, que no fundo esses casos, seria melhor usar composição. E certamente [ela tem seus problemas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42970/101).

Bom, aí já começamos entrar na polêmica da herança. Depois de anos de abuso hoje se considera a [composição melhor que herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11594/101) em grande parte dos casos. Diz-se que em aplicações reais e não apenas em exercícios a herança traz tantos problemas na maioria dos casos que é melhor evitá-la.

Se a pergunta for em cima da interface obter o mesmo resultado da herança múltipla, então a resposta é não.

Existem soluções melhores que chegam mais próximo do que a herança múltipla consegue. Entre elas estão o *mixin* e o *trait*. Java 8 tem algum próximo disto que são os [*default methods*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22721/101). Estas formas tentam permitir implementações e até estado sem que se constitua uma herança.

A interface prejudica o reuso de código que é a principal proposição da orientação a objeto. Claro que existe um motivo para isto. Ninguém fez isto gratuitamente. Tudo tem seu custo e seu benefício.

Já que interfaces não possuem código, é insano afirmar que elas ajudam o reuso do código. Outros mecanismos associados a interfaces podem até ajudar (delegação, por exemplo), afinal herança, que eu costumo criticar, não é a única forma de reuso de código. Só que a interface claramente não é uma dessas formas. Interfaces são apenas contratos.

Interfaces podem ajudar manter o contrato, mas não podem ter estado, não podem ter implementações. Então elas são diferentes. Elas ajudam, mas não substituem herança múltipla.

Interfaces **ajudam** mais no polimorfismo. Interface não é herança a não ser que considere herança um papel que diz que você como herdeiro não ganhou nada e vai ter que se virar para obter o que quer seguindo uma obrigatoriedade.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "A interface prejudica o reuso de código" - então ao "programar por interfaces" eu estarei abrindo mão, ou reduzindo drasticamente  a possibilidade,  de poder usar meu código em outros projetos?

Comment: É um pouco mais complicado que isto. Ela prejudica o reuso. Não inviabiliza. O problema é que ela não tem código. Aí você tem duas opções quando for implementar a interface, ou reescreve um código possivelmente já existente, ou seja não reusou nada, ou então cria uma classe utilitária que contém o código padrão necessário para a implementação e chama esta classe dentro da sua implementação. Até ocorre um certo reuso, mas não de forma automática que é a ideia da OOP. Interfaces são ótimas, mas não resolve tudo e não é livre de problemas. Procure outras perguntas sobre o assunto ou abra uma nova

Comment: @bigown Você quer dizer então que o que prejudica o reuso de código é ter (ou usar) _apenas_ interfaces? Algo no jeito que você escreveu fez parecer que todo uso de interfaces causa isso.

Comment: @Pablo As interfaces puras certamente prejudicam o reuso de código. É óbvio que há casos que elas são necessárias, isto é outra coisa. Mas toda vez que opta por uma interface pura, ela não tem código, então não há reuso, há apenas contrato. O que promove o reuso é a herança comum de classe concreta ou abstrata ou de mecanismos que possuem códigos, como *mixins*, *traits* e assemelhados. Entre outras coisas que não são consideradas tão orientadas a objeto. O reuso pode ser obtido de várias formas.

Comment: @bigown Tá certo. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Answer (score 4):

Sim, a interface pode resolver esse problema, mas não sozinha. Além da interface, precisamos do uso de classes extras, abstratas e concretas, arbitrariando delegação manual para resolver o problema.

Na tentativa de compreender como resolver vários problemas de herança no Java,  esse exemplo baseado no [stackoverflow Java Multiple Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824402/java-multiple-inheritance) ilustra de forma clássica o problema do diamante e como podemos solucioná-lo.

Vamos supor que eu tenho a classe `Animal` que estende ave e cavalo e que eu preciso fazer uma classe Pegasus, que se estende de `Ave` e `Cavalo`, `Pegasus` é uma ave e um cavalo ao mesmo tempo.
Para resolver esse problema de múltipla  herança, é fazer com que `Pegasus` implemente as interfaces pássaro e cavalo.

**Exemplo 1**

Considere as seguintes interfaces:

```
public class Passaro implements Avem { }
```

e

```
public class Cavalo implements Equo { }
```

e também

```
public class Pegasus implements Avem, Equo { }
```

A fim de reduzir o código duplicado, você pode criar uma classe abstrata que contém a maior parte do código comum dos animais que você deseja implementar.

```
public abstract class AbstractCavalo implements Equo { }

public class Cavalo extends AbstractCavalo { }

public class Pegasus extends AbstractCavalo implements Avialae { }
```

**Exemplo 2**

Esse outro exemplo maior, porém  mais explicativo, do mesmo link citado anteriormente, pode ajudar-nos a entender mais de perto a questão de como a interface pode ser usada para solucionar o problema da múltipla herança:

Aqui temos a interface animal:

```
   public interface Animal{
        public int numeroDePernas();
        public boolean podeVoar();
        public boolean podeSerMontado();
    }
```

Interface Passaro que estende a interface Animal:

```
public interface Passaro extends Animal{
    public void fazerCoisasDePassaro();
}
```

Interface Cavalo  que estende a interface Animal:

```
public interface Cavalo extends Animal{
    public void fazerCoisasDeCavalo();
}
```

Aqui temos a Interface Pegasus que estende a interface Passaro e Cavalo:

```
public interface Pegasus extends Passaro,Cavalo{

}
```

Classe abstrata AnimalImplementacao que implementa a interface Animal:

```
public abstract class AnimalImplementacao implements Animal{
    private final int numeroDePernas;

    public AnimalImplementacao(int numeroDePernas) {
        super();
        this.numeroDePernas = numeroDePernas;
    }

    @Override
    public int numeroDePernas() {
        return numeroDePernas;
    }
}
```

Classe abstrata PassaroImplementacao que herda de AnimalImplementacao e implementa a interface Passaro:

```
public class PassaroImplementacao extends AnimalImplementacao implements Passaro{

    public PassaroImplementacao() {
        super(2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean podeVoar() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean podeSerMontado() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void fazerCoisasDePassaro() {
        System.out.println("fazendo coisa de passaro...");
    }

}
```

Classe abstrata CavaloImplementacao que herda de AnimalImplementacao e implementa a interface Cavalo:

```
public class CavaloImplementacao extends AnimalImplementacao implements Cavalo{

    public CavaloImplementacao() {
        super(4);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean podeVoar() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean podeSerMontado() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void fazerCoisasDeCavalo() {
        System.out.println("fazendo coisas de cavalo...");
    }

}
```

E finalmente:
Classe concreta PegasusImplementacao que implementa a interface Pegasus:

```
public class PegasusImplementacao implements Pegasus{

    private final Cavalo cavalo = new CavaloImplementacao();
    private final Passaro passaro = new PassaroImplementacao();


    @Override
    public void fazerCoisasDePassaro() {
        passaro.fazerCoisasDePassaro();
    }

    @Override
    public int numeroDePernas() {
        return cavalo.numeroDePernas();
    }

    @Override
    public void fazerCoisasDeCavalo() {
        cavalo.fazerCoisasDeCavalo();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean podeVoar() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean podeSerMontado() {
        return true;
    }
 }
```

Desta forma, vimos como a interface contorna o problema da múltipla herança em java. Entretanto, java não pode ter herança múltipla de forma alguma. Assim, o uso de interfaces, classes abstratas e classes concretas são componentes que ajudam a resolver esse tipo de problema.
Espero ter ajudado Duds.

Comment: A resposta está quase toda correta. Só a parte mais importante dela está errada. O primeiro e o último parágrafo onde dá a conclusão. A resposta comprovou que a interface não resolve o problema da herança múltipla. Além da interface, precisou do uso de classes extras, abstratas e concretas e fazer delegação manual para resolver o problema. Lembrando que delegação manual é justamente o que a herança tenta evitar. Pode até ter obtido o mesmo resultado, mas o código é enorme, não há reuso. E pra falar a verdade, neste caso, a interface é só acessória. A solução está nas classes.

Comment: O código apresentado claramente viola o DRY dificultando a manutenção. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22721/101

Comment: Melhorou mas ainda conclui que ela resolve o problema, quando ela só ajuda tangencialmente. Ela **não** resolve o problema.

Comment: Editei  a resposta e agora a  conclusão esta correta!Obrigado.