# Interface Java 8

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, java-8, interface, classes-abstratas

O Java 8 permite que você implemente métodos na própria interface.

Sendo assim gostaria de saber o que uma classe abstrata pode fazer que uma interface não pode.

Fonte: http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-default-methods/

Comment: Nessa pergunta tem uma [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3620/91) sobre o java8 porém foi apagada pelo autor, talvez fosse interessante ressuscitar  ela. Se não puder ver, tem uma [imagem aqui](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tBJs7.png)

Comment: Implementar os métodos na interface? Pode passar a referência disso?

Comment: @jbueno claro, tambem me espantei quando o bigown me informou, e essa foi a motivação para criar a pergunta e deixar mais claro entre a comunidade.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Classes abstratas podem conter estado e interface não pode. Esta é a principal justificativa para usá-la do ponto de vista mais técnico. Obviamente que por ter estado, ela pode ter construtores, interface não.

Outro motivo é a possibilidade de ter membros privados. Interfaces continuam só podendo ter métodos públicos, pelo menos por enquanto, não faz sentido manter essa restrição.

Do ponto de vista conceitual a classe abstrata ainda passa a ideia de que o objeto derivado **é um** objeto base. A interface continua passando a ideia de que o objeto que usa a interface apenas **tem um** comportamento específico.

Lembrando que sempre foi mais interessante, na maioria dos cenários, criar interfaces do que classes abstratas na medida do possível.

Ou seja, não muda nada, a não ser que automatizou um pouco o processo do uso de interface. Você não vai passar usar interfaces onde precisava usar uma classe abstrata, a não ser que usava classe abstrata onde não devia. Melhorou o uso da interface, não mudou o caso de uso de cada um dos mecanismos.

Até o Java 7 o método concreto que cumpre o contrato da interface precisava ser escrito na classe. Havia casos que isto poderia gerar duplicação de código. Para evitar a duplicação a solução era criar uma [classe utilitária](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90047/101) (chamada *companion class*) com a implementação concreta. Aí dentro do método na classe concreta que implementa a interface era só chamar o método utilitário desta desta classe companheira.

No Java 8, não precisa fazer isto. O método já é escrito dentro da interface e na classe concreta não precisa escrever nada, a classe já sabe o que executar. Obviamente a classe utilitária deixou de ser necessária. Facilita o reuso de código e melhora o encapsulamento.

Note que nada impede de implementar algo diferente e sobrepor a implementação *default* da interface. E obviamente é obrigado implementar o método concreto, criando uma desambiguação, se há mais que uma interface exigindo o mesmo método (mesma assinatura)

[Documentação "oficial" dos *default methods*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html).

Relacionado: [Java 8 "default method" versus C# "extend method"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121240/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Excelente, muito boa explicação.

Comment: Ótima explicação.