# Como fazer uma interface em C++?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, interface

Java, C# e outras linguagens possuem o conceito de interface, o que é bem útil em algumas circunstâncias. Como fazer uma interface ou o mais próximo disso em C++?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basta criar uma classe 100% abstrata, que é obtida apenas por convenção. Assim como não existe uma palavra-chave para determinar que algo é uma interface, não existe nada que obrigue a classe ser abstrata. Então basta ter todos os métodos escritos sem implementação (método puramente virtual) e sem estado:

```
class Interfaceable {
public:
    virtual void Interface() = 0; // isso é um método puramente virtual
};
```

Se tentar instanciar esta classe, não dá. Ela é abstrata, há um método explicitamente sem implementação.

Aí toda classe que seja escrita com herança desta classe será obrigado implementar o método `Interface` com esta assinatura.

```
class Classe : public Interfaceable {
public:
    void Interface();
};

void Classe::Interface() {
    cout << "interface";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/mPqf3o). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bnuzuumq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/OOP/Interface.cpp).

Pelo menos não há outra forma em C++ padrão (tem compilador com dialeto que permite).

Se quiser usar algo equivalente aos [*default methods* das interfaces do Java 8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90168/101), basta colocar uma implementação lá na classe abstrata ao invés de deixá-lo como *pure virtual*. Lembrando que C++ permite múltipla herança.