# Diferença entre classe e interface

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, classes, terminologia, interface

Qual a diferença entre classe e interface e em que momento devo usar uma ou outra?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Classes são estruturas de dados completas. Elas possuem, ou pelo menos podem possuir estado e comportamento. Então elas são compostas por variáveis e métodos diversos incluindo aí a implementação dos métodos. Classes normais podem ser instanciadas (criar objetos de acordo com sua estrutura). Pode-se herdar de classes (geralmente).

Interfaces são apenas contratos. Elas só possuem a [declaração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101) das [assinaturas de métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) que devem existir em uma classe para conformar com uma interface. Em geral, mas nem sempre, elas não possuem implementações (código) dos métodos e **nada de dados**. Interfaces só podem ser usadas em conjunto com classes ou outras interfaces (herança).

Ambas são tipos de dados e seus detalhes podem variar um pouco de acordo com a linguagem, então tome cuidado para não aprender o conceito de uma linguagem e achar que se aplica igual em todas elas.

As [classes abstratas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87423/101), a grosso modo, são o meio termo entre classes e interface, já que elas podem ter métodos sem implementação. [Elas só podem ser herdadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89236/101), não podem ter instâncias concretas diretamente.

Há linguagens que permitem alguma [implementação em interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90168/101), mas de forma limitada. [Algumas linguagens não possuem sintaxe específica para interfaces](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127279/101), mas o conceito pode ser aplicado.

Interfaces soam bastante estranho em linguagens dinamicamente tipadas, afinal elas não prezam muito por contratos. Não que outras estruturas seja muito melhor, essas linguagens de tipagem dinâmica "Modernas" são bem esquisitas, parece que não sabem onde querem chegar, falta visão do que importa para elas, e algumas pessoas consideram que estão conceitualmente erradas por definição.

Tem uma [pergunta mostrando quando usar interfaces](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/101) e diversos *links* sobre o assunto. Há uma corrente que prega que deve-se [preferir a interface sempre que possível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101). Mas [não pode exagerar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23900/101).

[Exemplo prático da diferença em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76316/101). E [sobre PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115695/101) (pra mim o maior exemplo de uso errado de interface, a não ser que eles desistam de vez de ter tipagem dinâmica, que está quase caminhando, mas impossível no estágio atual, sem quebrar tudo o que existe, ou seja, eles queriam outra coisa para essa linguagem, mas começaram do jeito que não queriam.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Esclarecido, Obrigado.