# Qual a diferença entre um estado (referente a Máquina de estados) e uma classe?

Tags: java, classes

Gostaria de saber diferenciar um estado, uma interface de uma classe, quais suas principais diferenças? Como as posso distinguir?

Comment: Humnn !?!?!?!?! Dê mais contexto, talvez fosse bom mostrar onde está se confundindo. Ou pelo menos deixar mais claro sobre o que está falando, onde quer chegar? O que espera que respondamos. Essas coisas não parecem ter ligação. Estado é algo usado em vários contextos. Classe é classe, qual a dúvida? *Timeout*? *Input*?!?!?!

Comment: @bigown reformulei a minha pergunta

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136404/101. Não entendo o que máquina de estados tem a ver com classes e interfaces. Pode ter se você contextualizar.

Comment: @bigown interfaces e estados são coisas distintas ou são equivalentes?

Comment: São coisas tão distintas que eu não sei nem o que estão fazendo na mesma pergunta.

Comment: Minha resposta sanou suas dúvidas? se sim, por favor marque-a como "Aceita", caso contrário, reedite sua pergunta para ficar mais claro o que você precisa saber, ok?

Comment: Relacionada: [Em qual contexto o padrão de máquina de estado é indicado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/493062/357)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Estado (de uma Máquina de Estados):**

Um Estado pode ser simplesmente uma Instância de uma Classe que implementa uma Interface que podemos chamar de 'Estado'. Você pode ter várias classes implementando a interface 'Estado', como a Classe 'EstadoX', a Classe 'EstadoY', etc. Veja:

```
public interface EstadoDosBotoes { //Esta é a Interface
    boolean isExibirBotaoAbrirArquivo();
    boolean isExibirBotaoSalvarArquivo();
    boolean isExibirBotaoNovoArquivo();
    boolean isExibirBotaoFecharArquivo();
}
public class EstadoSemArquivoAberto implements EstadoDosBotoes { //Classe que implementa a interface
   public boolean isExibirBotaoAbrirArquivo() {return true;}
   public boolean isExibirBotaoSalvarArquivo() {return false;}
   public boolean isExibirBotaoNovoArquivo() {return true;}
   public boolean isExibirBotaoFecharArquivo() {return false;}
}
public class EstadoComArquivoAberto implements EstadoDosBotoes { //Outra Classe que implementa a interface
   public boolean isExibirBotaoAbrirArquivo() {return false;}
   public boolean isExibirBotaoSalvarArquivo() {return true;}
   public boolean isExibirBotaoNovoArquivo() {return false;}
   public boolean isExibirBotaoFecharArquivo() {return true;}
}
```

### **Máquina de Estados:**

Uma 'Máquina de Estados' pode ser simplesmente uma Instância de uma Classe que possui um 'Estado', assim:

```
public class ControladorDosBotoes {//Esta é nossa "Máquina de Estados"
    private EstadoDosBotoes estadoAtualDosBotoes = new EstadoSemArquivoAberto();
    public void setEstado(EstadoDosBotoes novoEstado) {estadoAtualDosBotoes = novoEstado;}
}
```

Criamos "Máquinas de Estado" quando temos algum Objeto que precisa alternar entre determinados Estados específicos durante a execução, para cada Estado possível você deverá criar uma Classe que implementa a interface que a "Máquina de Estados" aceita (no nosso caso, a interface "EstadoDosBotoes"), como fizemos acima.

Isso garante que o "ControladorDeBotoes" só vá alternar entre os Estados "EstadoComArquivoAberto" e "EstadoSemArquivoAberto", e qualquer outro Estado que criarmos posteriormente; Assim, você define em cada Estado os Botões que serão exibidos (e os que não serão) enquanto o "ControladorDeBotoes" estiver neste Estado (*possuir este estado*).

A "Máquina de Estados" precisa utilizar o "Estado" que ela possui atualmente, se comportando de modo diferente para cada "Estado" que você colocar nela; isso pode
exigir que cada "Estado" possua um ou mais métodos (sobrecritos da Interface "Estado") que a "Máquina de Estados" irá chamar para que eles façam algo. Isto já assemelha-se ao *Padrão Strategy*, pois você pode alterar - até mesmo durante a execução! - o código que seu Cliente-da-Estratégia (sua Máquina de Estados) irá executar simplesmente alterando a Estratégia (o "Estado") que está dentro dele(a).

### **Diferenças entre o Estado (de uma Máquina de Estados), Interface e Classe:**

- Um Estado é uma Instância de uma Classe que implementa uma Interface;
- Uma Interface declara métodos (sem corpo, ou seja, sem código dentro) que uma Classe que implemente esta interface deverá implementar (deverá adicionar o código ao método declarado na interface). Ou seja, a Interface define o retorno e os parâmetros de entrada de cada método, assim como os nomes deles, e, as Classes que implementarem esta interface deverão definir o código para cada um destes métodos.
- Uma Classe é um Arquivo onde você colocará o código em si. Para criar "Estados" você deve ter uma Interface que declare todos os métodos que a "Máquina de Estados" precisará chamar em seu Estado interno, e, deverá criar uma Classe para cada Estado fazendo-a implementar (*"implements"*) esta Interface. Para criar uma "Máquina de Estados", você deverá criar uma Classe que receba e utilize uma Instância (um Estado) que implementa a Interface em questão, *onde esta "Máquina de Estados" deverá mudar seu comportamento de acordo com o Estado que possuir*.