# O que é uma máquina de estado?

Tags: terminologia, thread, assincronismo

Eu estou fazendo uma tour no site, pesquisando sobre assincronismo, threads, paralelismo e afins.

Ao encontrar esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/19172/4995), percebi que o autor faz uma citação a respeito de *máquinas de estado*.

Não entendi muito bem o que seria uma máquina de estado e qual relação ela teria com assincronismo, threads e afins.

- O que seria máquina de estado?
- Qual é a relação com os termos citados acima?

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a diferença entre um estado (referente a Máquina de estados) e uma classe?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195283/51124)

Comment: Relacionada: [Em qual contexto o padrão de máquina de estado é indicado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/493062/357)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O assincronismo pode ser obtido através de uma máquina de estados já que ele precisa apenas garantir que não ocorra espera enquanto está fazendo algo potencialmente demorado, então ele precisa trocar o contexto de execução entre mais de uma parte da aplicação.

Esta é uma técnica antiga e bem conhecida usada em diversos problemas. Ela vai trocando um ou mais determinados estados de acordo com o que vai acontecendo em algo relacionado com o que ela está controlando.

Mesmo este mecanismo tem diversas formas de implementá-lo. A forma como a entrada que provoca troca de estado pode ser obtida de diversas maneiras. Um sistema de eventos que indica a mudança de estado é bem comum.

A imagem lá na pergunta é bem ilustrativa como é complicado controlar o fluxo de execução. Siga a guerra de índio.

[image: Máquina de estados async/await]

[Artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

[Uma implementação em C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5924053/221800).

[Explicação detalhada de como O `async/await` do C# funciona](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-c-sharp-async-await-1-compilation). Ali tem exemplos mais ou menos de como o código fica na verdade quando este mecanismo é usado. Tudo ali é uma máquina de estados, sendo que o que está esperando é o responsável por mudar o estado dessa máquina. Quando não houver mais espera um processamento diferente é executado encerrando o que começou, mas não bloqueia a execução de outras coisas. Há um controle se ainda pode executar alguma outra coisa, ou se deve retomar o processamento do que está em espera.

Um [exemplo de código real que é gerado pelo compilador](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/535635/Async-Await-and-the-Generated-StateMachine). Simples, não?

> ainda vou melhorar.

Comment: Sei que vai melhorar ainda, mas vou dar meu +1 de confiança

Comment: Esperando as melhorias!

Comment: :P :P :P :P :P :P

Answer (score 6):

Uma máquina de estado é um termo da ciência da computação que descreve um programa de computador. Se você parar para pensar, um sistema é um conjunto de estados, por exemplo, na sequência de fibonacci temos a soma dos dois últimos números para formar o próximo número. Essa máquina teria um estado inicial:

```
N1: 1
N2: 1
N3: 2
```

O estado seguinte seria:

```
N1: 1
N2: 2
N3: 3
```

E assim por diante. Uma máquina de estado é a representação gráfica de um programa de computador e todos os seus estados possíveis e é geralmente usado para ilustrar fluxos de dados e de informações, descrevendo os estados que acontecem no meio do caminho.

Ele não tem nenhuma relação com os termos, até porque ele é usado apenas para ilustração e diagramação. Pode ser que a pessoa tenha se *utilizado* de uma máquina de estados para representar o funcionamento de algum programa assíncrono ou de alguma *thread*.

Veja [este link](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1quina_de_estados_finita) para uma melhor referência.