# Qual a diferença entre Semáforo e Monitor?

Tags: java, terminologia, concorrência, semáforo

Estou com uma dúvida no conceito dessas duas **estruturas**.

- Qual seria a diferença entre elas?
- Qual é mais rápida?
- E qual é mais fácil de usar?
- Poderia me dar um exemplo básico de cada uma?

Comment: O que são "Semáforo" e "Monitor"? Onde você viu esses termos? Semáforo trata-se de `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`?

Comment: @Douglas , esses termos eu vi na disciplina de programação concorrente e paralela, mas infelizmente não lembro o que era monitor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O [monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)) é um mecanismo de mais alto nível cujo objetivo é impedir o acesso concorrente inadequado, obrigando uma *thread* esperar por outra terminar o que está fazendo. Ele é um objeto específico que controla esse acesso a um outro objeto principal que precisa da proteção de concorrência. É um mecanismo mais pronto, você só precisa dizer que precisa monitorar este objeto, em alguns casos precisa dizer que não precisa mais.

Um código tirado da Wikipedia demonstra como ele funciona (note que é possível que a linguagem esconda a complexidade disto tudo):

```
class Account {
    private lock myLock //isto pode ser escondido do código
    private int balance := 0
    invariant balance >= 0

    public method boolean withdraw(int amount)
        precondition amount >= 0 {
        myLock.acquire() //isto pode ser simplificado no código
        try {
            if balance < amount {
                return false
            } else {
                balance := balance - amount
                return true
            }
        } finally {
            myLock.release()
        }
    }

    public method deposit(int amount)
        precondition amount >= 0 {
        myLock.acquire() //isto pode ser simplificado no código
        try {
            balance := balance + amount
        } finally {
            myLock.release()
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Semaphore.java).

Ele pode ser implementado com diversas técnicas, uma das mais usadas é a do [semáforo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)), onde existe uma informação que indica se o objeto pode ser acessado ou não através de um contador atômico (não há risco de haver incremento ou decremento concorrente criando uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101)).

Se há a indicação que há uma *thread* trabalhando no objeto em uma situação que precisa da proteção através deste contador é como se tivesse um sinal vermelho dizendo que não ninguém pode fazer o que deseja. Quando esta operação termina, é mudado o estado do semáforo, ou seja, dá luz verde para outro fazer o que quiser, o que poderá provocar uma nova mudança de estado para vermelho. Em geral isto é implementado como uma [máquina de estados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/208328/101).

Obviamente por ser mais baixo nível o risco de fazer é algo errado é maior no semáforo, dá um pouco mais de trabalho controlar seu funcionamento.

O monitor tende ser mais rápido e por isso é preferido hoje me dia, sempre que possível.

Em geral ele pode gerenciar filas de *threads* que estão esperando para operar naquele objeto.

Pseudocódigo que representa um semáforo:

```
struct Semaphore { //pode ser o mesmo do lock usado no monitor
    int value; //o mutex costuma ser só um booleano
    Queue q;
} S;
withdraw(account, amount) {
wait(S);
    balance = get_balance(account);
    balance -= amount;
    put_balance(account, balance);
    signal(S);
    return balance;
}
wait(S) {
    Disable interrupts;
    while (S->value == 0) {
        enqueue(S->q, current_thread);
        thread_sleep(current_thread);
    }
    S->value--;
    Enable interrupts;
}
signal(S) {
    Disable interrupts;
    thread = dequeue(S->q);
    thread_start(thread);
    S->value++;
    Enable interrupts;
}
```

[Fonte](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/fa05/cse120/lectures/120-l6.pdf).

[Mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) é outra forma muito comum de fazer o mesmo. A maior diferença para um semáforo é que só a *thread* que bloqueou o objeto pode liberá-lo. Outra diferença é que ele apenas determina se o objeto está bloqueado ou não.

Muitas vezes usa-se os termos sincronização ou travamento para dizer mais ou menos a mesma coisa.

Existem implementações que vão além do processo.

Se alguém disser que não é bem assim, tem chance dela estar certa, tem fontes controversas sobre como é cada. O assunto é um pouco mais complicado que isto, talvez alguém esteja com paciência para dar mais detalhes.

[Java trabalha com monitores em todos os objetos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).