# O que são Mutexes e quando é aconselhável usar este recurso?

Tags: c#, .net, aplicação-desktop, processo

Li a respeito de *Mutexes* e a classe [Mutex](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=netframework-4.7.2). Porém, não consigo compreender de forma clara o que de fato é Mutex e o que esta classe faz.

Sendo que eu gostaria de saber se posso usar este recurso para impedir que minha aplicação desktop seja executada mais de uma vez (várias instancias do mesmo processo no caso do usuário abrir o programa repetida vezes).

Uma implementação que fiz foi a seguinte:

```
private bool ProcessoExecutando()
{
    var localizacao = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    FileSystemInfo systemInfo = new FileInfo(localizacao);
    Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "Global\\" + systemInfo.Name, out bool novoProcessoCriado);
    if (novoProcessoCriado)
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
    return !novoProcessoCriado;
}
```

Este método é chamado no método `Main()` e serve em tese para verificar se já existe uma instancia do processo da aplicação executando. E me parece um pouco gambiarra =/

Veja:

```
static void Main()
{
    if (ProcessoExecutando())
    {
        return;
    }

    //Inicia aplicação
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);            
    Application.Run(new AppMain());
}
```

No entanto, o significado da classe `Mutex` esta confuso em minha mente e a minha falta de conhecimento nisto pode fazer com que eu use este recurso de forma equivocada.

Sendo assim, eu gostaria de ter as dúvidas abaixo esclarecidas.

## Dúvidas

1. O que são Mutexes?
2. Quando é aconselhável usar a classe `Mutex`?
3. O caso ilustrado acima do usado da classe `Mutex` é o ideal para
   impedir que a aplicação seja executada mais de uma vez?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> O que são Mutexes?

O mecanismo de MUTual EXclusion é usado em ambientes concorrentes e é uma forma de impedir que um recurso seja acessado por mais de uma linha de processamento ao mesmo tempo. Ele é usado principalmente para evitar a [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101), para manter uma operação [atômica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253852/101).

Ele é uma forma de travamento de um recurso, em geral na memória. Existem outros mecanismos parecidos como o semáforo, por exemplo, onde [já dei uma resposta e falei superficialmente sobre o Mutex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/208859/101). O [artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) mostra alguns.

Enquanto um recurso qualquer não pode ser acessado concorrentemente ele não precisa de um mecanismo desse tipo, e muitas vezes é preferível ter alguma forma assim que é muito mais simples, até mesmo se precisar duplicar o recurso. Criar um Mutex não é barato, e todo recurso que só pode ser acessado com uma consulta ao Mutex tem um acesso muito mais caro que o normal, em alguns casos esse controle é mais caro que o acesso em si. Mas nem todos os casos podem ter o acesso concorrente eliminado, há objetos que precisam de um estado global consistente.

Há casos que um objeto pode ter um Mutex interno, em outros pode ser usado de forma individualizada. O uso interno pode dar mais garantia que nenhum acesso será violado, porém obriga o objeto ter o custo desse controle em todos os acessos, até mesmo quando não há concorrência.

O Mutex, de forma geral, é um objeto que indica se o objeto está sendo acessado por algum código naquele momento ou não. Então você sempre precisa consultá-lo para saber se pode fazer algo no objeto. Se a consulta não for feita e tentar acessar o objeto sem cuidado poderá causar problemas. Você só poderá acessar o objeto de forma livre se o Mutex for liberado e isto só deve ocorrer quando quem o criou o fizer.

Só uma linha de processamento pode ser dono de um Mutex para um recurso.

Entenda o Mutex como um porteiro que diz quem pode entrar ou não em um lugar e ele só deixa entrar se o local está vago. Sabe ambientes onde todo mundo quer falar e só um pode. Alguém controla o microfone de quem pode falar naquela hora. Esse é o Mutex. Esse caso específico só quem pode dizer que outra pessoa pode usar o microfone é quem está usando. Só ele pode desligar o uso e permitir que outra pessoa comece usar. A outra pessoa pode ficar tentando, mas não tem acesso a ele enquanto o outro está usando.

No C# é possível ver o [código da classe que implementa o Mutex](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/mutex.cs,29b92e0e2832a8d6). Ou [pode ver como é no .NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Threading/Mutex.cs,29b92e0e2832a8d6), bem diferente e precisa seguir as abstrações já que cada sistema operacional é diferente.

[image: Threads tentando acessar um objeto]

> Quando é aconselhável usar a classe Mutex?

Em essência o que já foi dito. Há exemplos nos *links* para respostas já postadas aqui no SOpt que mostram isto.

> O caso ilustrado acima do usado da classe Mutex é o ideal para impedir que a aplicação seja executada mais de uma vez?

Não me parece ser necessário um Mutex, é possível você saber que a aplicação está em execução de outras formas, e o custo disto geralmente já é bem alto, não preciso de um mecanismo de baixo custo que é o caso do Mutex.

Normalmente um Mutex deve durar muito pouco tempo sob pena de causar [*deadlocks*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/64484/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).