# "foreach" do C# vs "ForEach()" do EF6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, foreach

Segue código:

#### `ForEach()` do EF6:

```
var result = ctx.Table.Where(x => x.User == "João").ToList();
result.ForEach(x => x.Read = true);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

#### `foreach` do C#:

```
var result = ctx.Table.Where(x => x.User == "João").ToList();
foreach (var item in result)
{
    item.Read = true;
}
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Acredito que os códigos acima são a mesma funcionalidade, qual é a diferença entre elas?

Comment: O do EF é Linq, o de baixo não

Comment: Mais e o desempenho ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ao contrário do que possa parecer, os códigos LINQ do Entity Framework tentarão gerar uma expressão SQL ou algo equivalente que processe os dados do banco de dados. Ele não executará exatamente o código que está escrito ali. Isso é que se chama DSL (Domain Specific Language). Deve ocorrer com o `Where()` usado antes para adquirir o que está no banco de dados.

Mas não deve ocorrer com o `ForEach()` que não existe no fornecedor LINQ do EF. Então a diferença entre eles é quase sintática.

Pra saber qual demora mais teria que fazer testes. O problema é que ambos são abstrações que possuem custo. O `foreach` precisa pegar um iterador que é um objeto externo à coleção para controlar o andamento de cada item. Isto não é de graça. Já o `ForEach()` do `List` é um `for` simples sem iterador, o que é mais rápido. Por outro lado, ele precisa chamar um delegado em cada iteração, que não é de graça.

Em geral ele é [usado para paralelização de processamento](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#overloads) que não é possível com o comando `foreach`, ele é um pouco mais caro, mas se há ganhos (nem sempre há) pode terminar antes se executar em paralelo. Neste caso é só um processamento na aplicação em cima do resultado trazido pelo banco de dados.

Tem gente que gosta dele em qualquer situação por ficar mais curto e eventualmente mais semântico sobre o que quer fazer. Mas a performance não é boa se não paralelizar bem. E a paralelização nem está disponível em toda implementação do `ForEach()`. Ao contrário do que as pessoas imaginam ele não é um método único, pode ter vários sabores.

Veja mais:

- [Qual a diferença entre IEnumerable, IQueryable e List?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17284/101)
- [Uma consulta LINQ retorna qual tipo de dado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129810/101)
- [O que é tecnologia LINQ?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182176/101)
- [Como funciona a lógica do Where no Entity Framework?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125811/101)
- [Fonte do `ForEach()` do `List`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,03061465caeb91cc) ([.NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/List.cs,0053606219c31c58))
- [Tem outros](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=foreach) ([.NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#q=foreach))

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Mas existe `ForEach` pra IEnumerable?

Comment: Não, não faz muito sentido. Ele é no máximo um método de conveniência. O objetivo do LINQ é fazer consultas e não processamentos. O objetivo do `ForEach()` é fazer processamentos.

Comment: Acho que eu confundi alguma coisa na resposta. Por que o primeiro código iria demorar mais?

Comment: Tenta ver esses *links* que explica o funcionamento do LINQ. Ele é uma abstração com um custo extra de uma [máquina de estados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/208328/101) para gerenciar cada passo da execução, ao contrário do `foreach` que é um código mais limpo (mas nem tanto, porque em alguns casos o `for` pode ser ainda mais rápido).

Comment: Ok. Eu tenho uma base do funcionamento do LINQ, porém não existe LINQ ali (exceto pela query). Existe?

Comment: @LINQ aí eu que me confundi. Esse `ForEach` não é LINQ mesmo, esse é "nativo" do `List` como você respondeu. Vou melhorar a resposta, porque isso pode não ser verdade. Obrigado por ter falado.

Comment: O LINQ tem algum tipo de foreach? Se o `ForEach()` é do `List` então qual seria o foreach do LINQ?

Comment: Não existe, @gato

Answer (score 18):

O método `ForEach()` não tem nenhuma relação com o Entity Framework.

Ele é um método da classe **`List`**, [vide documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach). Perceba que ele não tem nem relação com o LINQ, ele é nativo de `List`.

Não existe nenhuma diferença importante entre os dois. São duas formas diferentes de se fazer a mesma coisa. No fundo o método usa o *for* para passar por todos os elementos.

Eis o código do método:

```
public void ForEach(Action<T> action) {
    if( action == null) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.match);
    }
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    int version = _version;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < _size; i++) {
        if (version != _version && BinaryCompatibility.TargetsAtLeast_Desktop_V4_5) {
            break;
        }
        action(_items[i]);
    }

    if (version != _version && BinaryCompatibility.TargetsAtLeast_Desktop_V4_5)
        ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_EnumFailedVersion);
}
```

<sup>[**Veja mais em referencesource.microsfot.com**](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,545)</sup>

Obviamente que muda bastante a forma de escrever/ler o código, qual é melhor ou mais legível é uma questão de gosto.

Acho interessante ler [este artigo do Eric Lippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/) que trata do assunto (não diretamente da sua pergunta, mas trata).

Comment: Eu gostaria de saber como é o funcionamento deste `ForEach()`, vc poderia me explicar?

Comment: Como assim, @gato? É a mesma coisa do `foreach` normal. Não sei se entendi bem sua pergunta.

Comment: Ele me parece um método, como este método consegue interagir numa lista e ao alcançar o mesmo resultado do `foreach`?

Comment: Ele recebe uma `Action<T>`, certo? Internamente é passado por todos os itens da lista e essa action é chamada para todos os elementos. Algo como `foreach(T element in this._itens) { action(element) }`. Entende?

Comment: Então no fundo é um `foreach`!? Daria até para criar os seus próprios `ForEach()` então, eu achava q ele era algo nativo da linguagem.

Comment: @gato Sim, é um `foreach`. Pensei que isso tinha ficado claro na resposta :p (editarei). Ele faz parte da classe `List`, não tem a ver com a linguagem em si.

Comment: @gato Na verdade é um for

Comment: Eu estava pensando, q um for seria mais performático ;P