# O que são loop Parallel.For e Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, .net, terminologia, assincronismo, paralelismo

Vi o uso de [`Parallel.For`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx) e [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd997393(v=vs.110).aspx) em alguns lugares, sei que são *loops*, mas não entendi como e quando devo usá-los e tenho minhas duvidas.

O que são *loop* `Parallel.For` e `Parallel.ForEach`?

Quando devemos usá-los?

Tem alguma diferença entre eles?

Comment: Acho que já está respondido aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211053/101

Comment: @bigown, o que me deixa sem entender do assunto é o uso do Parellel. Sua resposta especificar o uso dos loops e ate linka o Parallel, mas não explica bem o assunto nem diz quando devo usar-los.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Imagine que você tem um diretório no seu computador com 8 arquivos de música no formato FLAC. Excelente formato a propósito, áudio limpo.

Agora imagine que você quer converter estes arquivos de FLAC para MP3 (não tão bom assim) pois seu cd-player (nem o meu) reconhecem o formato FLAC. Você vai criar seu próprio código para converter arquivos de áudio:

Primeiro, vamos obter uma lista com os áudios usando um método que eu inventei agora.

```
FlacAudio[] audioFiles = FlacHelper.ReadFromDirectory("caminhoDoDiretorio");
```

Pronto, temos uma lista com os 8 arquivos de música.

Agora vamos converter eles:

```
List<Mp3Audio> mp3Files = new List<Mp3Audio>();

foreach (FlacAudio file in audioFiles)
{
   Mp3Audio mp3 = FlacHelper.ConvertToMp3(file);
   mp3Files.Add(mp3);
}

// Salvar os arquivos convertidos no diretório destino...
```

Aqui, neste iterador `foreach` apenas uma thread é usada para cada um dos 8 arquivos, então enquanto o primeiro está sendo convertido, os outros 7 estão impacientes aguardando. Mas olha só, você possuí um processador Intel Core I7 com 8 threads disponíveis, então para que esperar?

Vamos reescrever código para que todo esse poder de processamento seja usufruído:

```
List<Mp3Audio> mp3Files = new List<Mp3Audio>();

Parallel.ForEach(audioFiles, file =>
{
   Mp3Audio mp3 = FlacHelper.ConvertToMp3(file);
   mp3Files.Add(mp3);
});
```

Pronto, neste código o `foreach` do `Parallel` descobre e utiliza todos os threads disponíveis do seu processador para que a ação, que no caso é converter arquivos de áudio, seja executado paralelamente, então cada thread vai converter um arquivo ao mesmo tempo.

Considerando que levaria 1 minuto para cada arquivo, o `foreach` padrão levaria um total de 8 minutos, enquanto um `Parallel.ForEach` levaria 1 minuto considerando 8 arquivos no diretório e um processador com 8 threads.

O **`Parallel.For`** funciona exatamente como você imagina:

```
List<Mp3Audio> mp3Files = new List<Mp3Audio>();

Parallel.For(0, files.Length - 1,
index => { 
            Mp3Audio mp3 = FlacHelper.ConvertToMp3(audioFiles[index]);
            mp3Files.Add(mp3);
         }); // Index é o número da iteração atual, que neste caso parte de zero e é incrementada a cada iteração.
```

**Quando utilizar:**

Para operações que dependam de processamento (CPU-Bound) e que possam ser executadas de maneira paralela quando houver mais de uma ocorrência de item a ser processado, similarmente a nossa lista de músicas.

**Ressalva**:

Utilizar o `Parallel.ForEach` em operações/iterações simples que não utilizam muitos recursos não é garantia de ser mais rápido do que um `foreach` padrão. Na verdade o custo de alocar threads da maneira que o `Parallel` faz pode causar uma "overhead" que deixe seu código mais lento, então o "peso" da operação a ser executada dentro do `foreach` é o que vai ditar se compensa ou não a utilização da forma paralela.

Comment: O `Parallel` não é adequado para IO, para isto assincronismo é o ideal.

Comment: Agora eu vi que mudou para o conversor, se ele for intensivo em processamento fica ok.

Comment: Uma dúvida. Qual é a diferença de usar "Parallel.For..." e "mp3Files.AsParallel.Foreach...".  Vc pdr usar o parallel antes ou parallel depois.

Comment: @Leandro O método de extensão "AsParallel" funciona como um "wrapper" em volta do "IEnumerable". Ele faz parte do PLINQ (Parallel LINQ). Quando você chama "AsParallel" em um IEnumerable, ele faz com que o método de extensão LINQ chamado consequentemente seja paralelo. Por exemplo: "mp3Files.Sum(t => t.Size)" não é paralelo, agora "mp3Files.AsParallel().Sum(t => t.Size)" é paralelo e efetuará a soma de cada item paralelamente. Isso só funciona para métodos LINQ como "Sum", "Select", 'Max", etc. O "ForEach" não é um método LINQ, então ele não será paralelo. Seu equivalente PLINQ é o "ForAll".

Comment: Quanto a questão do "custo para alocação de threads", o Parallel não usa as threads do pool? Porque se for assim, acho que sempre que for possível utilizá-la estaremos tendo benefícios de desempenho.

Answer (score 9):

Alguns processamentos em coleções de dados ou algum algoritmo que seja feito como uma repetição, desde que não dependentes da sequência a ser executada, podem se beneficiar se forem feitos em paralelo aproveitando a capacidade atual dos processadores de possuírem vários unidades independentes de processamento, em geral isto se dá através de *threads*.

Entretanto fazer uso de *threads* nem sempre é simples, por isso foi criado um *framework* de processamento paralelo que abstrai isto para você, então em vez de execução um *loop* normal você cria uma função anônima (*lambda*) com o algoritmo a ser executado e transfere para o *framework* executar em paralelo da melhor forma possível, toda lógica interna e cuidados a serem tomados, como consolidar o resultado fica a cargo do *framework*.

Sequências que dependem do resultado anterior para continuar a execução não conseguem ser paralelizados. Somar os itens de uma coleção ou achar quais os primos funciona bem, mas uma progressão de qualquer forma, aritmética, Fibonacci, etc.) não dá certo.

O `ForEach` é usado para coleções de dados e o `For` é usado para processamentos repetidos em geral, o que não impede, mas não é o ideal, que seja usado em coleções de dados.

Veja também: ["foreach" do C# vs "ForEach()" do EF6](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211053/101)

Leitura obrigatória: [É sempre garantido que uma aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101). Não tente usar este mecanismo para fazer operações com arquivos ou que acessem recursos externos ao processador, ele foi feito para utilizar melhor o processador e não os dispositivos externos que se dão melhor com [assincronismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175304/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então o uso do Parellel nada mais é que uma forma de encapsular o que o faríamos através de vários threads ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Basicamente isto.

Answer (score 2):

Respondendo:

> O que são os loops.

São similares aos loops for e for each, porém otimizados para programação paralela de dados.

> Quando devemos usá-los.

É complicado definir um cenário ideal, mas sempre quando é necessário obter desempenho de execução com multiplas threads. O Parallel, é utilizado para poder fazer duas coisas ao mesmo tempo, utilizando varias threads.

> Existe diferença entre eles?

A mesma entre o for comum e o foreach comum.

Comment: Então não tem diferença entre um fazer um Loop For ou um Loop Parallel.For ?

Comment: A diferença entre eles é que um vai ser executado de forma sequencial, e outro de forma paralela. No segundo você tem que controlar as threads de execução tbm, pois um item a frente da sequencia pode terminar antes que um anterior. A não ser que vc necessite de um processamento muito, mas muito rapido, use o Parallel.