# O que são coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, corotina

O que me foi dado a perceber é que é uma nova forma de escrever código assíncrono, permitindo evitar o bloqueio da *thread*.

Isto leva-me a supor que são uma alternativa à classe `Thread` do Java (e/ou outras baseadas nela).

Assim, gostaria de saber:

- O que são e como funcionam.
- Vantagens e desvantagens em relação à abordagem baseada em *threads*.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

São rotinas **cooperativas**, ou seja, são rotinas (funções, métodos, procedimentos) que concordam em parar sua execução permitindo que outra rotina possa ser executada naquele momento esperando que essa rotina secundária devolva a execução para ela em algum momento, portanto uma coopera com a outra.

Isso permite a execução em partes. Um dos grandes benefícios é manter algum estado entre os momentos de execução, então sua principal função é facilitar a execução segmentada, possivelmente criando alguma abstração na execução.

O principal mecanismo em linguagens para alcançar isto é o [`yield`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44293/101). Também pode usar uma [máquina de estados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/208328/101) manualmente ou por biblioteca.

Então elas mantém o estado da rotina em algum lugar, incluindo aí em que instrução ela parou para poder continuar dali quando voltar.

A partir dessa estrutura é possível criar uma máquina de estados específica para permitir que a execução crie assincronicidade de execução que pode substituir *threads* que eram usadas para permitir a execução paralela e concorrente, mas era o mecanismo errado nestes casos.

Não é que *threads* não sejam úteis, elas são, mas apenas uma para cada processador, assim permite que várias execuções ocorram de forma efetivamente simultâneas. Mas a execução das operações diversas concorrentes não necessariamente simultâneas, não se beneficiam delas. Em cada processador só pode executar uma coisa de cada vez, mesmo que tenha a ilusão de estar executando várias. É mais vantajoso deixar as rotinas dizerem quando não precisam mais executar do que deixar o sistema operacional ficar trocando isso muitas vezes sem necessidade.

Então uma rotina executa sua parte e nos momentos que ela fará IO haverá entrega de execução para outra rotina. O IO será feito pelo sistema operacional ou pelo serviço que está sendo usado por conta dele, nada tem a ver com sua aplicação, então não tem porque sua aplicação ficar esperando sem fazer nada. Com a corrotina ela coopera dizendo que outra rotina pode ser executada nesse momento. Quando a parte de IO terminar volta para a rotina anterior terminando de executar com o resultado do IO em mãos.

Não tem tanta diferença assim, só que a suspensão de execução é determinada pela própria rotina e não pelo sistema operacional, por isso ela é chamada de cooperativa, o sistema operacional faz de forma **preemptiva**.

Algumas linguagens abstraem tudo isso, outras exigem que você cuide de todo o mecanismo de troca de execuções (a máquina de estado), o que na prática faz "ninguém" usar.

*Thread* é útil quando precisa criar linhas de processamento e a maior vantagem se dá quando se tem vários processadores disponíveis. Claro que a *thread*, que é um recurso do sistema operacional, pode ser usada como máquina de estados de execução, mas tem um custo mais alto. [Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101). Corrotinas neste contexto é mais útil quando tem entrada e saída ou quando precisa linhas de processamento que vão além dos processadores disponíveis.

Há muito desperdício no uso de *thread* porque tem o custo de gerenciamento do sistema operacional, tem a troca de contexto que é cara, tem a alta probabilidade de uma *thread* ser acionada e não ter nada para fazer. Corrotinas são bem leves, gerenciadas de forma simples pela própria aplicação e são acionadas conforme a necessidade. O "sob demanda" é o segredo aqui.

Claro que se a rotina que deve cooperar for mal escrita, pode ser que enrosque por muito tempo atrapalhando tudo. A preempção força a troca de execução da rotina de uma *thread* para outra, mesmo que a aplicação não ajude.

Houve uma revolução de performance em servidores HTTP, que o Node levou a fama sem ter o mérito, justamente por usar corrotinas no lugar de *threads*.

A **corrotina é ortogonal à *thread***, então uma não depende da outra, mas pode ser que uma corrotina seja colocada em *thread* separada, dependendo da necessidade.

Nos comentários o AP fala sobre escrever código sequencial que acaba sendo distribuído concorrentemente, e é isso mesmo, desde que a linguagem ou até mesmo a biblioteca ajude.

Por falta de um mecanismo melhor nos anos 90 disseminou-se o uso de *threads* para algo que não precisava delas, inclusive porque quase nenhum computador tinha mais que um processador.

Entenda melhor a [diferença entre paralelo e simultâneo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166032/101).

O [`await`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2793/101) do C# faz exatamente isto. [Kotlin tem mecanismo muito parecido](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#dispatchers-and-threads). Boa parte das implementações atuais usam algo parecido com C# por acharem que foi uma boa implementação. Curiosamente C# acha que a implementação de F# é melhor :)

Exemplo em Python:

[image: Corrotina]

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine).

Tem uma [resposta no SO com mais detalhes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23436125/221800).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Então, se não há *threads* envolvidas, como isso funciona?

Comment: @ramaral dei uma melhorada, não sei se é isto que quer saber. Nos *links* tem mais detalhes sobre o funcionamento.

Comment: A minha dúvida era se havia a criação de novas *threads* ou não. Por aquilo que eu entendi a ler [isto(2ª parágrafo)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html) pode haver, caso isso seja adequado. No fundo(se eu entendi bem), esta abordagem, permite que se escreva código sequencial, na coroutine, deixando a biblioteca escolher a melhor forma de o implementar assincronamente.

Comment: È uma das consequências de usar corotina.

Comment: Que me parece boa na maioria dos casos.

Comment: Sem dúvida, uso de *thread* a não ser pra divisão entre processadores foi um acidente de percurso.

Comment: @Maniero essa abordagem chamada **corotina** pode prevenir ou evitar o *race condition*?

Comment: @gato Pelo contrário, pode causar. Se a execução pode ser interrompida para outra parte executar e depois voltar, quem garante que o estado externo a esta rotina, e que é acessado por ela, continua o mesmo? Se ele pode ou não ser alterado, se essa alteração afeta o resultado final ou não é outra discussão, porque só há condição de corrida se a alteração afeta o resultado. Até melhorei uma resposta para tentar deixar claro isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/243893/101