# Path da pasta anterior

Tags: c#, path

Como eu posso obter o caminho da pasta anterior?
Por exemplo eu tenho este caminho : `C:/Pasta1/Pasta2`
E eu queria pegar o caminho da pasta 1 `C:/Pasta1`
Como eu posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Acredito que deseje o [`GetParent()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getparent?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_IO_Directory_GetParent_System_String_).

```
using static System.Console;
using System.IO;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() => WriteLine(Directory.GetParent("/Pasta1/Pasta2"));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/aXT0r3). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/geJlcN). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/GetParent.cs).

Só precisa tomar cuidado se terminar com uma barra porque ela fará com que o corrente seja nada, e o último listado seja o pai. Se pode ocorrer situação assim é melhor tratá-lo adequadamente.

Answer (score 6):

Segue exemplo de utilização do `GetParent()` da classe `System.IO.Directory`

```
var caminho1 = Directory.GetParent("C:\\Pasta1\\Pasta2");
//caminho1 = "C:\Pasta1"
```