# Além de estruturas como "for", "while", "goto" ou recursão, há alguma outra forma de repetir algo na programação?

Tags: loop, independente-de-linguagem

Na programação estruturada, temos estruturas como laços `for`, `while` e outros similares, além de estruturas `goto`, que nos permitem realizar *repetições*. Na programação funcional, a recursão é usada para atingir esse mesmo objetivo.

Assim, além de estruturas de repetição como `for`, `while`, `goto` e recursão, na programação há algum outro meio de se realizar *loops*? Se sim, qual?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Iteração

Na verdade os três primeiros que usou é a [**iteração**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185497/101). Se considerar tudo como uma coisa só, além da **recursão**, até onde eu conheço, só existem esses dois.

Existem outras formas de iterar que não são esses comandos, mas a pergunta indica saber disto. Algum paradigma pode até mesmo usar outra forma de chamar isso, mas ainda será uma iteração. Ou recursão. Dependendo da abstração existem outros comandos possíveis em algumas linguagens, mas é só sintaxe, não é um conceito novo.

E as iterações acabam virando um *branch*. Os outros comandos são abstrações (padrões de projeto). Até mesmo o `goto` acaba sendo uma abstração porque o *branch* simples costuma ter menos restrições.

E é bom deixar claro que o `goto` pode fazer repetições, mas nada garante que tenha sido usado assim.

## Recursão

Existe [recursão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/101) em formas diferentes do que conhece, por exemplo como ocorre com [*templates*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150181/101), ou até já disseram que pode ocorrer com *generics* (nunca comprovei, mas acredito que dê mesmo), então não é só função. Macros também podem ter algo assim. Mas é comum que essas recursões não aconteçam na execução, ela é resolvida em tempo de compilação.

Lembrando que é comum em algumas linguagens que [a recursão de função seja transformada em iteração quando compilado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184494/101). Aí no seu código terá a recursão, mas internamente só terá uma iteração.

Portanto o que você vê no seu código de repetição automática por recursão pode desaparecer do executável, seja por *unrolling* para a repetição manual ou transformação em iteração.

## Manual

Essas formas de repetição são mecanismos para automatizar uma repetição. É possível obviamente repetir manualmente, mas entendo que isso seria indesejado ao que está na pergunta.

Por exemplo a aplicação ficar proliferando por aí é uma forma manual, não é um mecanismo de repetição escrita em código.

## Abstrações dos conceitos anteriores

Claro que pode ser criativo se puder envolver outras abstrações (através de biblioteca e/ou código bastante complexo, um exemplo é a corotina, outro é GUI, todos terão um *event loop* iterativo mascarado), mas ainda usará um dos conceitos acima.

Se envolver recursos externos à aplicação também é possível algo ser repetido, mas no fundo haverá uma iteração ou recursão, ainda que não esteja no seu código ou aplicação. Poderíamos chamar de sinalização.

Vai considerar essas como formas diferentes de repetição? Que seja, mas elas são só abstrações em cima dos dois conceitos já estabelecidos.

Se puder envolver algo externo à linguagem existem formas infinitas de fazer e não caberia responder aqui, a lista sempre será incompleta.

Como a pergunta não envolve uma tecnologia específica entendo que ela se refere ao conceito matemático e o que ocorre no seu código e eu só consegui identificar esses dois.

## Condição

Além disso vou dizer que sem algum truque que esconda uma condição, como uma sinalização externa que interfira no fluxo por exemplo, não é possível ter repetição finita automática sem alguma forma de condição.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Alguns mecanismos diferentes dos citados:

- [Corotinas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241437/o-que-s%C3%A3o-coroutines).
- É possível também fazer com criação de subprocessos, onde um processo inicia uma cópia de si mesmo. Alguns vírus/worms de computador fazem isso. Uma ou outra vez eu vi sendo usado em um programa legítimo, mas é raro.
- Função que agenda a si mesma para executar novamente. Exemplo em javascript:

  ```js
  function teste() {
      alert("Hello");
      setTimeout(teste, 3000);
  }
  teste();
  ```
- Função que é executada periodicamente. Exemplo em javascript:

  ```js
  setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
  ```
- Muitos vírus/worms enviam a si mesmo para outros computadores através da internet, iniciando então uma nova execução de si mesmos em um outro *host* da rede. Isso também é uma forma de repetição.
- Uso de falhas de buffer overflow em C permite que alguns truques sejam possíveis ao escrever-se diretamente na memória que representa a pilha de execução ou o código sendo executado, e com isso é possível fazer com que:

  - Uma função `x` chama uma função `y`. Mas quando `y` retorna, ela vai retornar para um ponto de `x` diferente de onde `y` foi chamado.
  - Uma função `x` chame uma função `y`. Mas quando `y` retorna, ela vai retornar para o meio de uma função `z` completamente diferente de `x`.
  - Uma função que escreve uma cópia de si mesma em algum lugar da memória e chama essa nova função recém-criada.
  - Uma função que altera o seu próprio código a medida que está sendo executada.

  Enfim, essas maluquices eu só vi em quatro lugares diferentes: (a) vírus (que fazem isso para mascarar o seu propósito e dificultar a engenharia reversa); (b) exploits de falhas de segurança; (c) códigos de proteção contra pirataria e (d) [IOCCC](https://www.ioccc.org/).

Não é muito difícil reduzir o problema de definir o que é ou não de uma forma nova de repetição ao [problema da parada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276648/132). Isso implica que o número de formas de se definir estruturas que repetem é essencialmente infinito. Sempre haverá algum método mais novo e mais sofisticado de fazer isso, não importando quantos métodos anteriores já tenham sido inventados. Ocorre que a maioria dessas formas ou são coisas de nichos e situações bem específicas ou são coisas malucas demais para ter sentido de ser feito por meros mortais. De qualquer forma, a resposta para a pergunta "*na programação há algum outro meio de se realizar loops?*" é afirmativa.

Comment: Que é o que eu disse em "Claro que pode ser criativo se puder envolver outras abstrações ou recursos externos à aplicação, mas no fundo haverá uma iteração ou recursão, ainda que não esteja no seu código ou aplicação" e "Além disso vou dizer que sem algum truque que esconda uma condição, como uma sinalização externa que interfira no fluxo por exemplo, não é possível ter repetição finita automática sem alguma forma condição", não é um mecanismo do código. Não listei já que entendi que ele estava falando de mecanismos do código. Um agendador faz repetição.

Comment: O `setTimeout()` pede para o *runtime* junto com o sistema operacional fazer a repetição, não o código. E na prática ainda é uma recursão ou iteração mesmo que não esteja vendo (por isso eu nem sei qual dos dois foi usado) "Dependendo da abstração existem outros comandos possíveis em algumas linguagens, mas é só sintaxe, não é um conceito novo", que é o caso de uma corotina. Como não tem uma linguagem especificada, para listar todas abstrações teria  que ver todas as abstrações possíveis já criadas em uma linguagem ou biblioteca, e nem consideraria as que o programador poderia criar.

Comment: @Maniero Seria recursão se a função chamar a si mesma. Nesse caso, ela não chama a si mesma, ela apenas pede para que outra coisa a chame. Além disso, numa recursão, o resultado da chamada interna é disponibilizado para a externa, coisa que não ocorre num agendamento. A recursão também tipicamente exibe o empilhamento de chamadas de uma mesma função na pilha de execução, coisa que não ocorre no agendamento. Logo, isso não é recursão, nem `for`, nem `while` e nem `goto`. É verdade que haverá um `while` em algum lugar do sistema operacional ou runtime, mas ele não está sendo usado diretamente.

Comment: @Maniero E não é muito difícil reduzir o problema de definir o que é ou não de uma forma nova de repetição ao problema da parada. Isso implica que o número de formas de se definir estruturas que repetem é essencialmente infinito. Sempre haverá algum método mais novo e mais sofisticado de fazer isso, não importando quantos métodos anteriores já tenham sido inventados.

Comment: Não precisa chamar a si mesma para ser recursão, existe recursão triangulada. Mas isso não importa, o fato é que se não tiver uma recursão haverá uma iteração. Justamente para não entrar no infinito da resposta que é melhor reduzir aos conceitos abstratos, porque se a pergunta queria uma lista de todos mecanismos abstratos possíveis de criar, ela seria muito ampla, talvez a mais ampla já criada no site.

Comment: @Maniero A pergunta está perguntando apenas que "na programação há algum outro meio de se realizar loops?" - E certamente que há. Ocorre que a maioria dessas formas ou são coisas de nichos e situações bem específicas ou são coisas malucas demais para ter sentido de ser feito por meros mortais. Mas isso não faz a resposta tornar-se negativa.