# O que são Fibers no PHP?

Tags: php

Recentemente, o PHP 8.1 introduziu algo novo: *fibers* (ou fibras em Português), que segundo a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.fibers.php):

> Fibers represent full-stack, interruptible functions. Fibers may be suspended from anywhere in the call-stack, pausing execution within the fiber until the fiber is resumed at a later time.
>
> *Traduzido: Fibras representam funções autênticas e interruptíveis. Fibras podem ser suspensas a partir de qualquer lugar na pilha de chamadas, pausando a execução dentro da fibra até que ela seja retomada em um momento posterior.*

Mas não entendi muito bem o seu propósito.

O que são *fibers* e quando devo usar isso?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241437/o-que-s%c3%a3o-coroutines/241768#241768

Comment: são a forma do PHP lidar com o paralelismo através de threads virtuais, ou até msm green threads

Answer (score 2):

Talvez o exemplo da documentação seja mais eloquente do que a própria documentação:

```
<?php
$fiber = new Fiber(function (): void {
   $value = Fiber::suspend('fiber');
   echo "Value used to resume fiber: ", $value;
});

$value = $fiber->start();

echo "Value from fiber suspending: ", $value;

$fiber->resume('test');
?>
```

O exemplo acima irá imprimir:

> Value from fiber suspending: fiber Value used to resume fiber: test

É um objeto que encapsula uma função e permite que ela seja interrompida e retomada quando desejado pelo código que a chamou (nesse sentido, lembra as generator functions).

Uma das vantagens, pela própria documentação, é que a ordem pra suspender a função (a instrução `suspend()`) e a respectiva retomada pode estar tanto na própria função quanto em funções aninhadas chamadas pela Fiber ou pela chamadora.

Veja o que acontece no exemplo acima: você atribuiu uma função cuja execução precisa ser interrompida á variável de objeto `$fiber`. Depois, em algum momento do seu código, você chama a tal função (nesse caso, o método `$fiber->start()`). A função começa a rodar, chega na `suspend()` e devolve um valor nesse momento. A função chamadora continua, utilizando esse valor parcial  como quiser (é por isso que a frase de baixo aparece primeiro, junto com o valor parcial). Depois, o código chamador manda continuar a execução da função de onde havia parado (é por isso que a frase que está dentro da função só aparece depois). Como não há novas suspensões, a Fiber roda até o final.

Num nível mais simples, você pode usar uma generator para isso, mas a função generator não vai permitir sem uma certa gambiarra retomar a execução da função pausada numa estrutura em que você aninhou funções (por exemplo). As generators  têm métodos mais voltados para geração de valores através de alguma iteração.

Embora eu nunca tenha usado as Fibers, imagino uma grande utilidade para separação de "concerns" e organização do código: digamos que você tem uma ação assíncrona (um pagamento ou qualquer outra coisa que dependa de uma consulta num banco de dados ou requisição web). A Fiber vai te dar uma forma mais simples de pausar a função que está no seu módulo/objeto responsável pela operação comercial para esperar o pagamento e continuar a execução dela a partir de outro módulo/objeto, responsável pelo pagamento, sendo que os dois módulos/objetos não conhecem um ao outro: só usam a interface da Fiber (em tempo: nesse exemplo a operação terminou ficando síncrona, mas é só um exemplo possível, pois como eu disse, nunca usei).

Comment: Não posso eleger sua resposta como recompensável porque ela não atendeu nenhum critério antes solicitado. Talvez até tenha tentado atender, mas ficou com uma qualidade relativamente baixa e pouco didática. Além disso, ela ficou com um gostinho de "opinativa" quando cita bastantes cenários específicos de uso pessoal.

Comment: Além disso, o exemplo da documentação não é _"eloquente"_ o suficiente, pois a documentação que citei na pergunta é a mesma que vinculastes em tua resposta.