# Em qual contexto o padrão de máquina de estado é indicado?

Tags: design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, arquitetura-de-software

Eu andei pesquisando algumas implementações de máquina de estado e gostaria de saber em qual situação a maquina de estado se encaixa e qual o beneficio de usá-la?

Comment: Relacionado: [O que é uma máquina de estado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208328/o-que-%c3%a9-uma-m%c3%a1quina-de-estado)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Introdução

Programar é achar uma solução automatizada para um problema. Certos tipos de problemas em programação, que envolvem entidades que transitam a cada momento para um estado diferente dentro de um conjunto finito de estados possíveis, podem ser modelados (representados) na forma de uma máquina de estado **finita**, que é basicamente um certo tipo de diagrama que irei descrever. Essa representação em princípio não chega a entrar no mérito de como esse problema vai ser solucionado no código, mas facilita essa transição, sugerindo um algoritmo e eventualmente algumas abstrações.

A definição de máquina de estado finita (FSM) pode ser mais rigorosa que isso, mas irei tentar explicar de uma maneira mais visual.

Também não estou entrando no mérito do outro tipo de máquina de estado, que são as máquinas de estado **in**finitas. Como se vê aqui no SOpt, é comum que ao se falar em máquina de estado em programação esteja subentendendo as finitas.

Pois bem. Uma vez modelado o problema ou cenário em questão, a forma de implementação irá depender essencialmente do tipo de aplicação que você está desenvolvendo, do(s) paradigma(s) de programação adotados (em outras palavras, da linguagem) e, claro, do problema em si.

## O que é e onde se aplica

É um conceito bem simples na verdade, em geral faz sentido modelar o problema como uma máquina de estado finita quando você tiver uma entidade (uma "coisa" qualquer) que pode a cada momento estar em um determinado estado dentro de um conjunto de diversos estados possíveis, como no caso de uma lâmpada (ligada ou desligada), um semáforo (vermelho, verde, amarelo, e não esqueçam também do estado de "defeito") ou outras coisas assim (na verdade acho que três ou mais estados é mais comum, se forem só dois a gente tende a se virar com booleanos para resolver o problema), e existe um critério para se passar de um estado para outro que respeita uma certa lógica e também ações que devem acontecer quando se chega a um estado "X", bem como a lógica para escolher qual vai ser o próximo estado.

Qualquer situação envolvendo algum tipo de fluxo ou etapas (sejam elas obrigatórias ou opcionais), onde exista uma etapa de partida e uma de chegada ou então as transições de uma para outra entre em ciclo, pode caber aplicar a ideia de máquina de estados finita, que não passa de uma brincadeira de ligue-os-pontos com bolinhas e setas (as bolinhas são os tais estados possíveis, e as setas são as transições de um para outro, normalmente com o critério para a transição ocorrer anotado perto de cada seta).

Se quiser visualizar como é, tem uma figura mais abaixo.

## Benefícios

Pode ser interessante modelar a solução assim porque é isso que o problema representa, então essa seria a vantagem, a modelagem da solução ficar mais próxima à representação do problema e portanto mais fácil de implementar, estender e dar manutenção. O diagrama subentende um algoritmo que pode ser implementado de maneira clara.

Outro possível benefício é aproveitar as abstrações que ela sugere. Em orientação a objetos por exemplo, se você implementar o conceito de "estado" como um objeto, pode achar interessante no seu código manter a escolha do critério de transição vinculada ao objeto que representa aquele estado. Também pode tirar proveito de herança e polimorfismo para acrescentar novos estados que não estavam previstos inicialmente e invocar seus métodos de maneira a obedecer o princípio do Aberto/Fechado (aberto para extensão, fechado para modificação).

## Formas de implementar

A implementação em si pode ser feita de várias maneiras, vai depender do problema e do tipo de aplicação que você está desenvolvendo.

Se for para funcionar em uma *thread* (linha de execução) só, pode ser feito por exemplo com um simples `switch(estadoAtual)` contido em um *loop*, para checar o estado atual e cada `case` executar determinadas ações quando se chega naquele estado, seguido da lógica de mudar de um estado para outro, que irá variar conforme a situação.

Também podem ser `if`s:

[image: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RosjDcNoqmk/maxresdefault.jpg]
*(Exemplo bem simples de visualizar que peguei desavergonhadamente da Internet)*

Ou também usando-se certos padrões de projeto, se não me engano o padrão ***State*** é um que pode ser aplicado neste cenário. Outro possível conforme o caso é o ***Builder***, que consiste em ir construindo um objeto em passos graduais.

## Exemplos de uso

Máquinas de estado fazem sentido em vários cenários, por exemplo num contexto de estabelecer ou autenticar uma conexão de rede em que é feito um *handshake* ("aperto de mão" entre as partes que envolve vários passos) e implica em vários estados intermediários que cada lado pode assumir (como ocorre no nível da implementação do protocolo TCP, ou no dos protocolos SSL/TLS, ou mesmo no nível da aplicação final conforme o protocolo de autenticação que se está implementando), na verdade não só o *handshake* mas o ciclo de  vida todo da conexão.

Ou num contexto de executar uma sequência de passos qualquer e ir assumindo estados intermediários (um possível exemplo seria um carrinho de compras ou processo de compra num site de *e-commerce* ou de *delivery*, que do lado do servidor seriam bons candidatos para um *Builder*).

Só lembrando que uma máquina de estados não é necessariamente sequencial, ela pode ser cíclica ou conter transições de um estado para outro que formam ciclos ou mesmo de um estado para ele mesmo, para não ficar com a ideia errada por conta desses exemplos que eu citei por último que foram mais sequenciais.

Outros dois casos para máquina de estados são o ciclo de vida de uma "tarefa" em um sistema operacional moderno (por exemplo: criado, pronto p/ executar, em execução, bloqueado, terminado, etc.) e as implementações de *loops* em thread única que disponibilizam sem abstrair muito os recursos de I/O não-bloqueante feita pelo sistema operacional com o intuito de obter maior escalabilidade em aplicações que executam muita I/O, por exemplo através da biblioteca de NIO do Java que é base para frameworks de comunicação em rede escaláveis como o Netty e o Apache MINA, bem como versões de Tomcat mais recentes, ou como suponho que é feito no Node.js para atender um grande volume de requisições da Web a partir de uma thread só.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Piovezan, deu para esclarecer o assunto.

Comment: " uma máquina de estados não é necessariamente sequencial, ela pode ser cíclica e também ter loops internos" @Piovezan  Imagino que tenha usado isso para ilustrar sua explicação apenas, mas uma máquina de estados não tem ciclos, sequência ou algum tipo de loop interno ou externo. Tem apenas ao menos 1 estado e talvez uma regra de transição para algum outro estado. Uma máquina finita de estados FSA pode ter dois estados por exemplo: ligada e desligada. e oscilar entre os dois. Isso não é um loop. Do ponto de vista de design cada estado é autosuficiente.

Comment: @arfneto Chamei de loops nesse caso às eventuais sequências de transições cíclicas, não os loops no código da implementação, se foi a isso que você se referiu. Ciclos entre estados ou de um estado para ele mesmo acredito que tem sim: https://blog.markshead.com/869/state-machines-computer-science/ De qualquer forma não estou sendo muito rigoroso na conceituação e posso ter falado algo errado.

Comment: @piovesan Entendo a idéia. Acho que o autor que mencionou também quis simplificar. Li o artigo. Acho que a idéia de loop não se aplica a uma FSM --- e acho que, até como o tal Mark chega a acenar, o que importa mesmo é uma maquina de estados determinística. E nesse caso cada estado tem uma regra objetiva de sucessão, podendo ser o único estado, afinal 1 é finito. E se pode implementar completamente um estado apenas mantendo a máquina e o contexto. Esse é o lance desse design pattern. Em um protocolo de comunicação por exemplo um grupo pode implementar até um certo estado apenas

Comment: @Piovezan e outro grupo seguir adiante depois da sessão autenticada. Esse é o valor dessa coisa: poder programar algun estados e seguir adiante. Talvez a gente devesse ter um exemplo. Vou ver se tenho algo disponível aqui

Comment: @arfneto Se quiser acrescentar, sugiro fazê-lo na forma de uma outra resposta. A minha está bem informal e acho que ficou até meio grandinha. Acho que o que estou definindo é uma FSM mesmo.

Comment: @Piovesan tem razão. Eu escrevi um exemplo para alguém outro dia e deve servir. Vou ver onde está. Abraço

Answer (score 2):

Resposta didática para entender o que é e por quê é importante.

Você observará isso no mundo para aplicar depois em software ou projeto de circuitos.

Porta > (tem dois estados Aberta ou Fechada) - Considerando que ela está devidamente "instalada" heheheh.

Pense agora num Interruptor (Ligado / Desligado) que ATUA no estado de outro objeto chamado Lâmpada. (fica transitando entre esses dois estados eternamente) - claro para simplificar não considerei o estado dela: Queimada.

Agora, trazendo para os dias atuais, pense num sensor de temperatura conectado a uma placa de Arduino: (desligado) (ligado) (incomunicável) - estados possíveis. Exemplo: quando o sensor está incomunicável, não teve alguma resposta ao tentar se obter a temperatura, tem que tomar alguma decisão: enviar o email para alguém trocar aquele sensor, avisar, registrar num log de sistema, enfim (por si só O ESTADO DELE, pode interferir no comportamento TODO do sistema). Por isso que definir o estado de objetos é tão importante.

Diagramas de máquinas de estado da UML servem para vc poder mapear todos os estados possíveis de um determinado objeto (seja objeto do mundo real ou de software).

A parte interessante é que você pode observar a aplicação de diagramas de máquinas de estado em projetos de circuitos / IoT. Exemplo: Se o estado do sensor de temperatura é "defeito", toma uma decisão específica ou modifica o estado de outro objeto que faz parte do sistema como um todo.

A importância disso é não "esquecer" de todas as possibilidades e estados possíveis e acabar deixando alguma situação de projeto passar.

Imagine agora um sistema de e-commerce qualquer. Nele certamente existe o objeto PEDIDO.

O pedido pode transitar entre os diversos estados: FATURADO (o cliente acabou de fazer e pagar - um novo pedido com a nota fiscal já gerada) - EM SEPARAÇÃO (no setor de logística para poder ser despachado) - A CAMINHO (sendo transportado) - ENTREGUE / EXTRAVIADO ou Roubado pelos CORREIOS hahahahahahhahaha (pessoal é brincadeira - apenas para não esquecer do exemplo)...

Importante você compreender: Cada vez que um determinado objeto muda de estado, pode interferir no comportamento sistêmico como um todo ou de outros objetos e partes de um sistema e, respondendo sua pergunta: É importante projetar ou pelo menos levantar todos os estados possíveis dos objetos importantes do sistema para que você não esqueça de detalhes importantes ou de situações não previstas de projeto O QUANTO ANTES.

Quer ver um exercício legal? Estado de uma câmera de vigilância WiFi. Pense na máquina de estados dela (não é ligada/desligada não ... é interessante).

Comment: Bacana, gostei das analogias :)