# Alternativa à herança múltipla

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, herança, interface

Não é possível herdar de mais de uma classe em C#, então venho aqui em busca de sugestões para meu problema.

Estou construindo um pequeno jogo usando Unity. No Unity os objetos do jogo (`GameObject`) herdam de uma superclasse chamada `MonoBehaviour`, como é o caso da minha classe `Player`, e como é o caso da minha classe `Enemy`.

Tanto `Player` como `Enemy` tem a possibilidade de escolher um alvo na tela e executar `Attack()`. Porém, no caso do `player`, seu alvo pode ser tanto um `Enemy` quanto outro `Player`. Na inocência rapidamente criei uma classe `Entidade`, coloquei nela um método `RecebeAtaque(Attack a)`, e fiz `Player` e `Enemy`herdarem de `Entidade`. Depois disso, o fiz o método `Attack` receber um parâmetro `Entidade`.

Porém, `Player` e `Enemy` já herdam de `Monobehaviour`, assim, isso não foi possível. Eu preciso que eles herdem de `MonoBehaviour`, pois essa super classe me disponibiliza maneiras de manipular o `GameObject` na cena do jogo.

Como eu poderia implementar isso?

Comment: Faça `Entidade` herdar de `MonoBehavior`.

Comment: Por incrível que pareça, era isso mesmo que eu queria. Testei aqui a implementação e funcionou exatamente como eu esperava. Muito obrigado, era uma coisa tão simples, e eu não consegui perceber. Caso queira postar uma resposta, eu marco como aceita :)

Comment: Enquanto não podemos ter herança múltipla, temos a utilização de interfaces para, por exemplo, adicionar comportamentos a um objeto. No caso do Unity, a class `MonoBehavior` serve exatamente para isso. Você pode compor um objeto complexo com vários `MonoBehavior`, ou seja, você vai adicionando comportamentos. Na verdade, eu procuro evitar classes gigantescas com muitas responsabilidades, eu sugiro tentar quebrar em classes menores, respeitando o SOLID. No caso, você já conseguiu resolver o problema, só quis dar mais detalhes ;) boa sorte!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Herança múltipla é problemática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42970/101) e raramente é necessária de fato. [Como uma coisa pode ser duas coisas ao mesmo tempo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101). Além disso o ganho de herança mesmo é bem pequeno em quase todos cenários, principalmente se considerar que a [composição deve ser preferida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/101).

Em geral só queremos adicionar comportamento, isto pode ser feito com [`interface`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/101), especialmente quando é possível ter código na interface o que dá em [C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127279/101), [Java 8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90168/101) e [C# 8](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/288) ou linguagens que possuem *traits*.

Quando a intenção é usar realmente mais de uma classe em quase todas as situações é possível fazer isso pela hierarquia, ou seja, uma classe herda da outra e esta fica disponível com os membros das duas para outras classes herdarem. Tudo é o que questão de entender o que a classe significa, qual seu papel, o que ela é no projeto.

Nesse exemplo parece que a solução é `Entidade` herdar de `MonoBehavior`.

## Alternativa

Mas eu não sei o que essas classes fazem. Não gosto da maneira como esses *engines* de jogos são arquitetadas. [Um `Enemy` é um `MonoBehavior`? Não, né?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35317/101) É algo esquisito. Então [não deveria ter uma herança aí](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173198/101). Ou deveria fazem uma composição para que `Enemy` tenha o `MonoBehavior` ou isto deveria ser só uma interface para adicionar comportamento na classe deseja.

E `Entidade` é o que? Até me parece que um `Enemy` pode ser uma  `Entidade`, mas como não vi a implementação dela, não sei. Pode ser que ela não tenha função alguma ou não adicione nada no objeto, aí uma [interface é mais que adequada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136404/101), ainda mais se for só um [*marker*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76511/101), que pode ser o caso.