# O que é herança de tipo e estado?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, terminologia, herança, interface

Recentemente em um simulado de Java, me deparei com uma pergunta relacionada a classificação de herança, a qual nunca tinha visto antes.

Aproveitando a oportunidade, vou separar em tópicos, para que a resposta seja mais clara:

- O que é **herança de tipo**?
- O que é **herança de estado**?
- Java implementa **herança múltipla de tipo** e ou **herança múltipla de estado**?

Comment: Tem certeza que o termo é este? Tem algum contexto? Nunca vi "herança de estado" e mesmo "herança de tipo" em geral não é um bom termo.

Comment: Pois é. No meio de um simulado caiu algo que nunca vi durante o estudo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Herança de tipo

Herança de tipo é capacidade de uma classe herdar uma *interface* (*interface* - nesse contexto - não significa necessariamente algo que faz uso da *keyword* `interface`, mas sim tudo aquilo que é tornado público pela classe") e, assim, ser referenciada por esse outro tipo. Exemplo:

**Classe abstrata Animal**:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    
    protected String especie;
    
    public abstract boolean nascer();
    
    public abstract boolean morrer();
}
```

**Interface Movel**:

```
public interface Movel {
    
    public void andar();
}
```

**Classe Pessoa**:

```
public class Pessoa extends Animal implements Movel {

    @Override
    public boolean nascer() {
        //alguma lógica aqui
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean morrer() {
        //alguma lógica aqui
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void andar() {
        //alguma lógica aqui
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima, podemos referenciar a classe `Animal` através de vários tipos:

```
//Como Pessoa
Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
//Como Animal
Animal animal = pessoa;
//Como Movel
Movel movel = pessoa;
//Como Object
Object objeto = pessoa;
```

Como Java permite que uma classe implemente múltiplas interfaces, podemos afirmar que **ela suporta herança múltipla de tipo**.

### Herança de Estado

Herança de estado é a capacidade de herdar o estado de outras classes através de seus atributos. No exemplo acima, podemos ver um exemplo disso onde `Pessoa` herda o atributo `especie` da classe abstrata `Animal` através de uma herança simples.

Herança múltipla de estado seria a capacidade de herdar diretamente o estado de múltiplas classes. Esse tipo de herança possui alguns problemas como: "O que fazer quando as classes possuírem métodos, construtores ou atributos com o mesmo nome? Quem tem precedência?". Java **não suporta herança múltipla de estado** para evitar problemas decorrentes dessa abordagem.

### Herança múltipla de implementação

Além dos tipos de herança perguntados, existe um outro suportado pela linguagem Java, a herança múltipla de implementação através dos *default methods* presentes na linguagem desde o Java 8. Esse tipo herança gera um problema semelhante ao de heranças múltiplas de estado, já que diferentes interfaces podem ter implementado métodos com a mesma assinatura.

Quando uma situação como essa ocorre em Java, a classe que implementa essas *interfaces* é obrigada a implementar o método para acabar com a ambiguidade.

[Referência](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/multipleinheritance.html).

Answer (score 3):

Os termos são estranhos, ainda mais usados juntos.

Se estivesse falando de herdar o estado (atributos) e/ou o comportamento (métodos) eu até entenderia. E  Java faz ambos, acho que é até óbvio.

Se falar de [subclasse e subtipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152266/101) (eu acho que a resposta lá tá caprichada :P), eles são conceitos relacionados e acabam formando a herança como conhecemos. E sim, Java tem ambos, até  porque a herança dessas linguagens pressupões ambas.

Talvez sejam só termos muito ruins para dizer que há suporte para herança de uma classe e herança de uma interface já que normalmente classe tem estado e interface não tem, na verdade nem comportamento ([exceto Java 8 que mudou a semântica da interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90168/101)), então sobra o tipo para ele "herdar".

Comment: Isso, estado tem a ver com classe mesmo. Depois de mais pesquisas achei este link da Oracle que menciona "state inheritance": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/multipleinheritance.html