# Se uma classe A é uma implementação de uma interface X, as subclasses de A também serão?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança, interface

Com a interface `Posicionavel`:

```java
package projeto;

public interface Posicionavel
{
  public boolean mesmaPosicao(Posicionavel p);
  public boolean mesmaPosicao(int[] x);
  public int[] posicoes();
}
```

E a classe `Celula`:

```java
package projeto;
public abstract class Celula implements Posicionavel
{
    protected String cor;
    protected int x, y;

    public Celula(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int[] posicoes()
    {
      return new int[]{x, y};
    }

    public boolean mesmaPosicao(Posicionavel p)
    {
      return posicoes().equals(p.posicoes());
    }

    public boolean mesmaPosicao(int[] x)
    {
      return posicoes().equals(x);
    }  
}
```

A classe abaixo será também uma implementação de `Posicionavel`?

```java
package projeto;

public class CelulaBoca extends Celula 
{ 
    public CelulaBoca(int x, int y) 
    {
        super(x, y);
        this.cor = Cores.VERMELHO;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim e poderá comprovar criando uma variável de referência Posicionavel que, sem problema algum, conterá a instância de uma classe que a implemente diretamente(Celula), ou, indiretamente(CelulaBoca).

Caso declare a linha abaixo, compilará e rodará sem problemas:

```java
int qualquerValorDeX = 1;
int qualquerValorDeY = 2;
Posicionavel posicionavel = new CelulaBoca(qualquerValorDeX, qualquerValorDeY);
```

Isso permite, apenas, acesso aos métodos **visíveis** em **Interface Posicionavel**.
Digo visível, pois poderia haver métodos privados nesta interface(sim, você pode) e todas as implementações de Posicionavel(Celula, CelulaBoca, etc) herdarão este comportamento, **porém** não terão visibilidade **direta** para acessá-los(o que não acontece com modificador de acesso public, por exemplo).
Isso independe se na outra ponta do operador **=** eu estou fazendo referência à  uma instância que implemente Posicionavel(Celula, CelulaBoca, etc), que tenha N novos métodos e com a maior visibilidade possível que é o public devido a variável de referência ser do tipo **Posicionavel**:

```java
posicionavel.mesmaPosicao(new int[1]);
posicionavel.mesmaPosicao(new CelulaBoca(qualquerValorDeX, qualquerValorDeY));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(posicionavel.posicoes()));
```

*Ah, mais uma coisa...* caso Posicionavel tenha algum método estático(sim, você pode) e public, qualquer implementação(Celula, CelulaBoca, etc) não herdarão estes métodos pois métodos estáticos **nunca** são herdados através de herança. Isso também serve para atributos estáticos, **nunca** são herdados pois o que é estático pertence apenas a **classe**.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, será, a herança faz a nova classe ter todas as características da classe mãe, seus campos, seus métodos, e seus tipos explicitamente declarados. Uma classe filha pode ter coisas a mais que mãe, mas nunca menos, é uma questão de cumprimento de contrato.

Este tipo de dúvida surge porque ainda não entende para que serve a herança e está decorando como usa o mecanismo. Isto nunca dá certo e cria a ilusão de que está programando orientado a objeto porque entende os mecanismos. Quando você entende para que serve a herança esse tipo de coisa se torna natural. [Pode começar por aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/296594/101), mas não pare aí. Também pode ser útil: [Classes que implementam interfaces são consideradas subclasses?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152266/101) e [O que é herança de tipo e estado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190140/101), e ainda [Princípio de substituição de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101).

Comment: Ela herda todos os atributos mesmo se houver algum que seja privado? Pois caso não herde, a subclasse pode sim ter "coisas a menos"...

Comment: Sim, herda tudo, o `private` apenas diz que a classe filha não pode acessar o campo (e não atributo que é termo errado que aprendeu), mas ele está lá, não tem como não estar. Parece que não leu os *links* que eu passei. Quase todo mundo entende herança errado e aí acaba usando errado.