# Dúvidas sobre Classes Abstratas e Interface (java)

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, interface, classes-abstratas

Antes de expor minha dúvida é válido deixar claro que de certa forma entendo a diferença entre as duas.

Sei que uma **classe abstrata** pode ter métodos implementados, atributos, construtores, e precisa de no mínimo um método abstrato. Já uma **interface** só pode conter a assinatura dos métodos. Porém, minha dúvida vai um pouco mais a fundo..

Não sei exatamente quando usar uma ou outra *(**exemplo:** Supondo que meu intuito é obrigar que minhas subclasses implementem certos métodos... uma classe abstrata tendo esses métodos como abstratos já não resolveria esse problema? Então por que eu usaria interfaces?).*

Aquele velho exemplo da classe abstrata **"Animal"** e suas subclasses: cachorro, gato, cavalo, etc.. Já vi Animal sendo usado de exemplo como interface e classe abstrata, nesse tipo de caso qual seria o mais adequado e por quê?

Comment: Relevante: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90168/101. Também pode dar mais detalhes: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87423/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107524/101