# Qual é a finalidade do default quando usado na assinatura de um método?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, característica-linguagem, interface, java-8

Dentro da interface `List<E>` do Java existe o método `replaceAll()` cuja finalidade é substituir todas as ocorrências de um valor especificado de uma lista.

Entretanto, em sua assinatura ele usa o comando `default`, isso me deixou confuso, é a primeira vez que vejo o `default` sendo usado na assinatura de um método, veja sua assinatura completa:

```
default void replaceAll(UnaryOperator<E> operator)
```

Qual é a finalidade do `default` quando ele é usado na assinatura de um método como no exemplo acima?

Comment: java8 ne? O default foi introduzido nessa versão para permitir que um método seja implementado na propria interface, sem que isso quebre a compatibilidade com todos os métodos que ela implementam. Você pode declarar um método default, mas ele não será imposto a ser implementado nas classes que já herdam a interface.

Comment: Relacionado:[Interface Java 8](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90176/28595)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A finalidade de um método `default` é prover uma implementação padrão para um método de interface no caso das classes que implementam a interface não implementarem o método.

Lembre que uma interface em Java é como um contrato. As classes (exceto a abstratas) que implementam a interface devem implementar todos os métodos da interface como uma obrigação de contrato, caso contrário elas não compilam.

Em teoria, não existe motivo para implementar um método numa interface, mas existem algumas razões práticas, dentre as quais se destacam:

## Incluir funcionalidades sem quebrar o código existente

Este é o caso do exemplo citado na pergunta, da interface `List`.

Antes dos métodos `default`, caso você quisesse adicionar um método comum numa interface você potencialmente quebraria o contrato e todas as classes que implementam ela precisariam ser modificadas.

No caso de `List`, considere que é uma das APIs mais usadas e diversas bibliotecas e sistemas possuem implementações próprias delas. Isso seria um impeditivo para migrar para a nova versão do Java até que todas as dependências e componentes fossem também atualizadas.

O principal objetivo dos métodos `default` é possibilitar uma evolução de APIs de forma transparente, sem trancos, pois um código "antigo" pode usar uma API mais nova sem precisar ser atualizado.

Isso é vantajoso principalmente quando o novo método agrega alguma funcionalidade, mas não é estritamente necessário para o funcionamento do modo "antigo".

Claro que isso não resolve o problema quando ocorre mudança no funcionamento de uma API, pois nesse caso os métodos existentes precisariam ser modificados e métodos `default` não são recomendados.

Num exemplo simples, imagine uma interface de um DAO assim:

```
public interface ClienteDao {
    void incluir(Cliente c);
}
```

Agora, imagine que esse DAO possui várias implementações por diversos módulos de um grande sistema. Equipes diferentes são responsáveis pelos diferentes módulos que, por sua vez, são colocados em produção em tempos diferentes.

Na versão 2.0 do sistema, você adicionar um novo método na interface, mas não pode esperar que todos os outros módulos sejam atualizados. Você poderia fazer assim:

```
public interface ClienteDao {
    void incluir(Cliente c);
    default void incluir(List<Cliente> clientes) {
        for (Cliente c : clientes) incluir(c);
    }
}
```

Pronto, agora a API do sistema está atualizada e tudo continua funcionando.

Enquanto as demais equipes não implementam o método novo, a versão padrão serve bem aos propósitos. Provavelmente não é a coisa mais otimizada do mundo, mas funciona.

Para um DAO em memória, provavelmente a implementação padrão é suficiente. Quando uma equipe que implementa o DAO para um determinado banco de dados for atualizar o módulo dela, eles podem implementar uma versão otimizada para incluir os clientes em batch.

## Flexibilidade no reuso de código

Reuso de código via herança não costuma ser uma boa prática, mas a realidade é que ter métodos em interfaces possibilita um tipo especial de herança múltipla ou mesmo pode ser considerado um tipo de [*trait*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_(computer_programming)).

No Java 6 você podia reusar métodos de outras classes usando `import static` para acessar métodos estáticos como se eles fizessem parte da classe. Mas com os métodos `default` do Java 8 você pode implementar uma interface para trazer um conjunto de métodos para sua classe.

A vantagem disso sobre o `import static` é que os métodos fazem parte da API da classe e ela pode ser usada polimorficamente.

A vantagem sobre delegar para outras classes é que o código fica mais limpo.

A vantagem sobre herança é que você pode "herdar" os métodos de várias interfaces.

Aliás, a API toda do Java seria diferente se métodos `default` existissem há mais tempo.

Um exemplo simples poderia ser um DAO genérico mais flexível, geralmente implementado usando uma classe abstrata. Se você tem alguma experiência com sistemas sabe que sempre existe exceções e nem todos os DAOs precisam ter todos os métodos. Isso ocorre, por exemplo, em entidades que são somente leitura.

Exemplo:

```
public interface GenericDao<T> {
    default Connection getConnection() {
        return DbUtils.getConnection();
    }
}

public interface ReadOnlyDao<T> extends GenericDao<T> {
    T instanciar(ResultSet rs); //específico para cada entidade
    default T recuperar(int id) {
        Connetion c = getConnetion();
        ... executa SQL usando alguma mágica ...
        return instanciar(rs);
    }
    default List<T> listarTodos() {
        ...
    }
}

public interface WriteOnlyDao<T> extends GenericDao<T> {
    void set(PreparedStatement st, T entidade); //coloca os parâmetros da entidade na query
    default void incluir(T entidade) {
        Connetion c = getConnetion();
        ... executa SQL usando alguma mágica ...        
    }
}

public interface DaoCompleto extends ReadOnlyDao, WriteOnlyDao {}
```

Com essas implementações, basta implementar as interfaces conforme a necessidade:

```
public class FeriadosDao implements ReadOnlyDao { ... }
public class LogAcessoDao implements WriteOnlyDao { ... }
public class ClienteDao implements DaoCompleto { ... }
```

E pronto, podemos incorporar funcionalidades de forma granular, conforme a necessidade.

Comment: Herança múltipla resolveria este problema, né?

Comment: @jbueno Sim, de uma forma um pouco mais complicada.

Comment: Entendi. Muito boa resposta, realmente.

Answer (score 8):

Java 8 permite ter os chamados *default methods*. São métodos cuja implementação já pode estar disponível na interface (o que não podia ocorrer antes). Assim todas as classes que implementarem esta interface já ganham uma implementação do método. Claro que a classe pode sobrepor esta implementação se quiser.

A palavra-chave está sendo usada apenas para indicar ao compilador que você sabe o que está fazendo, que está implementando um algoritmo na interface com consciência de que é isto que deseja mesmo, não foi acidente.

- [Interface Java 8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90168/101)
- [É correto afirmar que interface soluciona o problema de herança múltipla em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89273/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).