# Como herdar mais de uma classe no PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, herança

Existe a possibilidade de herdar duas classes no PHP?

Tenho uma classe que já herda a classe `Usuarios` e gostaria que ela herdasse a classe `Crud` também.

```
class Alunos extends Usuarios {
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prefira a composição à herança.

Você não precisa herdar. Basta instanciar as classes dentro dela e usar.

No PHP não existe suporte para múltiplas heranças.

Answer (score 9):

Não pode, quase linguagem alguma permite e mesmo as que permitem [é problemático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42970/101).

Existe a possibilidade de uso de [`interfaces`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166530/101) ([veja também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219288/101)) que define contratos e faz uma [espécie de herança múltipla](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/89275/101), faz subtipo, mas não subclasse, então não há reuso de código, ou então [`traits`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156913/101) que faz reuso de código de forma limitada. Não é o mesmo que herdar de uma classe, mas ajuda.

De qualquer forma quase todos os problemas que a pessoa pensa que precisa herdar de mais de uma classe está abusando da herança, e aí seria bom a pessoa repensar todo seu entendimento sobre herança, provavelmente essa pessoa [usa herança onde não deve](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/101) mesmo nos casos simples.

Eu acho estranho [um `Aluno` **ser** um `Usuario`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101), pode ser, mas não é comum. `Aluno` certamente não é um `Crud`. Aí não acho que cabe sequer herança simples. Na verdade, nem composição entre estas duas coisas, caberia.

Por isto que eu sempre repito que quase todo código OOP está errado, em geral tem mais confusão de conceitos do que solução para problemas. Digo mais, se as pessoas começarem usar OOP certo começam desistir.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Ou você poderia criar uma interface para encapsular seu código e implementaria através da classe Crud, que a classe Usuarios extenderia e por fim a classe alunos herdaria seus atributos e métodos, você pode instanciar sem problema algum.

```
interface Conexao { metodos();}

class Crud implements Conexao{herdaria metodo(){}} 

class Usuarios extends Crud{herdaria metodo(){}} 

class Alunos extends Usuarios{herdaria os metodos de ambas}

$aluno1 = new Alunos();
```

Assim ficaria mais fácil.

Answer (score 0):

No PHP existe um recurso chamado Traits. Trata-se de um método de programação (compartilhado por outras linguagens também) para adicionar mais funcionalidades a uma classe.

Se o objetivo é que vários classes usem os métodos CRUD, pode ser uma boa saída.

[Link da documentação oficinal](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.traits.php)

[Um artigo do Imasters](https://imasters.com.br/linguagens/php/como-fazer-uma-melhor-reutilizacao-de-codigo-php-usando-traits-parte-01/?trace=1519021197)