# Java 8 "default method" versus C# "extend method"

Tags: java, c#, java-8, interface, extension-method

O Java 8 introduz o conceito de "método padrão" para permitir adicionar novas funcionalidades a uma interface.

O C# disponibiliza "métodos de extensão" que permitem "adicionar" métodos(funcionalidades) a tipos existentes.

Tendo em conta o modo como são implementados pela linguagem e os possíveis cenários de utilização, em que aspectos eles se equivalem e em quais eles diferem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sozinho o método de extensão do C# não é equivalente ao método padrão do Java. Apenas quando se soma a interface é que o mecanismo pode ser comparável.

Já fica claro de imediato que no Java a sintaxe é mais conveniente.

## Método padrão

O método padrão do Java passa fazer parte do tipo. Há uma herança do método da interface para o método da classe. Aqui são métodos mesmo, a classe passa tê-los dentro delas. Qualquer tipo de acesso à classe, mesmo por reflexão indicará a presença deles.

Neste caso se o programador não quiser a implementação padrão ele poderá escrever uma própria para atender aquela interface. Se uma classe herda desta classe, a implementação da herdada poderá escrever outra implementação sem problemas.

O método é virtual, como todo método é em interface. É um mecanismo de *runtime* de acordo com a declaração da interface/classe. Tem as vantagens e desvantagens disso. A VM precisa tratar o funcionamento.

## Método de extensão

Ainda que seja em cima de uma interface e ainda que pareça que um tipo que implementa a interface tenha aquele método, o método de extensão continua sendo estático e totalmente fora do tipo. Por serem estáticos estes métodos funcionam mais como funções.

Como o método de extensão tem prioridade menor, em geral este mesmo efeito será obtido se a classe implementar o método declarado na interface, em qualquer ponto da hierarquia, mas não de forma polimórfica. Só funcionará se for chamado pelo tipo específico e o compilador souber qual é esse tipo. Se a decisão tiver que ser dinâmica, será transformada em estática e vai chamar o método estático de extensão. Pode acabar chamando o que não deve ou pelo menos o que o programador não espera.

Não posso garantir (não tenho conhecimento suficiente) que não tenha casos específicos extras onde isto pode ser um problema. Um óbvio é que é mais fácil haver conflitos de nomes. Outro é que pode dar margem a truques perigosos.

Como o método é externo ao tipo, ele não pode ser acessado diretamente pelo tipo, ele é independente e isolado.

Este é um recurso de linguagem e totalmente resolvido pelo compilador conforme o uso do método (em oposição a sua declaração). O CLR nem precisa saber lidar com isto.

Uma vantagem dos métodos de extensão (algumas pessoas dizem que é desvantagem) é que você pode adicionar métodos novos a uma interface e fazer todas classes que se propõem implementar a interface já tenha o método. Com o mecanismo do Java tem que modificar a interface para adicionar o novo método.

Agora C# tem [o mesmo mecanismo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#default-interface-methods?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para fazer algo mais similar ao Java. Há propostas mais ambiciosas que propõe outros mecanismos, como *traits*, mas não devem prosperar.

Tentei fazer o mesmo exemplo em Java e C# de acordo com o que cada linguagem fornece:

## Java

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Veiculo veiculoT = new Veiculo();
        System.out.println("veiculoT");
        veiculoT.diagnostico();
        veiculoT.liga();
        Testador.teste(veiculoT);
        Financeiro.compra(veiculoT);
        System.out.println("---------------");
        Veiculo carro = new Carro();
        System.out.println("carro");
        carro.diagnostico();
        carro.liga();
        Testador.teste(carro);
        Financeiro.compra(carro);
        System.out.println("---------------");
        Carro carro2 = new Carro();
        System.out.println("carro2");
        carro2.diagnostico();
        carro2.liga();
        carro2.buzina();
        Testador.teste(carro2);
        Financeiro.compra(carro2);
    }
}

interface Funcionamento {
    default void liga() {
        System.out.println("Ligou!");
    }
    static void buzina() {
        System.out.println("Buzinou!");
    }
}

class Testador {
    public static void teste(Funcionamento veiculo) {
        System.out.println("Vai testar");
        veiculo.liga();
    }
}

class Financeiro {
    public static void compra(Veiculo veiculo) {
        System.out.println("Comprou N: " + veiculo.id);
        veiculo.diagnostico();
        veiculo.liga();
    }
}

class Veiculo implements Funcionamento {
    public int id = 1;
    public void diagnostico() {
        Funcionamento.super.liga();
        Funcionamento.buzina();
        liga();
        System.out.println("Tudo ok!");
    }
}

class Carro extends Veiculo {
    public void liga() {
        System.out.println("Vrom!");
    }
    public void buzina() {
        System.out.println("bi bi!");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yzjs10). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/horehxgi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Interface/DefaultExamples.java).

## C#

```
using static System.Console;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void Main() {
        Veiculo veiculoT = new Veiculo();
        WriteLine("veiculoT");
        veiculoT.diagnostico();
        veiculoT.liga();
        veiculoT.teste();
        veiculoT.compra();
        WriteLine("---------------");
        Veiculo carro = new Carro();
        WriteLine("carro");
        carro.diagnostico();
        carro.liga();
        carro.teste();
        carro.compra();
        WriteLine("---------------");
        Carro carro2 = new Carro();
        WriteLine("carro2");
        carro2.diagnostico();
        carro2.liga();
        carro2.buzina();
        carro2.teste();
        carro2.compra();
    }
}

interface IFuncionamento {
    void liga();
}

static class Funcionamento {
    public static void liga(this IFuncionamento func) => WriteLine("Ligou!");
    public static void buzina() => WriteLine("Buzinou!");
}

static class Testador {
    public static void teste(this IFuncionamento veiculo) {
        WriteLine("Vai testar");
        veiculo.liga();
    }
}

static class Financeiro {
    public static void compra(this Veiculo veiculo) {
        WriteLine("Comprou N: " + veiculo.id);
        veiculo.diagnostico();
        veiculo.liga();
    }
}

class Veiculo : IFuncionamento {
    public int id = 1;
    public void diagnostico() {
        Funcionamento.liga(this);
        Funcionamento.buzina();
        liga();
        WriteLine("Tudo ok!");
    }
    public virtual void liga() => Funcionamento.liga(this);
}

class Carro : Veiculo {
    public override void liga() => WriteLine("Vrom!");
    public void buzina() => WriteLine("bi bi!");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/FiOThZ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yRdreU). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ExtensionExamples.cs).

Note que métodos externos ao tipo, como o `Teste()` e `Compra()` podem ser chamados de forma mais conveniente no C#. Mas o método `Liga()` precisa de uma classe extra com método de extensão para conter a implementação. Além disso precisa ter uma implementação na classe concreta, mesmo que só delegue para o método de extensão, sem isso não há polimorfismo.

Em C# isso é um truque que induz a erros e dificulta depurar e usar reflexão, podendo trazer resultados não esperados para o programador mais ingênuo.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que são coisas diferentes.

O C# não tem método padrão assim como o Java não tem `extensions methods`. O que o nosso amigo fez foi uma tentativa de chegar no mesmo resultado. É claro que dessa forma está sujeito a erros porque ele tentou fazer algo que no C# não existe.

`Extensions methods` são excelentes pra organizar o código e ter um programação fluente, fora que ela protege os elementos internos da sua classe que será estendida, mas, resumindo, é comparar laranja com maçã.