# Qual o uso de default interface methods?

Tags: c#, interface

Estava vendo algumas funcionalidades propostas para o C# 8 e me deparei com o [default interface methods](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/default-interface-methods.md).

> Add support for virtual extension methods - methods in interfaces with concrete implementations.

Pelo que entendi ele consiste em permitir implementações dentro de interfaces, mas qual é a utilidade disso? Isso não entra em conflito com o uso de classes abstratas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na verdade não há conflito, classes abstratas são classes, portanto uma classe só pode ser herdada de uma única classe. Interfaces continuam podendo ser herdadas quantas forem necessárias, mesmo com métodos com implementação padrão.

Isso por si só já aumenta muito a utilidade dela já que no fundo quase nunca é necessário múltiplas subclasses, mas múltiplos subtipos é importante, e os tipos podem beneficiar-se muito por ter comportamentos.

Note que interfaces continuarão não podendo ter estado, então neste ponto também se diferencia da classes abstratas. Ainda não está certo sobre tudo o que a nova funcionalidade disponibilizará, podem ter outras limitações, por exemplo de não ter construtores, o que faz sentido já que normalmente estes são usados para inicializar estado, que a interface não tem. E de fato depois de lançado ainda pode ter algumas coisas extras em futuras verssões.

O reuso de código aumenta muito. Hoje a solução passa por:

- a) implementar a interface na classe com um código novo escrito ali
- b) implementar a interface com método simples de delegação para um [método utilitário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54012/101)
- c) abandonar a capacidade de polimorfismo do método ([método de extensão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136913/101))

A versão 8 do C# permite que nada disso seja necessário e a implementação já esteja disponível para todas as classes que quiserem declarar como sendo do subtipo daquela interface (mas há limitações de acesso).

Algumas considerações podem ser feitas:

- nenhum método da interface precisa ser implementado nela, é uma opção (mais ou menos se você precisa desse método em contexto que não seja o da interface)
- a classe sempre pode sobrepor a implementação do método da interface, ele será obrigatoriamente virtual (há ideias de permitir métodos não virtuais em condições específicas, mas isto não está certo)
- **o mais interessante** para a pergunta é que será possível adicionar um método em uma interface existente e não quebrar todas as classes que a implementam, desde que este método novo tenha uma implementação padrão, assim tudo poderá ser executado.

A ideia inicial era fazer algo até melhor, mas para manter [compatibilidade com Java 8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121240/101) e poder interoperar bem no Android preferiram fazer quase igual ao Java.

De uma certa forma esta nova funcionalidade melhora a capacidade dos métodos de extensão, que ainda tem sua utilidade, inclusive poderá ter outras possibilidades de extensões ainda no C# 8.

Uma coisa legal é que poderá fazer uma classe se conformar com uma interface sem que a classe sequer saiba disso, tudo da interface será implementado fora da classe. Isto tem vantagens e desvantagens, mas ajudará muito evitar certos padrões de projeto que são adotados hoje em dia.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Só uma ressalva importante: "Interfaces continuam podendo ser herdadas quantas forem necessárias". **Implementadas**, não herdadas.