# Herança é uma má prática para todas a linguagens?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, estilo-de-codificação, herança

Fiz um curso de arquitetura de projetos Java e o instrutor me falou que herança no Java é considerado uma má prática, que deve sempre ser evitada e é preferível se possível utilizar composição no lugar.

Isso é válido para todas as outras linguagens ou somente para Java?

Isso é válido para herança múltipla também?

Comment: Má prática é fazer mau uso do recurso. Ele em si não é nocivo, desde que se saiba o que esteja fazendo e seus riscos. Se fosse ruim assim, linguagem nenhuma daria a possibilidade de uso.

Comment: É uma má prática?? Recomendo procurar outro instrutor. E no java não é possível utilizar herança múltipla

Comment: Possível duplicata de [É errado usar herança de classes para agrupar comportamentos e atributos comuns?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11594/%c3%89-errado-usar-heran%c3%a7a-de-classes-para-agrupar-comportamentos-e-atributos-comuns)

Comment: Fernando, teria um cenário onde esse "instrutor" disse que é uma **má prática**? É muito generalizado, e difícil julgar somente com isso. Porém, se ele realmente falou isso é porque... Melhor não julgar :p

Comment: É complicado considerar como "má prática". Usar herança tem que ser muito bem justificado, quando queremos dizer que uma classe é outra.  É fácil se confundir. Além que, com herança estamos violando outro parte do OOP, que é o encapsulamento.

Comment: Ele apresentou diversos cenários. Tentei tornar a pergunta compacta, o que acredito que tenha pego mal para ele.

Comment: Concordo com o seu instrutor. Herança **de classes** é uma coisa que cria mais problemas do que resolve e, a menos que você seja forçado a utilizá-la para fazer uso de alguma funcionalidade já pré-existente que exija isso, você **sempre** poderá eliminá-la e até hoje nunca vi um caso onde a forma sem herança fosse inferior a forma com herança - o que acontece é justamente o contrário. Se tal funcionalidade pré-existente que exija herança não existir, então você nunca precisará dela e fará um projeto tão bom ou melhor do que sem herança.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

É uma má prática ensinar as coisas como má prática ou boa prática.

O ideal seria explicar o porquê das coisas. Muitas vezes a pessoa não explica porque ela não sabe (não estou dizendo que é o caso). É comum as pessoas aprenderem por receitas de bolo. Ela lê em algum lugar e passa a repetir aquilo como verdade absoluta sem questionar, sem entender porque usar.

Esse é um problema da orientação a objeto e não do Java, portanto inerente à todas linguagens que adotam OOP. Curiosamente a característica mais marcante do ["paradigma"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101) não funciona tão bem quanto as pessoas imaginavam e só em alguns casos ele realmente é útil. Muitas vezes gera mais problemas do que gera soluções.

Se quiser usar esse termo que eu não gosto, sim, é uma má prática, desde que entenda que "prática" é algo geral que costuma ter muitas exceções. Se usar corretamente, onde é útil, não tem problema. Se achar que por ser "má prática" não deve usar, aí está fazendo errado. Tem que aprender onde usar e onde evitar. É uma "má prática" abusar do recurso onde ele não é necessário e tem uma solução melhor (composição e derivados).

Tem algumas perguntas aqui que ajudam entender isso:

- [É correto dar maior preferência a composição do que herança?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/101)
- [É errado usar herança de classes para agrupar comportamentos e atributos comuns?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11594/101)
- [Princípio de substituição de Liskov](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53468/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre Associação, Agregação e Composição em OOP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101)

## Herança múltipla

Herança múltipla é outro problema que agrava a dificuldade. Por isso poucas linguagem permitem.

Imagine como é complicado um objeto ser duas coisas ao mesmo tempo. Isso pode ocorrer em problemas de biologia. Até mesmo em química as coisas são compostas por outras e não são outras coisas ao mesmo tempo.

Além do problema conceitual há problemas técnicos. É difícil implementar um compilador que faça isso certo e exigirá que a linguagem tenha maneiras de resolver certos conflitos que podem surgir quando você herda de duas entidades diferentes que podem ter estados ou comportamentos com mesmo nome. Ter um conflito de nomes é o menor dos problemas, já que o conflito conceitual é mais importante.

Um dos maiores problemas é o [problema do diamante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem). Onde duas classes (`B` e `C`) herdam de uma terceira (`A`). Aí uma quarta (`D`) herda dessas duas classes (`B` e `C`). Ambas tinham os mesmos estados e comportamentos de `A`. Qual dos dois será usado em `D`?

[image: Diamond Problem]

A maneira de acessar esses membros se torna complexa e provavelmente menos performática do que se espera.

Então herança múltipla deve ser muito evitada.

Algumas linguagens mais modernas estão evitando ter herança, ainda que isso traga algumas dificuldades para alguns poucos cenários onde a herança funciona muito bem.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: dei +1 na hora só de ler a primeira frase.