# Mudança de objeto em herança

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Tenho as seguintes classes:

```
class Funcionario {
}

class Coordenador : Funcionario {
}

class Gerente : Funcionario {
}
```

Aí em determinado momento um Coordenador pode virar Gerente.

Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depende muito dos requisitos. Eu não faria isso com herança. Me parece que a função (papel) da pessoa é uma **situação transitória**, então eu faria uma composição.

Quando você muda o objeto por completo no fundo é outra pessoa, mesmo que mantenha os dados praticamente iguais, seria uma nova identidade, isso está conceitualmente errado. Não faz sentido e complicaria a persistência de maneiras que nem imagina.

Herança é um dos recursos mais abusados da programação hoje em dia. Só deveria ser usada quando realmente traz alguma vantagem maior que as desvantagens. Esta análise foi feita? Pode confirmar que é a melhor solução e a composição não é tão boa?

```
class Funcionario {
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
    public Funcao { get; set; } //aqui coloca a função do momento
}
class Funcao {
    ...
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Composition2.cs).

Veja:

- [Herança é uma má pratica para todas a linguagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173198/101)
- [É correto dar maior preferência a composição do que herança?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/101)

Se eu conhecesse melhor toda situação talvez eu desse uma solução diferente.

Answer (score 0):

Está com cara de polimorfismo. Apesar de ambos herdarem **Funcionario**, a classe **Coordenador**, não deverá ter as mesmas atribuições especificas de Coordenador e vice-versa, exceto as propriedades que compartilham de Funcionario . Por Exemplo, Coordenador e Gerente podem utilizar a propriedade Nome, Idade e Endereço de Funcionario mas uma sobrecarga do metodo virtual **AtividadesDiarias** por exemplo não. Assim, no caso de uma promoção, o coordenador João deixaria de utilizar a Classe **Coordenador** e sim a de **Gerente** (Mas ambos permanecem sendo Funcionario). Veja neste link, uma idéia teórica sobre polimorfismo.

[Quando e por que devemos usar polimorfismo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25100/quando-e-por-que-devemos-usar-polimorfismo/153042#153042)