# Herança - Banco de Dados?

Tags: mysql

Comecei a implementar um banco, e estou com dúvida no seguinte:

Tenho 4 tabelas

- Pessoa
- Cliente
- Funcionario
- Administrador.

`Cliente` e `Funcionario` herdam de `Pessoa` e `Administrador` herda de `Funcionario`

O que eu fiz foi o seguinte.

Pessoa contem os dados: `nome`,`emai`,`cpf`, etc., e `Funcionario` e `Administrador` só contem a `PK`, feito isso, eu preciso incluir `Agendamento`, e preciso que todas essas tabelas consultem `Agendamento`.

***Como prosseguir***?

Comment: Não pode ter empresas cadastradas? O funcionário não pode também ser um cliente? Herança não costuma ser uma boa ideia, ainda mais em banco de dados. Acabei de responder sobre isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191832/101. Veja uma alternativa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14839/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/123499/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54177/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80948/101 e finalmente http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83702/101

Comment: talvez, eu possa fazer uma tabela perfil, onde teria o cliente, funcionário e administrador,  separados por id e uma tabela usuarios, que teria a relação com essa tabela perfil, acho que isso resolve meu problema, e não fico com atributos duplicados, muito obrigado @bigown.

Comment: Qual seria o objectivo dessa relação ?

Comment: Somente identificar quem é quem no banco, e na aplicação dar o seu devido 'painel' pra cada perfil.